# Sizing cells in a GraphicsGrid/GraphicsRow

Tags: graphics, legending

I would like to add a colour bar to a plot.  I tried to use `GraphicsRow` for this.  In a `GraphicsRow`, each item is given the same space, resulting in this:

```
Clear[colorbar]
colorbar[colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 25] := 
 DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, .1}, {y, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic, None, None}, 
  ColorFunction -> colorFunction]

GraphicsRow[{DensityPlot[Sin[Norm[{x, y}]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}],
             colorbar[]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**The colour bar has too much space around it.  How can I specify the amount of space `GraphicsRow` should give a particular item?**

Alternatively, what is a better way to include the colour bar?

---

#### Answer summary

After experimenting with this for a while, it seems that the situation is the following (simplified):

- `Grid` and friends (`Row`, `Column`) will size the grid cells to fit each item individually (cells resized to fit items).
- `GraphicsGrid` will first set up a grid with fixed cell sizes, then fit each item into the cells (items resized to fit cells).

`GraphicsGrid`-like solutions are more convenient when the whole graphic need to be sized to a specification.

**István's answer** hacks `GraphcisRow` by setting a negative spacing and thus pushing the elements closer together.  It's the most convenient for this situation, but it doesn't generalize for many cells.

**R.M.'s solution** suggests using `Grid` instead.  This generalizes well, but requires pre-sizing all items individually, and no resizing is possible after (e.g. just before import).

Since `GraphicsGrid` is implemented in terms of `Inset`, the most general easily resizable solution would be implementing a `GraphicsGrid`-like construct where cell size ratios can be specified.  **kguler's last answer** illustrates this best.

Several other solutions used `Inset` directly as well.  A problem with resizing these solutions can be that the aspect ratio of elements is size-dependent (due to the absolute sizes used in `ImagePadding`), so how they fit into a fixed aspect ratio `Inset` will depend on the scale.  Note for example the difference in scaling behaviour between István's solution and kguler's solution at small sizes: in kguler's solution  (using a cell aspect ratio matching that of the colour bar)  the colourbar suddenly get shrunk compared to the main plot at small sizes, but the tick marks will never overlap with the other plot.  in István's solution (which uses overlapping square cells) the colour bar never gets overshrunk, but the tick marks will overlap the main plot.

**Update:** Version 9 has built-in support for [plot legends](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Legends.html), including [colour bars](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html). [`Legended`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Legended.html) is used to append a legend to a graphics object.

Comment: What is wrong with `Grid` rather than `GraphicsRow`/ `GraphicsGrid`? The sizings are not fixed to be equal with `Grid`.

Comment: @Verbeia Now I see that `Grid` is the most workable solution.  The inconvenience is that it's not resizable.  I need to specify the size of the grid elements instead.  I am making all  my figures to size, and I don't resize the final result in LaTeX because I want the font sizes to be consistent.  Resizing in Mathematica does not alter font sizes, but resizing an exporting PDF does.  That said, I am going with Grid, as R.M. suggested.  I don't think there is any other usable option.  (I actually manged to tweak the cell sizes in `GraphicsRow`, but it introduced other problems.)

Comment: `ItemSize` option to `Grid`? Let me see if I can come up with an answer quickly before work beckons.

Comment: @Verbeia When I use `Grid`, `ItemSize` is not even necessary because it the cells will auto-size to the content.

Comment: It's useful if your original `ImageSize` on the `colorbar` is not conformable to the other plot (which it isn't by default on my screen). Yes, you can use R.M.'s answer using `Show`, but in case there are situations where you don't want to use `Show`, this works. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: It's perhaps worth mentioning now that in Mathematica 9, for this specific case of a colour bar on a plot, you can use `PlotLegends` for this! http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/legends/ and specifically http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/legends/show-gradient-for-a-density.html

Comment: Note that the syntax for `FrameTicks` has changed. Now (at least since version 11) the syntax to produce the above bar label is `FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {None, None}}`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One way of doing it is to use `Row` instead of `GraphicsRow` and setting an explicit `ImageSize`. The solution also scales for different sizes. Setting the same `ImagePadding` on both plots will ensure that they are nicely aligned.  For example:

```
With[{size = 300}, 
 Row[Show[#, ImageSize -> {Automatic, size}, 
     ImagePadding -> 20] & /@ {DensityPlot[
     Sin[Norm[{x, y}]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], colorbar[]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

The above plot still has excess spacing between the graphic and the color bar. The reason for this is because of the uniform padding of 20. So this translates to 20 for the right side of the first + 20 for the left side of the second which means a 40 total between the two. Using the `{{left, right}, {bottom, top}}` spacing specification for `ImagePadding` works very well in aligning color bars to a plot. For this case, modify the above code to: `ImagePadding -> {{20, 0}, {20, 5}}`, which results in

[image]

You can now set a separate right padding if you need to leave some more space between the two.

Answer (score 11):

You can overlap `GraphicsRow` items by specifying negative spacings. This omits whitespace to the right (as in kguler's answer):

```
size = 360;

colorbar[colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 25] := 
 DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, .1}, {y, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic, None, None}, 
  ColorFunction -> colorFunction, ImageSize -> {size/5, size}]

GraphicsRow[
 Show[#, ImagePadding -> 20] & /@ {DensityPlot[
    Sin[Norm[{x, y}]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, ImageSize -> size],
    colorbar[]}, Alignment -> Right, ImageSize -> size, Frame -> None,
  Spacings -> {-3 size/4, Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Updated** with appropriate size specifications.

Comment: I chose this because it has the best scaling behaviour and is simple to implement.

Answer (score 10):

**Using `GraphicsRow` options:**

**-**  `Alignment` option

```
  GraphicsRow[{DensityPlot[
  Sin[Norm[{x, y}]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], colorbar[]}, 
  Alignment -> Left]
```

gives

[image: legend in graphicsRow]

**-** `Spacings` with negative values:

```
 GraphicsRow[{DensityPlot[
 Sin[Norm[{x, y}]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], colorbar[]}, 
 Spacings -> Scaled[-.4]]
```

or

```
 GraphicsRow[{DensityPlot[
 Sin[Norm[{x, y}]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], colorbar[]}, 
 Spacings -> -100]
```

Both give less white space on the right.

**Replacing position and size options of `Inset`**

Inspecting the `InputForm` of the output from `GraphicsRow`, we see that it is a collection of `Inset` objects, one for each graphics object in the argument list. So the positions and sizes of the graphics objects can be controlled by options to `Inset`. These are

> Inset[obj,pos,opos]
>
> aligns the inset so that position opos in the object lies at position pos in the enclosing graphic.
>
> Inset[obj,pos,opos,size]
>
> specifies the size of the inset in the coordinate system of the enclosing graphic.

This suggests a hack (specific to the example and wrapped with `Panel` to show the relative sizes)

```
 a = 420; b = 120; 
 Panel@GraphicsRow[{DensityPlot[
 Sin[Norm[{x, y}]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], 
 Graphics[colorbar[]]}, ImageSize -> 500] /. Inset[gr_, 
   {576., pos2_}, ImageScaled[{0.5, 0.5}], {sz1_, sz2_}] :> 
Inset[gr, 
   {a, pos2}, ImageScaled[{0.5, 0.5}], {b , sz2}]
```

with output

[image: inset legend]

**DIY `GraphicsRow`: Using `Graphics` and `Inset`:**

Use `Graphics` and `Inset` to replicate what `GraphicsRow` does, and control the options for `Inset` directly:

```
 Graphics[{ {Inset[
 DensityPlot[Sin[Norm[{x, y}]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], 
    {192, -189.}, ImageScaled[{0.5, 0.5}], {360, 360.}], 
  Inset[Graphics[colorbar[]], 
    {420., -189.}, ImageScaled[{0.5, 0.5}], {120., 360.}]}}, 
ContentSelectable -> True, ImageSize -> 500,
PlotRangePadding -> {6, 5}]
```

which produces the same output.

Comment: I found this myself, but unfortunately there's still a lot of whitespace on the right, which causes trouble when I export this to include in a document.

Answer (score 9):

Further to R.M.'s answer, you can use some combination of `ImageSize` on the graphic elements and `ItemSize` for the `Grid` elements themselves to finesse spacing. I've added the possibility to include other options to the `colorbar` function, such as `ImageSize`, though if you use them you need to set the other two arguments explicitly. This is an alternative to `Show` with additional options.

```
colorbar[colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 25, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, .1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[DensityPlot]]], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
  PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic, None, None}, 
  ColorFunction -> colorFunction]
```

`Framed` to show the difference between `ItemSize` and `ImageSize`. Note that the former is in character widths and the latter is in pixels.

```
Grid[{{DensityPlot[Sin[Norm[{x, y}]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], 
   Framed@colorbar[Automatic, 30, ImageSize -> 32]}}, 
 ItemSize -> {{15, 4}}, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

This alternative might be useful if, like here, the default sizes don't quite work together, and for whatever reason you don't want to use `Show`.

[image]

Comment: This is quite nice looking

Answer (score 9):

This is a little late, but I had actually fought the same problem a couple of days ago, and only now saw that this was a question. I'm putting it here as another solution:

```
Clear[colorbar,defaultSize]
defaultSize=360;

colorbar[colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 25] := 
 DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, .1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
  PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, AspectRatio -> Full, 
  ImageSize -> {defaultSize/10, defaultSize}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic, None, None}, 
  ColorFunction -> colorFunction]

GraphicsRow[{DensityPlot[
   Sin[Norm[{x, y}]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, ImageSize -> defaultSize], 
  colorbar[]}, Alignment -> {Left, Center}, Spacings -> 20, 
 ImageSize -> {Automatic, defaultSize}]
```

The difference between the original question and this is the following:

1. `AspectRatio->Full` which according to the docs: "specifies that a graphic should be stretched so as to fill out its enclosing region in a Grid or related construct."
2. Explicit `ImageSize`, especially in the GraphicsRow to specify `Automatic` in the horizontal direction, but our default size in the vertical.
3. `Alignment->{Left,Center}`
4. `Spacings` played around with until a 'nice' value was found.

Hope this helps someone. FWIW, I have no idea why the above works, maybe someone better versed in inner MMA speak can answer that.

[image: DensityPlot]

Comment: Interesting solution, I didn't know about `AspectRatio -> Full`.  Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Szabolcs you're welcome. I had more or less the exact same problem, and it took me a full day to figure out the right combo of settings. It's voodoo.

Comment: I used the answer I accepted in conjunction with [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2091/retrieving-the-imagepadding-in-absolute-units).  What a hack to use image processing just to get some margins right!

Answer (score 7):

This seems to give good flexibility:

```
Show[DensityPlot[Sin[Norm[{x, y}]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], 
 Graphics@Inset[colorbar[], {15, 0}], 
 ImagePadding -> {{20, 100}, {20, 20}}, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
You can also use relative coordinates:

```
Graphics@Inset[colorbar[], ImageScaled[{0.9, 0.5}]]
```

The advantage of this method is that you can easily configure/tweak it to be almost anything you want, and also add multiple `Graphics`:

```
Show[DensityPlot[Sin[Norm[{x, y}]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}], 
 Graphics@Inset[colorbar[], ImageScaled[{1, 0.3}], {0.5, 0.5}, 
   ImageScaled[{0.1, 0.4}]], ImagePadding -> {{20, 20}, {20, 20}}]
```

[image]

Comment: The disadvantage here is that the positioning of the colour bar depends on the plot coordinates on the main graphic --- something to avoid if possible.

Comment: @Szabolcs I edited it with an example independent of the plot coordinates

Comment: Placing the colour bar inside the plot is not acceptable for my use case.  The entire plot region contains important information that must not be covered.  Thank you for showing be `ImageScaled`, it will prove very useful!

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica versions 11 and 12 behave differently with regard to `GraphicsRow`/`GraphicsGrid`.

For `GraphicsRow`, there is no change required when using the negative spacing hack identified as István's answer in the Question's Answer Summary.

For `GraphicsGrid`, the negative spacing hack which worked in version 11 does not immediately in version 12. Calling `AspectRatio` as outlined in a [related post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78192/delete-the-white-areas-in-graphicsgrid) allows keeping previously chosen spacing(s) as is.
Besides, both versions 11 and 12 result in whitespace at the top. If neither using `Frame` nor `Dividers`, that can be removed with `ImageCrop`, see e.g. [there](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238390/remove-white-border-around-graphicsrow-graphicsgrid-graphicscolumn).

Answer (score 1):

This is the best scaling behavior for this specific problem that I could come up with:

```
Clear[colorbar]
colorbar[colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 25] := 
 DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, .1}, {y, 0, 1},
   PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0,
   AspectRatio -> 7, PlotRangePadding -> 0,  
   Frame -> False, Axes -> {False, True}, 
   TicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, Red], AxesOrigin -> {0.1}, 
   ColorFunction -> colorFunction
 ]

Graphics[{
  First @ DensityPlot[Sin[Norm[{x, y}]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}],
  Inset[
    colorbar[],
    Scaled[{1, 1/2}],
    ImageScaled[{-0.1, 1/2}],
    Scaled[{1/7, 1}]
  ]
 },
 Frame -> True,
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 5}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice trick putting the ticks inside.  Unfortunately I can't do this.  But I learned about the possibility of `FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, All}` now.  Thanks!  (That `All` was not so obvious to me.)