# Retrieving the ImagePadding in absolute units

Tags: graphics

Consider the following graphic:

```
g = Graphics[Circle[], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"one", "two"}]
```

Retrieving the `ImagePadding` by traditional means does not work:

```
AbsoluteOptions[g, ImagePadding]

(* ==> {ImagePadding -> All} *)
```

My guess for the reason behind this is that it is the Front End that can compute the actual value of the ImagePadding to use, so this can't be obtained without first rasterizing the image in the front end.

Is there some trick to get a numerical value for the `ImagePadding` so I can align two figures (make them have the same `ImagePadding`) *and* use an optimal value (not too small cutting off something, not too large wasting space), perhaps by asking the Front End directly?

Note that the `ImagePadding` is in absolute coordinates (printer's points, not plot coordinates).

Comment: to align plots i always explicitly set image padding in all plots. is there some reason you do not want to do that?

Comment: @Mike The question is: what padding should we use to ensure that all tick marks and labels are visible and no space is wasted?  If there's a lot of label / tick / font size and style tweaking, each of those will require me to manually re-adjust the image padding.  Heike's solution works quite well and spared me this (very real) trouble.

Comment: ok. I understand now :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Update**

*I created a paclet. Install the paclet with*

```
PacletInstall[
    "GraphicsInformation",
    "Site"->"http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/GraphicsInformation/master"
]
```

*and then load the paclet with*

```
<<GraphicsInformation`
```

*Use `GraphicsInformation` instead of `graphicsInformation`*

**Original post**

Here is my attempt to create a function that returns reliable values for [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html), [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) and [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html). It is inspired by the efforts of @LLlAMnYP in his answer to [83636](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83659/45431) and @AlexeyPopkov in his answer to [18034](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18040/45431)

The basic idea is use [`ExportPacket`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExportPacket.html) to find out what the FrontEnd computes for these values. Not only is this what [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) uses under the hood, it allows one to support [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html) [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) settings as well by setting the [`WindowSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WindowSize.html) of the [`Notebook`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Notebook.html) object fed to [`ExportPacket`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExportPacket.html). For instance, @Heike's answer doesn't fair well when [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html)->[`Full`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Full.html) is used.

1. [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) /[`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html) - Adding an [`Annotation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Annotation.html) wrapper to appropriate [`Rectangle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle.html) objects added as an [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) can be used to determine these values.
2. [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) - Rather than using pure function [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html), I used pure function [`GridLines`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLines.html). GridLines apply whether [`Frame`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Frame.html)/[`Axes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Axes.html) are [`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True.html) or [`False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/False.html).

Here is the function:

```
graphicsInformation[gr_Graphics] := Module[{info},
    info = Flatten @ Reap[
        Rule @@@ ReplaceAll[
            "Regions",
            FrontEndExecute @ ExportPacket[
                toNotebook[gr],
                "BoundingBox",
                Verbose->True
            ]
        ],
        _,
        #1->#2[[1]]&
    ];
    extract[info]
]

toNotebook[gr_] := Notebook[
    {
    Cell[BoxData @ ToBoxes @ instrumentGraphics[gr],
        "Output"
    ]
    },
    WindowSize -> CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize],
    Evaluator -> CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], Evaluator]
]

instrumentGraphics[gr_Graphics] := Show[
    gr,
    GridLines -> {sowRange["X"], sowRange["Y"]},
    Epilog -> {
        Annotation[
            Rectangle[Scaled[{0,0}], Scaled[{1,1}]],
            "PlotRange", "Region"
        ],
        Annotation[
            Rectangle[ImageScaled[{0,0}], ImageScaled[{1,1}]],
            "ImageSize", "Region"
        ]
    }
]

sowRange[label_] := Function[Sow[{##}, label]; None]

extract[rules_] := Module[{pr, is, xr, yr},
    {pr, is, xr, yr} = {{"PlotRange", "Region"}, {"ImageSize", "Region"}, "X", "Y"} /. rules;
    {
    "ImagePadding"->Abs[is-pr],
    "ImageSize"->Abs[Subtract@@@is],
    "PlotRangeSize"->Abs[Subtract@@@pr],
    "ImagePaddingSize"->Total[Abs[is-pr],{2}],
    "PlotRange"->{xr,yr}
    }
]
```

Here are a couple examples:

```
graphicsInformation @ Plot[
    Sin[x],
    {x, 0, Pi},
    ImagePadding -> {{1.1,2.2}, {3.3,4.4}}
]
```

> {"ImagePadding" -> {{1.1, 2.2}, {3.3, 4.4}}, "ImageSize" -> {360., 228.153}, 
>    "PlotRangeSize" -> {356.7, 220.453}, "ImagePaddingSize" -> {3.3, 7.7}, 
>    "PlotRange" -> {{-0.0654498, 3.20704}, {-0.0555556, 1.05556}}}

```
plot = Plot[
    Sin[x],
    {x, 0, Pi},
    ImageSize -> Full,
    ImagePadding -> {{1.1,2.2}, {3.3,4.4}}
];
graphicsInformation[plot]
```

> {"ImagePadding" -> {{1.1, 2.2}, {3.3, 4.4}}, "ImageSize" -> {706., 441.992}, 
>    "PlotRangeSize" -> {702.7, 434.292}, "ImagePaddingSize" -> {3.3, 7.7}, 
>    "PlotRange" -> {{-0.0654498, 3.20704}, {-0.0555556, 1.05556}}}

Compare to Heike's solution:

```
heike[g_]:=BorderDimensions@Image[Show[g,LabelStyle->White,Background->White]]
heike[plot]
```

> {{19, 4}, {5, 7}}

One final comment. It is possible to use a single call to [`ExportPacket`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExportPacket.html) to extract graphics information from multiple graphics objects. Since the call to [`ExportPacket`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExportPacket.html) is the most time consuming part of the code, using a single call to [`ExportPacket`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExportPacket.html) will be much quicker than using `graphicsInformation` on multiple [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) objects. Here is a version that does this:

```
Clear[graphicsInformation, extract]
graphicsInformation[gr:{__Graphics}] := Module[{info, res},
    info = Flatten @ Reap[
        Rule @@@ ReplaceAll[
            "Regions",
            FrontEndExecute @ ExportPacket[
                toNotebook[gr],
                "BoundingBox",
                Verbose->True
            ]
        ],
        _,
        #1->#2[[1]]&
    ];
    res = extract[info] /@ Range @ Length @ gr;
    Thread @ Rule[
        {"ImagePadding", "ImageSize", "PlotRangeSize", "ImagePaddingSize", "PlotRange"},
        Thread @ ReplaceAll[
            {"ImagePadding", "ImageSize", "PlotRangeSize", "ImagePaddingSize", "PlotRange"},
            res
        ]
    ]
]
graphicsInformation[gr_Graphics] := Replace[
    graphicsInformation[{gr}],
    Rule[a_, {b_}] :> a -> b,
    {1}
]

toNotebook[gr_] := Notebook[
    {
    Cell[BoxData @ ToBoxes @ instrumentGraphics[gr],
        "Output"
    ]
    },
    WindowSize -> CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize],
    Evaluator -> CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], Evaluator]
]

instrumentGraphics[gr:{__Graphics}] := MapThread[
    Show[#1,
        GridLines -> {sowRange["X" -> #2], sowRange["Y" -> #2]},
        Epilog -> {
            Annotation[
                Rectangle[Scaled[{0,0}], Scaled[{1,1}]],
                "PlotRange", #2
            ],
            Annotation[
                Rectangle[ImageScaled[{0,0}], ImageScaled[{1,1}]],
                "ImageSize", #2
            ]
        }
    ]&,
    {gr, Range@Length@gr}
]

instrumentGraphics[gr_Graphics] := instrumentGraphics[{gr}]

sowRange[label_] := Function[Sow[{##}, label]; None]

extract[rules_][k_] := Module[{pr, is, xr, yr},
    {pr, is, xr, yr} = {{"PlotRange",k}, {"ImageSize",k}, "X"->k, "Y"->k} /. rules;
    {
    "ImagePadding"->Abs[is-pr],
    "ImageSize"->Abs[Subtract@@@is],
    "PlotRangeSize"->Abs[Subtract@@@pr],
    "ImagePaddingSize"->Total[Abs[is-pr],{2}],
    "PlotRange"->{xr,yr}
    }
]
```

Comment: Very nice. What happens if `gr` already has an `Epilog`?

Comment: @ChipHurst It gets zapped by the `Epilog` added by `instrumentGraphics`. Since an `Epilog` doesn't affect any of the output of `GraphicsInformation`, there is no need to worry about combining epilogs.

Comment: This is extremely useful. Here's a use case: https://github.com/szhorvat/MatchGraphics

Answer (score 14):

This almost works but seems to be 1 point off some of the time

```
im = Image[Show[g, LabelStyle -> White, Background -> White]];
BorderDimensions[im]
```

For example for

```
g = Graphics[Circle[], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"one", "two"}, 
  ImagePadding -> {{35, 20}, {40, 50}}]
```

The output is

```
{{35, 19}, {40, 50}}
```

Comment: Off by 1-2 pixels is not a big deal.  The solution is still usable. Off by 6-8 would be too inaccurate.

Answer (score 5):

Edit: more seriously this time, this actually should be helpful.

---

```
fill = Show[#,
        Epilog -> {
          Black, Rectangle[ImageScaled[{0, 0}], ImageScaled[{1, 1}]],
          Red, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]
        }
       ] &;

rle = Part[Length /@ Split @ #, {1, -1}] &;

imgpad[g_] := With[{dat = ImageData[fill @ g]},
  {rle @ dat[[#]], Reverse @ rle @ dat[[All, #2]]} & @@ Quotient[Dimensions @ dat, 2]
]
```

Usage:

```
imgpad[graphic]
```

I don't have the function `BorderDimensions` but I presume this could be substituted for the part after the `fill`.

Comment: You need to use ImageData to get the image data (not Part, in the `bin` function).  The Image format changed in version 8, but ImageData works.  The last number returned is incorrect and needs to be adjusted to the image height here (I get `{{30, 1}, {32, 223}}` instead of `{{35, 1}, {32, 0}}`)

Comment: @Szabolcs please tell me if this is working now.

Comment: It still doesn't work correctly.  `imgpad[DensityPlot[x, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]]` gives me `{{17, 1}, {13, 341}}`.  Sorry, really don't have time to dig into why right now ... just an example where it gives an incorrect reasult

Comment: @Szabolcs your test code returns: `{{31, 3}, {20, 2}}` on my system.

Comment: This should be linked from the version compatibility testing question ... I'll try to figure out what's going on later.  BTW Heike's method gives `{{17, 1}, {14, 0}}` for the same `DensityPlot`

Comment: I think the problem is that your function does not require that all borders have the same colour therefore it won't work if some borders are of width 0.

Answer (score 2):

This works sometimes (for framed graphics only):

```
absoluteImagePadding[g_] := 
 Module[{img, lines, small, big, x1, x2, y1, y2},
  img = Rasterize[Show[Graphics[{}], Sequence @@ Options[g]], "Image"];
  lines = ImageLines[ColorNegate[img], .25];
  {small, big} = 
   Sort@Cases[lines, {{_, a_}, {_, b_}} /; Abs[a - b] < 2 :> Mean[{a, b}]];
  {y1, y2} = Round[{small, ImageDimensions[img][[2]] - big}];
  {small, big} = 
   Sort@Cases[lines, {{a_, _}, {b_, _}} /; Abs[a - b] < 2 :> Mean[{a, b}]];
  {x1, x2} = Round[{small, ImageDimensions[img][[1]] - big}];
  {{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}}
  ]
```

It works by rasterizing the image, detecting the frame lines and measuring their position.  It is an extremely hackish and fragile workaround though.

[image: Mathematica graphics]