# Aligning plot axes in a graphics object

Tags: graphics, plotting

I need to align the y-axes in the plots below.  I think I'm going to have to do some rasterizing and searching for vertical lines, then vary `x` and `w`.  Is there a better way?

```
a = ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {16, 20}},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 16}, {0, 20}}, Frame -> True];
b = ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {160000, 200000}}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 160000}, {0, 200000}}, Frame -> True];
x = 3.1; w = 5;
Graphics[{LightYellow, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {7, 8}], 
  Inset[a, {x, 5.5}, Center, {w, Automatic}], 
  Inset[b, {3.1, 2.2}, Center, {5, Automatic}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 8}}, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Comment: See http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/AlignPlotsWithEachOther.html

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is a common (and very big) annoyance when creating graphics with subfigures.  The most general (but somewhat tedious) solution is setting an explicit `ImagePadding`:

```
GraphicsColumn[
 {Show[a, ImagePadding -> {{40, 10}, {Automatic, Automatic}}], 
  Show[b, ImagePadding -> {{40, 10}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is tedious because you need to come up with values manually.  There are hacks to retrieve the `ImagePadding` that is used by the `Automatic` setting.  [I asked a question about this before.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2091/retrieving-the-imagepadding-in-absolute-units)  Using Heike's solution from there, we can try to automate the process:

```
padding[g_Graphics] := 
 With[{im = Image[Show[g, LabelStyle -> White, Background -> White]]},
   BorderDimensions[im]]

ip = 1 + Max /@ Transpose[{First@padding[a], First@padding[b]}]

GraphicsColumn[
 Show[#, ImagePadding -> {ip, {Automatic, Automatic}}] & /@ {a, b}]
```

The padding detection that's based on rasterizing might be off by a pixel, so I added 1 for safety.

Warning: the automatic padding depends on the image size!  The tick marks or labels might "hang out" a bit.  You might need to use `padding@Show[a, ImageSize -> 100]` to get something that'll work for smaller sizes too.

I have used this method myself several times, and while it's a bit tedious at times, it works well (much better than figuring out the image padding manually).

Answer (score 20):

While Szabolcs's method works beautifully for standard plots, anything more complicated with nonuniform `AspectRatio`s fails. Let's generate some plots with varying image padding, sizes and ratios:

```
a = Plot[2 Sin[x] + x, {x, 0, 16}, Filling -> Bottom, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 16}, {0, 20}}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400];
b = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {20, 20}], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 160000}, {0, 200000}}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {
     {MapIndexed[{First@#2, #1} &, Range[0, 160000, 8000]], None},
     {MapIndexed[{First@#2, Rotate[#1, -\[Pi]/2]} &, Range[0, 200000, 10000]], None}},
   ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> 1, ColorFunction -> (Hue[#1, .7, 1] &)];
c = BarChart[{1, 2}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 200, AspectRatio -> 2];

Row@{a, b, c}
```

[image]

The default layout is far from visually appealing. Here I provide the package-ready `plotRow` function that builds on Szabolcs's (and Heike's) approach when estimating padding and also accounts for `AspectRatio`s by querying them directly from plots. One only has to specify the desired vertical size (`200`) to easily align frames.

```
padding[g_Graphics] := With[{im = 
   Image[Show[g, LabelStyle -> White, Background -> White]]}, BorderDimensions@im] + 1;
plotRow[g : {__Graphics}, y_] := Module[{ip = padding /@ g, ar},
   ip = ReplacePart[ip, {_, 2} :> Max /@ Transpose[Last /@ ip]];
   ar = (AspectRatio /. Options@# /. Automatic -> 1./GoldenRatio) & /@ g // N;
   MapThread[Show[#1, ImagePadding -> #2, AspectRatio -> #3, 
      ImageSize -> ({y/#3, y} + Plus @@@ #2)] &, {g, ip, ar}]
 ];

Row@plotRow[{a, b, c}, 200]
```

[image]

The same can be easily done for a vertical layout by modifying the appropriate parts of `plotRow`.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but it is not yet robust.  Consider the case of `Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotLabel -> Style["Title", Opacity[1], Red, 22]]` -- the explicit style overrules your `LabelStyle -> White`.  Though not as clean you might use something like: `With[{rec = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]}, 
  Show[#, PlotRangeClipping -> None, 
   Epilog -> {Black, ImageScaled /@ rec, Red, Scaled /@ rec}]
  ] &`