# Aligning a DensityPlot with a Plot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to show a gradient field behind a plot, and then its density in a separate plot below.

I understand (as in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4059/aligning-plot-axes-in-a-graphics-object)) that this must normally be done using the ImagePadding directive.  However, that does not quite align the plots in this case:

```
padding = {{20, 30}, {20, 30}}; 
GraphicsColumn[
  {
   Show[
    DensityPlot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], Log[x/40]] , 
      {x, 15, 60}, {y, 0, 30}, 
      ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"], 
    Graphics[{Dashed, Gray, Line[{{40, 0}, {40, 30}}]}], 
    Plot[If[x < 20, 10, If[x < 25, 2 x - 30, 20]], {x, 15, 60}, 
      PlotRange -> {0, 30} , 
      PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0.5, .7, 0.2], Thickness[0.01]}], 
    ImagePadding -> padding, PlotRangePadding -> None
   ], 
   Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 5 Log[x/40]] , {x, 15, 60}, 
      PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[1, 0.4, 0], Thickness[0.01]},
      ImagePadding -> padding]
  }
]
```

[image: Align me]

Is there a way to get the abscissa ranges to match?

Comment: You also need to set `PlotRange` explicitly for both plots

Comment: You might also need to explicitly set the AxesOrigin option in the bottom plot.

Comment: To those tempted to close: I believe the issue is slightly different from earlier alignment questions. Please don't close.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`AbsoluteOptions` shows there to be several differences between the  output settings of the first and second plots:

```
Grid[Prepend[Transpose[
     AbsoluteOptions[#, {PlotRangePadding, AspectRatio, 
           Frame}] & /@ {plot1, plot2}], {"first", "second"}], Frame -> All]
```

[image: settings]

It'll look better if you use the same aspect ratio (I used 1/GoldenRatio) and a frame in each picture. I also set `PlotRangePadding-> None` in the second case.

[image: plots]

Comment: Your method of examining AbsoluteOptions is very generalizable.  I think it's great.

Comment: Thanks. It's probably still a good idea to first scan the output of  `AbsoluteOptions[plot1]` and `AbsoluteOptions[plot2]` to identify the options you want to compare.

Answer (score 4):

Use for example Framed[]:

```
padding = {{20, 20}, {20, 20}};
GraphicsColumn[{
  Framed[Show[
    DensityPlot[
     PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], Log[x/40]], {x, 15, 60}, {y, 0, 
      30}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"],
    Graphics[{Dashed, Gray, Line[{{40, 0}, {40, 30}}]}], 
    Plot[If[x < 20, 10, If[x < 25, 2 x - 30, 20]], {x, 15, 60}, 
     PlotRange -> {0, 30}, 
     PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0.5, .7, 0.2], Thickness[0.01]}], 
    ImagePadding -> padding, PlotRangePadding -> None], 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[White]],
  Framed[Plot[
    PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 5 Log[x/40]], {x, 15, 60}, 
    PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[1, 0.4, 0], Thickness[0.01]}, 
    ImagePadding -> padding, Frame -> True], 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[White]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, sneaky trick!