# HoldFirst and inserting additional options into a Grid of Graphics

Tags: programming, evaluation

This is related to [my earlier question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6877/do-i-have-to-code-each-case-of-this-grid-full-of-plots-separately), but is specific to an issue I have encountered with the use of the `HoldFirst`

First, let's create some fake data for testing purposes.

```
dateARList = 
  With[{ar = FoldList[0.9 #1 + #2 &, 0., 
      RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]]},
   Transpose[{ Table[DatePlus[{2000, 1, 1}, {n, "Month"}], {n, 0, 100}], ar}] ];
```

Now define two functions. First, the general one that doesn't assume the size of the matrix in the first argument.

```
Clear[testHolder, testHolder2]

Attributes[testHolder] = {HoldFirst}

testHolder[m_?MatrixQ, rest : OptionsPattern[{Graphics, Grid}]] :=

 Module[{nc, nr, subrules, subargs},
  {nr, nc} = Dimensions[m];
  subrules = Table[Cases[HoldForm[m[[i, j]]], _Rule], {i, nr}, {j, nc}];
  subargs  = Table[Cases[HoldForm[m[[i, j]]], Except[_Rule]], {i, nr}, {j, nc}];
  Grid[Table[
    Head[m[[i, j]]] @@ Join[subargs[[i, j]], subrules[[i, j]], 
     {PlotLabel -> {i, j}, Joined -> True} ], {i, nr}, {j, nc}], 
  FilterRules[{rest}, Grid]]
  ]

testHolder[{{DateListPlot[dateARList, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   DateListPlot[dateARList, PlotStyle -> Blue]}}, 
 Background -> Yellow, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

As you can see, the options I tried to insert into the sub-plots  (`Joined` and `PlotLabel`) do not get passed to them, nor do the options for the overall `Grid` (`Frame` and `Background`).

Now, let's try a more specific case where the dimensions of the matrix in the first argument are known.

```
Attributes[testHolder2] = {HoldFirst}

testHolder2[{{l_[largs__, lopts___Rule], r_[rargs__, ropts___Rule]}}, 
  rest : OptionsPattern[{Graphics, Grid}]] :=
 Grid[{{l @@ Join[{largs}, {lopts}, {PlotLabel -> "Left", Joined -> True}], 
        r @@ Join[{rargs}, {ropts}, {PlotLabel -> "Right", Joined -> True}]}},  
 FilterRules[{rest}, Grid] ]
```

Now we have a better outcome - the options for the specific plots are passed to them, but the options for the `Grid` aren't used.

```
testHolder2[{{DateListPlot[dateARList, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   DateListPlot[dateARList, PlotStyle -> Blue]}}, 
 Background -> Yellow, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

I'm probably missing something, but I don't know what it is. Is `HoldFirst` the right way to ensure that additional options can be inserted into a function before it is evaluated? If not, what do I need to do to the evaluation sequence to get the desired result? Can I get the general (`testHolder`) case to work, or do I have to set things up with explicit pattern matches for the heads and arguments of the elements in the matrix, as in `testHolder2`?

Comment: It seems the problem is that `Cases[HoldForm[m[[i, j]]], Except[_Rule]]` is what evaluates your plots, thus rendering you unable to insert the `Joined` option.

Comment: I think I was just confused when answering. Do you want the `Graphics` options inserted at the end of the function to be passed to all individual plots or not?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you need.  I posted the method I would use for function insertion.  If you will describe the additional functionality you need or how my method fails I will amend it accordingly.

Comment: Verbeia would you tell me how you find my method lacking?

Comment: It isn't. Heike's version just was easier to integrate into the rather more complex actual code that I have, so I upvoted all good answers and accepted Heike's as the best one for my needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is to keep Mathematica from prematurely evaluating `m` while at the same time trying to extract its elements. In this approach I solve this by wrapping the elements of `m` with `Hold`

```
testHolder[m_?MatrixQ, rest : OptionsPattern[{Graphics, Grid}]] := 
 Module[{nc, nr, mheld, subrules, subargs},
  {nr, nc} = Dimensions[m];
  mheld = Map[Hold, Unevaluated[m], {2}];
  subrules = Table[Cases[mheld[[i, j]], _Rule, {2}], {i, nr}, {j, nc}];
  subargs = Table[Cases[mheld[[i, j]], Except[_Rule], {2}], {i, nr}, {j, nc}];
  Grid[Table[mheld[[i, j, 1, 0]] @@ 
     Join[subargs[[i, j]], subrules[[i, j]], {PlotLabel -> {i, j}, Joined -> True}], 
    {i, nr}, {j, nc}], FilterRules[{rest}, Options[Grid]]]]

testHolder[{{DateListPlot[dateARList, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   DateListPlot[dateARList, PlotStyle -> Blue]}}, 
 Background -> Yellow, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'd tried `Hold` - isn't it the `Unevaluated` that does the job?

Comment: The other crucial difference from my code seems to be `Cases[mheld[[i, j]], _Rule, {2}]` with the level specification. Not entirely clear to me why that is needed - something to do with getting underneath the `Unevaluated`?

Comment: @Verbeia, `mheld` is a matrix of things like `Hold[DateListPlot...`. So `mheld[[i, j]]` is `Hold[DateListPlot[..., ru->les]]`. There's no `Unevaluated` there any more. `Cases` by default works on level 1, but the rules are at level 2, so if you don't specify it they aren't found

Comment: @Rojo you have appended this comment to Heike's answer, where there is an `Unevaluated`. Your answer also has `Unevaluated`s in there still. It does seem important. I've accepted Heike's answer because it was the clearest and minimal adjustment to my own code, which now works (hooray!).

Comment: @Verbeia, yeah, I was referring to this code and your question... If I'm not reading it wrong, the only `Unevaluated` is in `Map[Hold, Unevaluated[m], {2}]`. That's an `Unevaluated` that gets automatically stripped off, and `Map` doesn't even see it, so it isn't there when it's `Cases` turn to act. Contrats on your code's working :)

Comment: @Rojo - right, that's the one I meant, but it seems to be necessary for things to work. I had already tried the putting `Hold` and `HoldForm` in the same place. Odd that `HoldFirst` in the function definition isn't sufficient once the `Map` comes into play. That was the thing I'd missed. The second level spec for `Cases` was just something that hadn't dawned on me when I posted the Q (at 11pm my time) - wrapping in `Hold` means the arguments of the plot are at second level. I now have a solution to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6877/8) that doesn't need `Inset`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the lines `Table[Cases[HoldForm[m[[i, j]]], _Rule], {i, nr}, {j, nc}]`, because `m[[i, j]]` isn't evaluated before you try to extact the rules, so none is extracted. They could be something like `Map[Function[plot, Cases[Unevaluated@plot, _Rule], HoldFirst], Unevaluated@m, {2}]`

Other problems:

- I don't think `FilterRules` works with something like `Grid` as a second argument. You need to put the options, such as `Options@Grid`
- I haven't tried but probably it's not a good idea to use `?MatrixQ` only to test structure because you'll leak evaluation, and plotting twice the same thing isn't something time trivial quite often. You could use `Function[mat, MatrixQ@Unevaluated@mat, HoldFirst]`. This is something I also use in my answer to map a holding version of append.
- `Head[m[[i, j]]` will evaluate the plots, and then extract the heads of the matrix entries (`Graphics` probably). You want to extract the heads before evaluating. So, do something like `(Unevaluated@m)[[i, j, 0]]`

Try it with these fixes

```
Attributes[testHolder] = {HoldFirst};
testHolder[m_?(Function[mat, MatrixQ@Unevaluated@mat, HoldFirst]), rest : OptionsPattern[{Graphics, Grid}]] := 
 Module[{nc, nr, subrules, subargs}, {nr, nc} = Dimensions[m];
  subrules = 
   Map[Function[plot, Cases[Unevaluated@plot, _Rule], HoldFirst], 
    Unevaluated@m, {2}];
  subargs = 
   Map[Function[plot, Cases[Unevaluated@plot, Except[_Rule]], 
     HoldFirst], Unevaluated@m, {2}];
  Grid[Table[(Unevaluated@m)[[i, j, 0]] @@ 
     Join[subargs[[i, j]], 
      subrules[[i, j]], {PlotLabel -> {i, j}, Joined -> True}], {i, 
     nr}, {j, nc}], FilterRules[{rest}, Options@Grid]]
  ]
```

Anyway, I started answering by doing it myself, and this is how I approached it

Is this the behaviour you want?

```
SetAttributes[testHolderV3, HoldFirst];
testHolderV3[m : {__List}, rest : OptionsPattern[{Graphics, Grid}]] :=  
 MapIndexed[
   Function[{graph, index}, 
    Append[Unevaluated@graph, 
     Join[FilterRules[{rest}, Options@Graphics],
      {PlotLabel -> index, Joined -> True}]], HoldFirst], 
   Unevaluated@m, {2}] //
  Grid[#, FilterRules[{rest}, Options@Grid] ] &
```

So

```
testHolderV3[{{DateListPlot[dateARList, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   DateListPlot[dateARList, PlotStyle -> Blue]}}, 
 Background -> Yellow, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

EDIT

Ok, I'm not sure if you want Graphics options inserted in the list at the end to be passed to all plots or not. Such as a possible `ImageSize->Medium`. 
If you want that, add to your `testHolder`, a `FilterRules[subrules, Options@Graphics]`. If you don't, remove from `testHolderV3` the `Join[FilterRules[{rest}, Options@Graphics],...` and just leave the options you want

Answer (score 4):

Your code is a bit of a tangle.  I'm not sure of all that you're trying to do with it, but here is the approach that I would use to insert a couple of arguments into each plot in a table:

```
ClearAll[testHolder]

Attributes[testHolder] = {HoldFirst};

testHolder[m_?MatrixQ, rest : OptionsPattern[{Graphics, Grid}]] :=
  Grid[
    MapIndexed[Hold, Unevaluated[m], {2}] /.
      Hold[head_[args__], idx_] :> 
        head[args, Joined -> True, PlotLabel -> idx],
    Sequence @@ FilterRules[{rest}, Options@Grid]
  ]

testHolder[
 {{DateListPlot[dateARList, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   DateListPlot[dateARList, PlotStyle -> Blue]}}, 
 Background -> Yellow, Frame -> True ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]