# ScalingFunctions option works for ListPlot but only if there's no Frame: how to work around this?

Tags: plotting

Mathematica has quite a nice [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) option to `BarChart`, `BubbleChart` and the various financial charting functions, which simplifies log scaling, reverse scales and so on. Consider:

```
test = FoldList[0.85 #1 + #2 &, 0., 
  Abs@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 3], 25]]

{0., 1.40961, 4.59418, 9.49233, 11.4004, 9.93797, 11.0347, 11.0437, 
9.39412, 8.46501, 10.5416, 10.3413, 9.60696, 8.47968, 9.45521, 
9.44406, 12.3554, 15.3821, 17.8863, 15.5349, 17.2376, 18.3164, 
 18.5506, 16.459, 14.6381, 13.7955}

BarChart[test, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

```
BarChart[test, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", Frame -> True]
```

[image]

As has been [previously noted on the site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5718/8), the option actually works for `ListPlot` and `ListLinePlot` (but not `DateListPlot`) as well, even though this fact is not documented.

```
ListLinePlot[test, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Reverse"}]
```

[image]

However that breaks down where there is a frame. The tick labels (`FrameTicks`) are now the *rescaled* values, not the original values. The data are correctly rescaled.

```
ListLinePlot[test, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Reverse"}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Obviously the undocumented insertion of this functionality into `ListPlot` and `ListLinePlot` only affected `Ticks` and not `FrameTicks`.

Is there any way to get the correct tick labels back?
Even better, is there a reasonably straightforward way to use `OptionValue[ScalingFunctions]` to ensure that *custom* tick mark placement is correct when the data have been rescaled like this?

Comment: When I specify `PlotRange` it never seems to take `ScalingFunction` into account, even in the documented uses. I could imagine that `PlotRange` is used in the `FrameTicks` calculation. If this turns out to be too hard, maybe you can use this work-around: `BarChart[test, Frame -> True, ScalingFunctions -> "Reverse",
 Joined -> Automatic, 
 ChartStyle -> Directive[Red, FaceForm[], EdgeForm[]]
 ]` However you can only apply `ScalingFunctions` to the `y` axis here.

Comment: @Jens that's very clever, thank, but unfortunately only it works if you only have one series. In my actual application, I have a set of custom functions to plot various kinds of plots with highly customised settings, so that they fit nicely in my [multipanel graphs](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6883/8)

Comment: FWIW, when thinking of a similar application, :) , I put the undocumented use of `ScalingFunction` in the too hard basket and went with a switch to `ListLogPlot` and similar.

Answer (score 3):

Extracting tick locations with `AbsoluteOptions` appears promising, despite error messages.

```
g = ListLogPlot[test];

Show[g, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> AbsoluteOptions[g, Ticks][[1, 2]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am using `ListLogPlot` as a proxy for `ScalingFunctions`.  Again, v7 works differently so I see little point in me carefully tweaking this method, but I think this shows that it should be possible.

Comment: Sorry, this was the one that the comment "
It's a good idea, but if one is drawing a `ListLogPlot` anyway one may as well just do that instead of using `ScalingFunctions`." was about

Comment: @verbeia With mr.wiz at v7 this is the closest he could get to answering with a tested answer. The intention is to replace the ListLogPlot with your plot and ScalingFunction.

Answer (score 1):

Version 7 doesn't support `ScalingFunctions` so I cannot test this, and I suppose that `Overlay` (also absent from v7) may work better.

Nevertheless here is one approach that may work with modification:

```
ListLinePlot[
  test,
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Reverse"},
  ImagePadding -> 20, AxesOrigin -> #
] & /@ {{0, 0}, {Length@test, Max@test}};

ImageCompose @@ %
```

[image]

Here it is with `Overlay`: not pixelated, but still some clashes of ticks.

```
Overlay[ListLinePlot[test, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Reverse"}, 
ImagePadding -> 20, AxesOrigin -> #] & /@ {{0, 0}, {Length@test, 
Max@test}}]
```

[image]

It turns out that you need to scale the values of the `AxesOrigin` according to the scaling function you want to use. In this case, one must `Log` the x-coordinate and reverse the sign of the y-coordinate.

```
Overlay[ListLinePlot[test, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Reverse"}, 
    PlotRange -> All, ImagePadding -> 20, AxesOrigin -> #] & /@ {{0, 
    0}, {Log@Length@test, -Max[test]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1: certainly food for thought, but there are some strange overlaps.

Comment: @Verbeia thanks for the image.  I am surprised to see that the lower "frame" is missing; can you tell why?  Also, I posted another answer that is rough but promising.

Comment: @Verbeia it just hit me: with `"Reverse"` working that should probably be `Min@test` -- would you try that, please?

Comment: Yes, but I realised that isn't the issue  - one actually has to rescale the points for the AxisOrigin: `{Log@Length@test, -Max[test]}}` in this case. Given that, it will probably be easier for me to just catch the value of the option and change the head of the plotting function to `ListLogPlot` or `ListLogLogPlot` depending on its value. The tick labels inside the plot area would also have to be fixed.

Comment: @Verbeia I agree this is not looking good.  Do you think my second answer is more promising?

Comment: @Verbeia My assumption was that the scaling function is not `Log`.  Further, I was not suggesting using `ListLogPlot` but rather `ListLinePlot` with `ScalingFunctions` and attempting the same extraction and replacement.  Have you tried this?