# Creating a grid of plots

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm really a noob on *Mathematica*. I would like to create a layout of multiple plots in *Mathematica*.

I've a function that calculates the solution, over time, of a system of differential equations. The results are to be plotted. In order to compare different solutions, I want a plot showing a 6X6 grid of `LogPlot`s.

I'm adding an example of my code

```
function[a0_, b0_, c0_, d0_, e0_, f0_] :=
  Block[{replacerules, sssol},
    replacerules = {a -> a0, b -> b0, c -> c0, d -> d0};
    sssol  = NSolve[Sys /. replacerules, {x,y,z}], ];
    numint = NDSolve[ SysDiff /. sssol ,{x,y,z},{t, 0, 100},];
    p = LogPlot[x[t] /.numint, y[t] /.numint, z[t] /.numint];
    Return[p]]

Manipulate[
  GraphicsGrid[ Table[function[a, b, c, d, e, f], 
  {a, -1, 4}, 
  {b, -1, 4}]],
  {c, -10, -4},
  {d,  -4,  2, 1},
  {e,   1, 20, 1}]
```

This is a really really simplified version of the code. I hope it can help.

My function takes as input some parameters and uses them to calculate the solution of a system of differential equations. Then everything is plotted with the help of Manipulate and Table to combine different parameters values.

Comment: Look at `GraphicsGrid`.

Comment: I've been trying to use it, but it gives me  a matrix of subplot where is almost not possible to see nothing(the size of the Plot are to small and they don't show not even a small part of the wawes). So I was wondering if there is a better way to do it

Comment: @Yyrkoon Try adding to your question a simplified example of your code - people may be able to suggest how you can improve it. Without seeing it, it's hard to say what can be improved...

Comment: I did not manage to execute your code, there appears to be some errors in it. But I think that in principle my answer stands. Try `ImageSize`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(6877)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6877/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming Anon's interpretation of your question is correct, you could also use the answer I gave [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6882/245). Just copy the code from that answer, starting with

```
Options[plotGrid] = {ImagePadding -> 40};
plotGrid[l_List, w_, h_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := ...
```

and then execute the following to get a grid of log plots that all share their common axes:

```
pt = Table[
   LogPlot[{x^{m x}, Exp[n x], x!}, {x, 1, 5}, Axes -> None, 
    Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, PlotRangePadding -> {0.2, .8}, 
    GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {1.1, 20000}], {m, 1, 6}, {n,
     1, 6}];

plotGrid[pt, 600, 600]
```

[image: log grid]

Here, I added the logarithmic grid lines just for illustration. Also, you could adjust `PlotRangePadding` to move the frame labels further away from each other. This kind of dense packing of plots works best if you make sure all plots have the same `PlotRange`, as I did above.

In the function `plotGrid` I'm using here, the first argument is the list of plots to be arranged on a grid, and the next two arguments are the `ImageSize` dimensions of the overall plot.

Comment: aaaah, my eyes.

Comment: @s0rce He did say it's a 6x6 grid... but better not look directly at it for more than 2 seconds.

Comment: Jens, do you not think this question is effectively a duplicate of the one you linked?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I had been hoping to get some feedback for clarification, but it looks like there's nothing more to it, and in that case it really *is* effectively a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry for the delay,
Thank you so much it worked!

Answer (score 7):

Here's some code that demonstrates your problem and the solution.

```
plots = Table[Plot[a x^b, {x, 0, 2}], {a, 1, 6}, {b, 1, 6}];
```

Without `ImageSize`, as you mention, the plots are really small using `GraphicsGrid`:

```
GraphicsGrid[plots]
```

However, with `ImageSize` they can be made arbitrarily large:

```
GraphicsGrid[plots, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

Comment: I also wasn't able to make much of the example code in the question, so +1 for giving the "most likely" solution.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried also your suggestion but i was still having the same problem!