# Gridlines overrule PlotRange

Tags: plotting, grid-lines, graphics

edit at the end

---

I encountered an interesting bug (?) when plotting where if a Gridline is outside the boundaries set by PlotRange, then the plot appears distorted and automatically resizes so that the full span of the image includes the 'invisible' gridline.

Here is a quick example where I plot two frequencies at **180** and **160** Hz, specify the PlotRange to only look at the desired range, but if I introduce a gridline at **300** Hz, which lies outside the visible range, it distorts.

```
nSamples = 2^14;
sRate = 2^14;
time = Array[# &, nSamples, {0, nSamples/sRate}];
x1 = Sin[2 \[Pi] 180 time];                                           \
                                (* generate the first frequency *)
x2 = Sin[2 \[Pi] 160 time];                                           \
                                (* generate the second frequency *)
x = (x1 + x2)/2;
fft = (Abs@
   Fourier[x, 
    FourierParameters -> {-1, 
      1}])^2;            (* generate power spectrum*)
fSpace = Table[(n - 1.) sRate/Length[fft], {n, 
   Length[fft]}]; (* create the frequency space *)
ListLinePlot[{fSpace, fft}\[Transpose], 
 PlotRange -> {{150, 210}, Full}, 
 GridLines -> {{300}, None}] (* plot *)
```

[image]

For reference, this is how it looks like if the gridline is within the boundary (gridline at 180 rather than 300)

[image]

Does anyone know how can this be circumvented?
I must note that in both cases the ImageSize is fixed.

**EDIT**: I'm using v.13.0 on Windows and the following options:

```
SetOptions[{ListPlot}, 
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, ImageSize -> 350, 
  PlotStyle -> 
   Evaluate[{AbsolutePointSize[10], cols[[#]]} & /@ 
     Range[Length@cols]], PlotRange -> Full, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 14, AbsoluteThickness[2]]];
```

with "cols" being a list with RBG colours.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior in your first plot (v. 12.3.1 on Win10-64). Particularly, I notice that your plot uses non-standard colors even though no style directives have bee included in your code, so I wonder if you have set some global preferences that are impacting other behaviors in unexpected ways. What version are you using? What OS?

Comment: Hi!
I've added more info as an edit. I don't think they should interfere, but maybe. will test them out later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [this fantastic little trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145446) does the trick:

Where you simply set `ImageSize->Automatic->size`