# How to make plots on a Grid the same size?

Tags: plotting, grid-layouts

I have the following Grid:

```
Plot100 = 
  Plot[Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 100}, 
   Frame -> True];
Plot200 = Plot[t^2, {t, 0, 200}, Frame -> True];
Grid[{{Plot100, Plot200}}]
```

How can I make the two constituent plots the same size despite the differing plot ranges on respective y-axes?

Comment: I would recommend using `ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]` or specify `ImageSize` for each subplot.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145442/exporting-an-image-so-that-the-plotrange-has-a-fixed-size-in-the-output/145446#145446

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot100 = 
  Plot[Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 100}, 
   Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Automatic -> 300];
Plot200 = 
  Plot[t^2, {t, 0, 200}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 20000}, 
   ImageSize -> Automatic -> 300];
Grid[{{Plot100, Plot200}}, Spacings -> 3]
```