# graphicsgrid white space

Tags: graphics

I'm working with mathematica 9.0 making a graphic grid. Here's my image:
[image]

I'd like to know if it's possible to make the two cells from right only one and if there's some manner to rid of the white space between top and bottom cells.
Thank you so much

---

I've solved the issue of the dividers. I plotted the red plot within the blue/orange. Now I have this picture
[image]

Now it could be nice to eliminate the y-axis from the right graphic, and join the two graphics. Does anybody know how to make this?
Thanks

Comment: Please add your own code and make more clear, what do you mean with "to make the two cells from right only one".

Comment: The following post may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818888/how-to-make-a-grid-of-plots-with-a-single-pair-of-framelabels

Comment: Look up the `Spacings` option.

Comment: Also relevant: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6877/8