# Aligning Overlay and GraphicsGrid plots

Tags: plotting, graphics, overlay

I need to make several plots displaying a `ListPlot` overlaid with a `Histogram` and close to it (ideally even sharing X axis) a Plot. After reading answers to similar questions, I've got his far:

```
randomData2 = Table[{RandomVariate[dist], RandomReal[]}, {i, 1, 3000}];

opts = {AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 50}; 
plot1 = ListPlot[ randomData2,
            PlotMarkers -> {".", 10}, Frame -> {True,True,True, True},
            FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {True, None}}, opts ];
plot2 = Histogram[ randomData2[[All, 1]], 50, "ProbabilityDensity",
            ChartStyle -> Red, ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5]],
            FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Red}, opts];
plot3 = Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, 0, 5},
            PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], AspectRatio -> 1,
            PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 50, Frame -> True];
plot4 = Overlay[{plot1, plot2}, ImageSize -> Full]

GraphicsGrid[{{plot3}, {plot4}}]
```

My questions:

1. The `Overlay` seems to be a little "moved". Numbers and ticks in the X
   Axis are not exactly on top of the previous. I could hide one, but I
   guess that the plots are not exactly aligned. How to align them
   exactly and automatically?
2. How to make the plots in the `GraphicsGrid` of the same size, scale
   and aligned so that one can easily compare the results in the upper
   and lower graphic?

I cannot manually align them with padding as I have to use the same structure with many different graphics of different sizes and ranges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Overlay` is not so useful for precisely aligning graphics objects with respect to the coordinate system of the `Graphics` itself. For that, you should use [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inset.html), or directly apply [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Show.html).

A quick way to do this is by using the function `plotGrid` from [my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6882/245), which is built on `Inset`. To make it work, we have to adjust the `PlotRange` for each of the plots so that they can be stuck together seamlessly.

I combine `plot1` and `plot2` using `Show`, and then put the result in the form of a `List` that mirrors the shape of the graphics grid I want to produce. This is then fed into `plotGrid`:

```
dist = NormalDistribution[]; randomData2 = 
 Table[{RandomVariate[dist], RandomReal[]}, {i, 1, 3000}];
opts = {AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 50};

plot1 = ListPlot[randomData2, PlotMarkers -> {".", 10}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 5}, {0, 1.04}}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {True, None}}, opts];
plot2 = Histogram[randomData2[[All, 1]], 50, "ProbabilityDensity", 
   ChartStyle -> Red, ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5]], 
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Red}, opts];


plot3 = Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, -3, 5}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium],
    Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-3, 5}, {-.04, .4}}];

plotGrid[{{plot3}, {Show[plot1, plot2]}}, 500, 300]
```

[image: plotgrid]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great function and great answer!