# use of grid to stick different plots

Tags: plotting

I have four plots that can be figured besides each other in `Grid` command.

```
m = {{1, 4, 0, 0}, {3, 4, 1, 3}, {0, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 0, 1, 3}};
s = Grid[Partition[
   ListPlot[#, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.03], 
     Frame -> True, Filling -> Bottom] & /@ 
     Table[Transpose[m][[i]], {i, 1, Length[m]}], 2]]
```

the resulted plot was as
[image]

How can I delete the space distance between different plots and stick them to each other. Although, some FrameTicks maybe can be hidden but it is not important, the significant case is sticking the plot.

Comment: Look up `Spacings`.

Comment: Based on your comment I used Spacings -> {-0.75,-0.75}, I think it satisfies my goal. thanks a bunch.

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6877/do-i-have-to-code-each-case-of-this-grid-full-of-plots-separately\

Comment: @Verbeia, Your comment is so wonderful, It is exact waht I was search.

Comment: That's great, Ackaran! If that's the case, if you don't mind, I'm going to link your question explicitly to that one. This is called "closing as a duplicate" and is not a criticism or a bad thing. It helps future site visitors find that answer if that's what they are looking for. Thanks for your question! You might notice that the prior question was mine - I had the exact same issue a while ago.

Comment: It doesn't matter, your work guides other user to direct way in this case.