# Combine graphics with GraphicsGrid

Tags: graphics

```
  FlatEllipsoid[x_, y_, dz_] := dz^2 + x^2/25 + y^2/9

RandomOffsets = 
  Table[RandomReal[UniformDistribution[{-1, 1}]], {i, 100}];

g=Table[ContourPlot[
  FlatEllipsoid[x, y, RandomOffsets[[i*j]]] == 1, {x, -5, 
   5}, {y, -3.5, 3.5}, PlotRange -> {{-5.5, 5.5}, {-3.5, 3.5}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 0.6], {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

When I wrap g to `GraphicsGrid` it gives a messy output. What is the proper way to combine the graphic objects of `g`?

Comment: `GraphicsGrid` is not bad per se, you can e.g. simply use a dedicated `ImageSize` either in your for your plots or the `GraphicsGrid`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get what you want out of `GraphicsGrid`, by writing `GraphicsGrid[g,ImageSize -> n]` where `n` is the total width of the grid, but I still find that it hogs more system resources than `Grid`.  But `Grid` will simply display the plots at their own predefined size, you can't adjust the overall size of the `Grid`.

That's why I stay away from `GraphicsGrid`, `GraphicsRow` and `GraphicsColumn` whenever possible, I just use `Grid`

```
Grid[g]
```

[image]

But better than that, use Jens's [plotGrid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6882/9490) function to get rid of all that white space and duplication of tick marks.

```
 plotGrid[g, 1200, 720]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I found this in an old book. It uses `GraphicsArray`. I thought `GraphicsArray` has been replaced by `GraphicsGrid`.

Comment: Apparently it is still there, but the help page says "As of Version 6.0, GraphicsArray has been superseded by GraphicsGrid and Grid."

Comment: Both answers are great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `FrameTicks -> None`

```
g =
  Table[
   ContourPlot[
    FlatEllipsoid[x, y, RandomOffsets[[i*j]]] == 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -3.5, 3.5},
    FrameTicks -> None,
    PlotRange -> {{-5.5, 5.5}, {-3.5, 3.5}},
    AspectRatio -> 0.6],
   {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 5}];
```

And then

```
Grid[g, Spacings -> {-1, -1}]
```

[image]

Or

```
Grid[g, Spacings -> {-1, -1}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Or label them somwhow with `Epilog` and `Text`

```
g =
 Table[
  ContourPlot[
   FlatEllipsoid[x, y, RandomOffsets[[i*j]]] == 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -3.5, 3.5},
   FrameTicks -> None,
   Epilog -> Text[Row[{i, " ", j}]],
   PlotRange -> {{-5.5, 5.5}, {-3.5, 3.5}},
   AspectRatio -> 0.6],
  {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 5}];

Grid[g, Spacings -> {-1, -1}]
```

[image]

You can use `ArrayReshape` to modify the layout:

```
Grid[ArrayReshape[g, {5, 2}], Spacings -> {-1, -1}]
```

[image]