# Why the Spectrogram can't plot correctly?

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis

The same data lead two different graph.

```
Plot[E^(-Pi*(t - 5)^2), {t, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The method to plot the spectrogram use the build-in function:

```
 Samplerate = 20;data = Table[E^(-Pi*(t - 5)^2), {t, 0, 10, 1/Samplerate}];
Spectrogram[data, 10, 2, SampleRate -> Samplerate]
```

[image]

You can see the center is not 5.but if you use the following code(sorry,I don't know how to add a link here,thanks Sjord C. De Vries).
The center is 5.

```
sndData = data;
sndSampleRate = 20;
min = Min[Abs[Fourier[sndData]]];
partSize = 10;
offset = 2;
spectroGramData = Take[20*Log10[Abs[Fourier[#]]/min],{2, partSize/2 // Floor}] & /@ 
Partition[sndData, partSize, offset]; MatrixPlot[
Reverse[spectroGramData\[Transpose]], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
DataRange ->Round[{{0, Length[sndData]/sndSampleRate}, {sndSampleRate/partSize, 
 sndSampleRate/2}}, 0.1], AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 800, 
Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Frequency (Hz)", "Time (s)", "", ""}, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontWeight -> Bold, 12}]
```

[image]

Do I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't really know if what you calculate in your code is the same as what `Spectrogram` is calculating, even aside from the log scale you use.  Just compare the dimensions of the data being plotted,

```
Dimensions@spectroGramData
Dimensions@SpectrogramArray[data, 10, 2]
(* {96, 4} *)
(* {101, 10} *)
```

I can't quite figure out exactly how `SpectrogramArray` is calculating things, but I can say that if you want to have the center of the spectrogram show up in the right spot, you need to increase your sampling rate:

```
plotGrid[
 Transpose@{Table[
    Spectrogram[
     Table[E^(-π*(t - 5.0)^2), {t, 0, 10, 1/Samplerate}], 10, 2, 
     SampleRate -> Samplerate], {Samplerate, {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 30, 50,
       100}}]}
 , 400, 600]
```

[image]

where I'm using Jens's [plotGrid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6882/9490) function to line the plots up nicely.