# Filling smoothed histogram with area representing standard deviation?

Tags: plotting

I've done a cluster analysis on a set of datapoints (listV) and used Mathematica to obtain a smoothed histogram with the x and y axes inverted. To aid visualisation I would like to fill the area underneath the histogram towards the y axis beginning at a value for each histogram determined from the earlier cluster analysis (lets call this A1), with width equal to the standard deviation determined from the analysis as well (A1 ± S1; shown in listA). There is a crude cartoon (Sorry - Paint!) of how it would look like next to a plot of the clusters in question. Due to inverting the x/y axis the Filling command does not seem to work.

**My question is if it would be possible to fill this area for all four datasets in the plot?**

I've also tried RegionPlot but have not managed to get it to work as yet (and am still trying!). A shortened version of the code is shown below. Thanks!

```
listA={{A1, S1},{A2, S2},{A3, S3},{A4, S4}}
listV = {data1[[All, 2]], data2[[All, 2]], data3[[All, 2]], data4[[All, 2]]};
sHV = SmoothHistogram[listV, 0.881, "PDF",
PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic},
ImageSize -> {500, 300},
PlotRange -> {1, 2.5},
];
plotSHV =Show[sHV /. x_Line :> Reverse[x, 3], PlotRange -> {Automatic, {1, 2.5}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]
[image]

**What was done in the end:**

Thank you for the answers. After working a bit more on it I've used the answers below in combination with Jens' function [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6877/do-i-have-to-code-each-case-of-this-grid-full-of-plots-separately), so that the smoothed histogram plots are stacked and look less cluttered. I'm pretty happy so far with the result. I've included the code below. Probably (definitely) not the cleanest, but I hope it helps anyone with a similar problem.

[image]

```
plots1 = {{
   Show[
    {
      SmoothHistogram[data1[[All, 2]], hData1, "PDF"],
      SmoothHistogram[data1[[All, 2]], hData1, "PDF", 
       PlotRange -> {{2, 9}, {0, 0.5}}, Filling -> Axis, 
       FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.75, data1Colour], 
       RegionFunction -> 
        Function[{x, y}, data1shadeMin < x <data1shadeMax]]
      }
     /.
     {
      x_Line:>GeometricTransformation[Rotate[x, -Pi/2, {0, 0}],ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}]],
      x_Polygon:>GeometricTransformation[Rotate[x, -Pi/2, {0, 0}],ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}]]
      },
    plotSettings,
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {2, 9}},
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 2}
    ],
    (*Other plots are omitted, they are just a repeat of this one.*)
    }}

plotSHdata1 = Show
  [
  Rasterize[Grid[{{plotdata1, plotGrid[plots1, 400, 300]}}]],
  Graphics[{Thick, Black, 
    Line[{ImageScaled[{0.3, 0.62}], ImageScaled[{0.96, 0.62}]}]}],
  Graphics[{Thick, Black, 
    Line[{ImageScaled[{0.15, 0.495}], ImageScaled[{0.67, 0.495}]}]}],
  Graphics[{Thick, Black, 
    Line[{ImageScaled[{0.16, 0.48}], ImageScaled[{0.774, 0.48}]}]}],
  Graphics[{Thick, Black, 
    Line[{ImageScaled[{0.29, 0.54}], ImageScaled[{0.874, 0.54}]}]}],

  Epilog -> {
    Inset[
     SwatchLegend[{Orange, Green, Blue, Red}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, 
      LegendLayout -> "Row", LegendFunction -> Framed, 
      LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 17}, LegendMarkerSize -> {12}]
     , ImageScaled[{0.78, 0.063}]
     ],
    Style[{Text["label", ImageScaled[{0.585, 0.97}]]}, labelColour, 
     labelFont],
    Style[{Text["Probability Density Function (PDF)", 
       ImageScaled[{0.78, 0.16}]]}, labelColour, labelFont]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: There seems to be two issues:  (1) How to fill and (2) What to fill.  The "What" is not clear from your statement "the area underneath the histogram towards the y axis with a width that represents the data's standard deviation."  You could fill the central 68.27% of the area but that only has a logical connection to a standard deviation for a normal distribution.  And all of that filling would make for a pretty crowded figure.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I've edited some additional information into the question, and also included a sketch (Paint so a little crude - Sorry!) to give an idea of what area it would be. Yes, it would seem that the figure will be quite crowded - was hoping that a hatched fill would alleviate that and/or figuring out alternatives.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
s = ColorData[1];
d = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[c, 2], 500], {c, 0, 9, 3}];
(*filling Mean ± Std Dev.You may chose other limits*)
lims = MapThread[({#1 - #2, #1 + #2}) &, {Mean /@ d, StandardDeviation /@ d}];

dd = Transpose[{d, lims}];
i = 1;
f[x_] := GeometricTransformation[Rotate[x, -Pi/2, {0, 0}], ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}]]

sHV = Show[{SmoothHistogram[#[[1]], PlotStyle-> s@i, PlotRange-> {{-6, 15}, Automatic}], 
            SmoothHistogram[#[[1]], PlotStyle-> s@i, Filling -> Axis, 
                        RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, #[[2, 1]] < x < #[[2, 2]]], 
                        FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.2], s[i++]]]} & /@ dd];


Show[sHV/. x_Polygon | x_Line:> f@x, 
     PlotRange -> Reverse[PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[sHV, PlotRange]],
     AspectRatio-> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise/know that the RegionFunction could be used to limit the plot range.

Comment: @Zhao It is a nice trick to use when you need two different plotting styles in different regions for the same curve

Answer (score 5):

Define a function using a combination of the options `Mesh`, `MeshShading` and `ColorFunction` to get partially filled histograms:

```
shF = SmoothHistogram[#, Filling -> Axis, 
  Mesh -> {#2}, MeshStyle -> Transparent, MeshShading -> {#3, Directive[Thick,#3]}, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  ColorFunction->Function[{x, y}, If[#2[[1]]<=x<=#2[[2]], Opacity[.4, #3], Transparent]]]&;
```

and a function to flip the axes by post-processing to reverse the elements in the first argument of `GraphicsComplex`:

```
flipF = # /.  GraphicsComplex[p_, x__] :> GraphicsComplex[Reverse /@ p, x] &;
```

Using an input setup similar to belisarius's:

```
d = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[c, 2], 500], {c, 0, 6, 2}];
lims =({#1 - #2, #1 + #2}) & @@@ Thread[{Mean /@ d, StandardDeviation /@ d}];
colors = ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[;; 4]];
ddd = Transpose[{d, lims, colors}];


Show[flipF@Show[shF @@@ ddd], AspectRatio -> 2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]