# Half Plot - half LogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting, ticks, logarithmic-scale

Is it possible to do a plot which is partially `Plot` and partially `LogLinearPlot`? The reference figure is

[image: plot]

We see that the $x$-axis is logarithmic up to `x = 30`, and linear from there on. The only idea I came up with is to use the `plotGrid` function of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6877/do-i-have-to-code-each-case-of-this-grid-full-of-plots-separately/6882#6882), but I am not really satisfied with the result, which is attached below.

[image: plot]

Comment: Another alternative would be to use `Piecewise` and custom ticks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ScalingFunctions` works for `Plot`, but I had to tweak the ticks by hand:

```
ClearAll[sfn, isfn];
SetAttributes[sfn, Listable];
SetAttributes[isfn, Listable];
sfn[x_] := Piecewise[{{x, x < 30}, {30 + Log[x] - Log[30], x >= 30}}];
isfn[y_] := Piecewise[{{y, y < 30}, {30 E^(-30 + y), y >= 30}}];

Plot[
 Sin[2 Log[x]], {x, 1, 10^4},
 ScalingFunctions -> {{sfn, isfn}, None},
 Ticks -> {MapAt[
    isfn,
    Flatten[{
      Charting`ScaledTicks[{sfn, isfn}][sfn[0.], sfn[30.], {6, 5}],
      Charting`ScaledTicks[{sfn, isfn}][sfn[30.], sfn[10.^4], {5, 5}]}, 1],
    {All, 1}], Automatic},
 PlotRange -> All,
 AxesOrigin -> {30, 0}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]