# How to generate common axes with GraphicsGrid and save plot as pdf when using Legended without cell number

Tags: legending, pdf-format

I would like to remove y-axes with keeping plot's consistency and then save it as pdf without cell number (I used save selection as), it is Ok if saved as an image but not working with pdf?! Here the used code:

```
t1=DensityPlot[Sin[y]^2 Cos[6 x], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 5},ImageSize -> 240, Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> {{40, 0}, {50, 5}},FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",PlotPoints -> 50]  

t2=DensityPlot[Sin[y]^2 Cos[3 x], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 5},ImageSize -> 240, Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> {{40, 0}, {50, 5}},FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",PlotPoints -> 50]

t3=DensityPlot[Sin[y]^2 Cos[4 x], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 5},ImageSize -> 240, Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> {{40, 0}, {50, 5}},FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",PlotPoints -> 50]

t4=DensityPlot[Sin[y]^2 Cos[2 x], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 5},ImageSize -> 240, Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> {{40, 0}, {50, 5}},FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",PlotPoints -> 50]  

Legended[GraphicsGrid[Partition[{t1, t2, t3, t4}, 2],Spacings -> {-70,-70}],Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}},LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12,Red, Bold},LegendMarkerSize -> 200], {{1.52, .59}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: like this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6877/5478?

Comment: But this is not working for Density plot?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I found  the post earlier and tried to implement it to density plot but could not

Comment: Jens' answer work out of hand for me, could you elaborate?

Comment: One more thing, I would like to control the `ImagePadding`  in each side of the resulted plot from `plotGrid`. I tried   ` ImagePadding -> {{40, 10}, {20, 5}}` but did not work?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use LevelScheme for this.  Clearly, it's more involved than GraphicsGrid[].  However, the control is unbeatable.

Load package & set defaults

```
Needs["LevelScheme`LevelScheme`"]
A4LEN = (11 3)/4;
SetOptions[DensityPlot, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotPoints -> 50];
```

define a color bar

```
cbar = ContourPlot[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True,
  Contours -> 50,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}
  ];
```

then construct the figure using

```
ofig = Figure[{
   SetOptions[SchemeObject, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 10],
   ScaledLabel[{.5, .97}, "Title", FontSize -> 12, 
    FontWeight -> Bold, Offset -> {0, 0}],
   ScaledLabel[{.5, .94}, "Subtitle", FontSize -> 10, 
    FontSlant -> Italic, Offset -> {0, 0}],
   Multipanel[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {2, 3},
    Margin -> 50,
    XPlotRanges -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 1}},
    YPlotRanges -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}},
    XFrameLabels -> {"X", "X", ""}, BufferB -> 5,
    YFrameLabels -> {"Y", "Y"}, BufferL -> 7,
    XFrameTicks -> {LinTicks[-2, 2, 1, 1], LinTicks[-2, 2, 1, 1],
      LinTicks[0, 1, 1, 1]},
    YFrameTicks -> {
      {LinTicks[0, 5, 1, 1], LinTicks[0, 5, 1, 1], 
       LinTicks[-1, 1, .5, 1]},
      {LinTicks[0, 5, 1, 1], LinTicks[0, 5, 1, 1], 
       LinTicks[-1, 1, 1, 1]}},
    YGapSizes -> .1, XGapSizes -> {.1, .2},
    YPanelSizes -> {1, 1},
    XPanelSizes -> {1, 1, .1},
    Order -> Vertical, ShowPanelLetter -> False
    ],
   FigurePanel[{1, 1}],
   RawGraphics@DensityPlot[Sin[y]^2 Cos[6 x], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 5}],
   FigurePanel[{2, 1}],
   RawGraphics@DensityPlot[Sin[y]^2 Cos[4 x], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 5}],
   FigurePanel[{1, 2}],
   RawGraphics@DensityPlot[Sin[y]^2 Cos[3 x], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 5}],
   FigurePanel[{2, 2}], 
   RawGraphics@DensityPlot[Sin[y]^2 Cos[2 x], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 5}],
   FigurePanel[{1, 3}, ShowPanelLetter -> False, 
    ShowTickLabels -> {False, True, False, False},
    XPlotRange -> {0, 1}, YPlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
    PanelAdjustments -> {{0, 0}, {.75, -.35}}],
   ScaledLabel[{1, .5}, "Lable", Offset -> {0, -2}, 
    Orientation -> -90 \[Degree]],
   RawGraphics@cbar
   },
  ImageSize -> (1*72) *  {A4LEN, A4LEN} (* adjust for page size *)
  ]
```

[image: image ...]

Save as PDF using

```
Export["test.pdf", ofig];
```

Comment: Thanx a lot! @dwa