# TickMarks get different length inside function plotGrid

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, ticks

Mathematica 11.2 or earlier: I want to create a grid of plots and found this one by Jens excellent: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6882/245 :

```
Options[plotGrid] = {ImagePadding -> 40};plotGrid[l_List, w_, h_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{nx, ny, sidePadding = OptionValue[plotGrid, ImagePadding], topPadding = 0, widths,   heights,   dimensions,   positions,   frameOptions =     FilterRules[{opts},      FilterRules[Options[Graphics],       Except[{ImagePadding, Frame, FrameTicks}]]]},  {ny, nx} = Dimensions[l];  widths = (w - 2 sidePadding)/nx Table[1, {nx}];  widths[[1]] = widths[[1]] + sidePadding;  widths[[-1]] = widths[[-1]] + sidePadding;  heights = (h - 2 sidePadding)/ny Table[1, {ny}];  heights[[1]] = heights[[1]] + sidePadding;  heights[[-1]] = heights[[-1]] + sidePadding;  positions =    Transpose@Partition[Tuples[Prepend[Accumulate[Most[#]], 0] & /@ {widths, heights}],  ny]; Graphics[   Table[    Inset[     Show[      l[[ny-j+1, i]],      ImagePadding -> {        {If[i == 1, sidePadding, 0], If[i == nx, SidePadding, 0]},        {If[j == 1, sidePadding, 0],          If[j == ny, sidePadding, topPadding]}        },      AspectRatio -> Full      ],     positions[[j, i]],     {Left, Bottom},     {widths[[i]], heights[[j]]}],    {i, 1, nx}, {j, 1, ny}    ],   PlotRange -> {{0, w}, {0, h}},   ImageSize -> {w, h},   Evaluate@Apply[Sequence, frameOptions]   ]  ]
```

But here is the problem: I need customised FrameTicks like in

```
test=Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 180}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {Union[Table[{i, i, {0, -0.02}}, {i, 0, 180, 30}], Table[{i, ""}, {i, 0, 180, 5}]], Automatic}]
```

where the ticks at 0, 30 etc are nice and long:

[image: single-plot-correct-ticks]

But now I execute

```
plotGrid[{{test, test}, {test, test}}, 500, 500]
```

and these long Tick Marks disappear. [What you see are only the "short" tickmarks which overlap with the long ones]:

[image: array with wrong tickmarks]

However, if I use a ridiculously large value for the tickmark length, then they are of course outsized in the original plot, but they are decent in the plotGrid:

```
test = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 180}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> nion[Table[{i, i, {0, -6(*!!!*)}}, {i, 0, 180, 30}], Table[{i, ""}, {i, 0, 180, 5}]], Automatic}]
plotGrid[{{test, test}, {test, test}}, 500, 500]
```

[image: single plot wrong ticks]  [image: array with acceptable tickmarks]

I know one should never just paste from the web and then complain, but I cannot figure out what goes wrong inside plotGrid.

Any ideas are much appreciated!