# How to use GraphicsRow(or other commands) to plot 2 figures with only one x-y axis?

Tags: plotting, graphics, probability-or-statistics

I can use the following command to plot two figures together.

```
a = DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];

b = DensityPlot[Sin[3 x y^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];

GraphicsRow[{a, b}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

However, this two figure has their own x-y axis.

What I want is a picture like this:

[image]

They share their x-y axis.

How to plot a figure like this?

Comment: maybe this [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6877/do-i-have-to-code-each-case-of-this-grid-full-of-plots-separately) may help

Comment: Take a look at LevelScheme  (https://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/)