# Replicating a PlotGrid without using Resources

Tags: plotting, graphics, resourcefunction

I want to create stacked plots which have a shared x and y axis label. I found an article [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid) from Wolfram, which does exactly what I want but uses `ResoruceFucntion`. This is dreadfully slow. Is there a way to replicate the effect shown in the article using standard Mathematica commands.

Here is an example from the page I referenced of what I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: What part of using the resource function is slow for you?  Running the documentation examples take about 0.25 seconds on my machine via ```First@RepeatedTiming[ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{{Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True]}, {Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True]}}]]```.  To make that faster you need to look at the definition for `PlotGrid`

Comment: Also look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6882/9490)