# Stacking multiple graphs together in separate plots

Tags: plotting, graphics, grid-layouts

I have been working on a problem where I wanted to stack multiple graphs on top of each other in the following format

[image: The expected output]

I tried to look for solutions to do the same but I could not. The closest I could get to was the `Graphics` command but in that case, there was undesired spacing between the graphs. Since all my graphs have the same values in the horizontal axis this looks a lot better. I understand the concepts of frames and my only issue is the spacing and alignment between the graphs. Is the solution to reduce the space in the `Graphics` command or there another solution?

Thank you to every suggestion or recommendation towards this.

Comment: Isn’t there an option for this now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid

```
ResourceFunction[
        "PlotGrid"][{{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
                FrameLabel -> {None, x}]}, {Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True,
                    FrameLabel -> {None, x}]}}, FrameLabel -> {2 Pi t, None}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Simply use Column:

```
pl = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
Column[{pl, pl}, Frame -> All, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you do it as a frame with ticks as shown in the OP?

Comment: You can e.g. try: pl = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"];
Column[{pl, pl}, Frame -> All, Spacings -> 0]  Note, "Column" is not responsible for the ticks, it is the Plot function who does it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way  where you can control the size along x and y of each subfigure

```
plot1 = With[{XZ = 210, YZ = 70}, 
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> Automatic -> {XZ, YZ}, ImagePadding -> 80, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, Axes -> False]];
Grid[{{plot1}, {plot1}, {plot1}}, Spacings -> {-12, -12}]
```

[image]

and you can do even more with this approach such as  this configration

```
plotver = 
  With[{XZ = 70, YZ = 218}, 
   Plot[x, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> Automatic -> {XZ, YZ}, ImagePadding -> 80, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, Axes -> False]];
Grid[{{g, plotver}}, Spacings -> {-11, -12.}, 
 BaselinePosition -> Bottom]
```

[image]

and have a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6877/do-i-have-to-code-each-case-of-this-grid-full-of-plots-separately) might help further

Answer (score 2):

This use of `ImagePadding` works on a simple example:

```
pTop = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   ImagePadding -> {{All, All}, {0, All}}];
pMid = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   ImagePadding -> {{All, All}, {0, 0}}];
pBot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
   ImagePadding -> {{All, All}, {All, 0}}, Axes -> False];
Column[{pTop, pMid, pBot}, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]

Often the vertical scales require different numbers of digits, which in turn leads to different paddings used to display the plots.  As far as I know, this is most easily dealt with by setting the left `ImagePadding` through trial and error.

```
lMargin = Scaled[0.05];
pTop = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   ImagePadding -> {{lMargin, All}, {0, All}}];
pMid = Plot[10 Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   ImagePadding -> {{lMargin, All}, {0, 0}}];
pBot = Plot[100 Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
   ImagePadding -> {{lMargin, All}, {All, 0}}, Axes -> False];
Column[{pTop, pMid, pBot}, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]