# Plotting different plot in a single grid frame without combining them

Tags: plotting, graphics, grid-layouts, plot-themes, grid-mathematica

[image: image shows three different plots in a single grid frame without combining them.]

**We can show the plot together, but how do we show different plots in the same grid frame without combining them? I have tried the `GraphicsColumn` and it shows the plots separately.**

Comment: Does [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6882/78049) answer your question?

Comment: The resource function `PlotGrid` is your friend: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid

Comment: Thanks this what I was looking for. Thankyou for the help

Answer (score 4):

```
Show[
 Plot[Sin[x] + 0, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 Plot[Cos[x] + 2, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Darker @ Green],
 Graphics[AxisObject[{"Horizontal", 0}]],
 Graphics[AxisObject[{"Horizontal", 2}]],
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Without `Ticklabels` (like in the image of the question)

```
Show[
 Plot[Sin[x] + 0, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 Plot[Cos[x] + 2, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Darker @ Green],
 Graphics[AxisObject[{"Horizontal", 0}, TickLabels -> {None, All}]],
 Graphics[AxisObject[{"Horizontal", 2}, TickLabels -> {None, All}]],
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `PlotLayout` option if the $x$-axis of your plot is not changing instead of using `Grid` or `GraphicsColumn` for a column representation.

A sample code:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x] }, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotLayout -> "Column", 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, AspectRatio -> 0.5]
```

[image]

However, if I understood the "*representation of different plots in the same grid frame without combining them*" correctly, what you want is something like this:

```
data = Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi, 0.1}];

dwd = DiscreteWaveletTransform[data, Automatic, 3]
WaveletListPlot[dwd, PlotLayout -> "CommonXAxis"]
```

[image]

If this is not what you want, please share the equations responsible for the above plot.