# How to make plot and a graphics have vertical axes align in grid

Tags: plotting, graphics

How can I modify the following code so that the vertical axes in both the graphics and plot align up? I think the aspect ratio for the plot is good. It appears that changing the ImageSize of the plot works, but I don't exactly what to change it to so that the vertical axes align exactly.

```
Manipulate[
  Grid[{
    {Graphics[{Circle[],Blue, PointSize[Large], Point[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}]},
       Axes -> True],
     Show[
       Plot[Sin[θ], {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
         Ticks -> {Range[0, 2 π, π/2], Automatic}, 
         PlotStyle -> Red],
       Graphics[
         {Blue, Line[{{θ, 0}, {θ, Sin[θ]}}], 
          PointSize[Large], Point[{θ, Sin[θ]}]}]]}},
    Frame -> All],
  {{θ, π/6}, 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: See, for instance, [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4059/aligning-plot-axes-in-a-graphics-object?rq=1). By the way, this is the first link that shows up in the `Related` links in the sidebar to the right. It is a good idea to search this site first for the answer to your question!

Comment: Thanks.  Using the accepted answer, I evaluated the padding function and I got my ip to be {21, 9}. However, it did not improve the vertical axes much.

Answer (score 3):

```
plotrangeconditions = Sequence[PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]];

Manipulate[
 GraphicsGrid[
  {{
    Graphics[
     {Circle[], Blue, PointSize[Large], Point[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}]}, Axes -> True,
     (*Introduce explicit plotrange and padding*)
     plotrangeconditions
    ],
    Show[
     Plot[Sin[θ], {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, Ticks -> {Range[0, 2 π, π/2], Automatic}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
     Graphics[{Blue, Line[{{θ, 0}, {θ, Sin[θ]}}], PointSize[Large], Point[{θ, Sin[θ]}]}],
     (*Introduce same plotrange and padding*)
     plotrangeconditions,
     (*Select a size*)
     ImageSize -> Medium
    ]
    }},
  Frame -> All
 ],
 {{θ, π/6}, 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. It seems that using GraphicsGrid and changing the ImageSize are the major factors here, and both seem to be required. Why does changing the ImageSize on only the second graphic make this work. Does GraphicsGrid make all have the same ImageSize somehow?

Answer (score 2):

```
 Manipulate[
     Grid[{{
        Graphics[{Circle[], Blue, PointSize[Large], 
          Point[{Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]}]},
         Axes -> True,
         ImagePadding -> 80,
         ImageSize -> 400],
        Show[
         Plot[Sin[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi},
          Ticks -> {Range[0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/2], Automatic},
          PlotStyle -> Red,
          ImageSize -> 400],
         Graphics[
          {Blue, Line[{{\[Theta], 0}, {\[Theta], Sin[\[Theta]]}}],
           PointSize[Large], Point[{\[Theta], Sin[\[Theta]]}]}]]}},
      Frame -> All],
     {{\[Theta], \[Pi]/6}, 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am curious how you came up with the 80 for ImagePadding and 400 for ImageSize. Both numbers seem to be important since changing either one loses the desired effect. Also, why not add the ImagePadding option to both graphics. I am just trying to understand how to use this technique again on a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that everybody is working too hard on this problem. It can be solved with a very simple `GraphicRow` expression in which the images in the row are forced to have the same height.

```
Manipulate[
  GraphicsRow[{
    Graphics[{Circle[], Blue, PointSize[Large], Point[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}]},
      ImageSize -> {Automatic, 150},
      Axes -> True],
    Plot[Sin[θ], {θ, 0, 2 Pi},
      ImageSize -> {Automatic, 150},
      Ticks -> {Range[0, 2 π, π/2], Automatic},
      PlotStyle -> Red,
      Epilog ->
       {Blue, Line[{{θ, 0}, {θ, Sin[θ]}}],
        PointSize[Large], Point[{θ, Sin[θ]}]}]},
    Frame -> All],
  {{θ, π/6}, 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: graphics]

Comment: The OP asked for a method "so that the vertical axes in both the graphics and plot align up". Your vertical axes are very close, but they do not really line up perfectly. For instance, note that the right plot's vertical axis reaches up to 1.1, whereas the one in the left `Graphics` expression does not. In my opinion @eldo's answer suffers from the same problem. However, perhaps I'm reading too much in the OP's language.

Comment: I wouldn't say you are reading too much into the problem. I would say that making the sure the corresponding y-values are at the same height is the most important thing.