# Combining multiple graphs in one photo without consulting external programs

Tags: plotting, graphics, simplifying-expressions, graphics3d, expression-manipulation

I want to add many plots from Mathematica into one picture and export as a PDF. Usually I select the plot and copy it as an image to Word, however the image reduces the accuracy of some plots.

How can I ask Mathematica to combine multiple plots to appear in one exported PDF?

Comment: You should use `Show` to combine the plots and `Export` to export the result. Look to the documentation.

Comment: Why don't you put periods or question marks at the end of sentences? This is how the intonation is conveyed in English.

Comment: There are many similar questions here. You can look here https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/AlignPlotsWithEachOther.html or here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4059/aligning-plot-axes-in-a-graphics-object. Other relevant commands are `GraphicsGrid`, `GraphicsRow`, `GraphicsColumn`.

Comment: I think we need additional information before suggesting any kind of answer.  `Show` might give an answer, but so might creating a `Grid` of individual plots.  Please supply an example of the output you want and any code that you have tried.

Comment: To the community -- I suggest that we give the OP a chance to clarify his question before closing it.  We just don't know what they want yet.

Comment: @Jagra I want to draw the following :  Integrate[(x^2 - y^2)^(d - 3)/2  x^2 Exp[-x], {x, y, Infinity}] for d=1,10 and y={-10,10}

Comment: That integral diverges for `d < 3`. For the remaining values of `d` and `y` the integral is a constant, so there is nothing to plot. The question is still not clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[d_, y_] = Assuming[Element[{d, y}, Reals],
  Integrate[(x^2 - y^2)^(d - 3)/2 x^2 Exp[-x], {x, y, Infinity}]]
```

[image]

```
LogPlot[Evaluate@Table[f[d, y], {d, 10, 3, -1}], {y, 0, 10},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {"y", "f[d, y]"}),
 WorkingPrecision -> 20,
 PlotLegends -> (StringForm["d=``", #] & /@ Range[10, 3, -1])]
```

[image]