# ImageCrop for vector graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a plot with some whitespace I'd like to get rid of. Ideally, I'd like to use a command like `ImageCrop`, but for non-raster graphics (`ImageCrop` rasterizes the graphic). The *Mathematica* documentation tells you how to do this by hand (under the "cropping" section):

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsLayout.html

...but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this via a command. I've tried all sorts of combinations of `FrameMargins`, `ImageMargins`, `ImagePadding`, etc, but to no avail. Even if I could just manually specify the number of pixels to crop by, that would be an improvement over the current situation, but ideally the best solution would be to replicate `ImageCrop` for non-raster graphics.

Comment: Have you looked into the option setting `Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}`?

Comment: Gave that a try, it seems to have bizarre behavior, it crops out the tick labels entirely. It might only work for raw Graphics objects? I'm trying to do this with a Plot object.

Comment: Could you please give code for your plot and indicate which white spaces?

Comment: The big question here: do you want to do this with the 'contents' of the graphics, i.e. all the graphics primitives?  Or do you want this to work for all labels, tick marks, frames, etc.?  If you only need the former, `Show[g, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> 0]` should do it.  If you need the latter, then you just opened Pandora's box ...

Comment: If you need the latter, you can start with dirty hacks like this:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2091/retrieving-the-imagepadding-in-absolute-units  (I uesd this several times, but I don't like it at all.)

Comment: In my answer, I started out trying to emulate what I believe the interactive editing tools are doing. Interestingly, the interactive editor _doesn't_ work with `Overlay` objects, whereas my answer does.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Indeed, I am interested in opening the "Pandora's box", as I am just trying to crop the whitespace around a plot object, but still include all the tick labels, etc. Jens' solution works nicely. Sorry to not have provided a more specific example, my full code is a mess.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Edit**

Come to think of it, one case where I often want to crop the output is `Graphics3D` (one can do it with `ViewAngle` etc., but it's not always convenient - one could also convert to bitmap, but again that's not always desirable). So I decided to allow the `cropGraphics` function below to be used with any object, not just 2D `Graphics`. Here is an example:

```
q = Show[ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}], ImageSize -> 360, 
  Background -> Darker[Green]]
```

[image: Cow]

```
cg = cropGraphics[q, -0.8, -0.4, 200, 200]
```

[image: CowCropped]

In the simple form defined below, `cropGraphics` requires the input object to have an explicit `ImageSize` setting. But it works for a wide range of objects. It can even be used to convert `Overlay` objects to `Graphics` while at the same time cropping them.

Speaking of `Overlay`, here is a continuation of the above example:

```
plot = Overlay[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
    Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 360],
   Magnify[cg, .5]}, Alignment -> {.5, .5}]
```

[image: Overlay]

This is an overlay with the cropped graphics created previously. Now crop *this plot* once again:

```
cropGraphics[plot, 0.5, 0, 300, 120]
```

[image: cropped crop]

**End Edit**

Here is the function that does the above. It is based on `Inset`, and it assumes for simplicity that the graphic you want to crop is going to be positioned in the crop window by placing the original coordinate `{0,0}` (in the coordinate system of the graphics) at a scaled position `{x,y}`. Here, `x` and `y` are between `0` and `1`, with `x = 0.5` corresponding to the center of the crop window. I'll explain this in an example:

```
cropGraphics[g_, x_, y_, w_, h_] := 
 Graphics[Inset[g, {x, y}, {0, 0}], PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
  ImageSize -> {w, h}, AspectRatio -> Full]
```

Here is a sample graphic; I would suggest always giving it a definite setting of `ImageSize` to begin with:

```
pl = Graphics[{{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {.5, .5}]}, {Blue, 
    Disk[{1, 1}, .5]}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {0, 1.5}}, 
  ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image: Example graphic]

For reference, the bottom left corner of the square is at `{0, 0}`, and the graphics is `400` pixels wide and high.

Now we crop it:

```
cropGraphics[pl, 0, 0, 300, 300]
```

[image: cropped 1]

The coordinates `0, 0` mean that the bottom left corner of the square is still where it was before, but the new image width and height are `300`.

If we want to crop part of the square instead, all we have to do is move its lower left corner `{0, 0}` outside the crop window by giving it negative scaled coordinates:

```
cropGraphics[pl, -.25, -.1, 300, 300]
```

[image: crop 2]

Finally, an example of a non-square crop area:

```
cropGraphics[pl, 0.5, -.24, 400, 300]
```

[image: crop 2]

One could improve on this by changing the scaled coordinates `x` and `y` to something absolute in pixels, but I wanted to keep it simple for now, to focus on the main issue: use `Inset` with a variable position in a "wrapper" graphic whose coordinate system ranges from `0` to `1` to make the inset position a scaled coordinate, and whose `ImageSize` has the value desired for the crop.

Comment: Related: [cropping graphics without converting it to raster](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33824/280).

Comment: (+1) It is really usefull; however, when try import the cropped .eps file the size of the exported file become very large which is strange! Also, It seems that the quality has been reduced a little.