# How to control the page size when exporting as a PDF?

Tags: export, pdf-format

When I used Mathematica under Windows, I could control the page size of the pdf files created by `Export[...,"PDF"]` by setting the paper size in the print menu to the desired size before executing the `Export` command.  In particular, I would set the paper size to `Ledger`, and when I opened the resulting files in Acrobat the page size would be listed as 10.83 x 16.83 in.

Now, I'm using Mathematica under Mac OS X, and this trick doesn't work.  Is there some option for `Export[...,"PDF"]` that allows me to control the PDF page size of the output directly?

**Update**

The item I'm exporting is of the form `CreateDocument[{item1,item2}]`, where item2 is a `GraphicsGrid` that contains `ImageSize` information.  Unfortunately, when that information gets wrapped inside `CreateDocument`, `Export[...,"PDF"]` seems to ignore it when setting the PDF page size.

Comment: Without much time to test, I've added another suggestion in response to your update.

Comment: The "trick" you describe works correctly for me.  If I adjust the paper size in the Page Setup dialog on Mac then I export the notebook the size I get is the size I specified in the dialog.  Note that this appears to be a per-notebook setting, so if you didn't explicitly set it for the notebook you exported you may not get the intended size.

Comment: I'm programmatically creating ~100 notebooks and exporting them immediately with a command of the form `Export[filename,CreateDocument[...],"PDF"]`, so I can't really go to the Page Setup dialog for each individual notebook.  Under Windows, setting the paper size once for the parent notebook sets the page size of the PDF exports of the notebooks it spawns.  It doesn't work that way for me under Mac OS X (v. 10.7.4; MMA v. 8.0.1.0).

Comment: I can set the "PageSize" and/or "PaperSize" of a notebook I'm creating with a command like `Export[filename, CreateDocument[{...}, PrintingOptions -> {"PaperSize" -> {11*72, 17*72}, "PageSize" -> {11*72, 17*72}}]]` and the Option Inspector does indicate that these options are set, but they don't affect the page size of the exported PDF.

Answer (score 14):

One possible solution is to do as I suggested in [this MathGroup post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/aEHH4aPfQIc/-hhByzz-WLMJ) (see also the follow-ups). I think one can simplify it by doing the following:

```
g = Graphics[{Inset[
   Plot[10^5 x^2, {x, -2, 2}, Frame -> True, Axes -> None], 
   ImageScaled[{0, 0}], ImageScaled[{0, 0}], ImageScaled[1]]}, 
 ImageSize -> {400, 400}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]

Export["g.pdf", g]
```

The `ImageSize` setting here is in points. You have to multiply the desired inches by `72` to get the length in points.

You may also find [this cropping function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5570/245) useful.

**Update**

In response to the updated question, one could try to set the following option in the `Advanced` tab of the `Preferences`:

[image: screenshot]

Here I have changed `"PageWidth"` under `ExportMultipleCellsOptions` from the original `Infinity` to `PaperWidth`.

Comment: Do you mind commenting where the "PageWidth" values comes from?  I tried setting both PaperSize and PageSize of the current Notebook, but neither seem to effect the output of the exported pdf?

Comment: One danger with this is that the `PaperWidth` value can cause odd bugs with copy-and-paste of chunks of text.