# Cannot change ImageResolution after applying ImagePad

Tags: export, image

I want to export high-resolution images of a plot I'm making.  The trouble is, the plot has a lot of extra white space around it which I get rid of via `ImagePad` (I could also use `ImageCrop` but I run into the same problem described here).

If I put in the following code,

```
tempimage = Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}];

Export["testexport100.png", tempimage, ImageResolution -> 100];
Export["testexport125.png", tempimage, ImageResolution -> 125];
Export["testexport150.png", tempimage, ImageResolution -> 150];
```

I get three files of different size and quality (10KB, 13KB, and 16KB).  But when I first adjust the margins of the image, I no longer have the ability to change the resulting image quality.  For example, if I do

```
tempimage2 = ImagePad[tempimage, {{0, -10}, {0, -10}}];

Export["testexport2_100.png", tempimage2, ImageResolution -> 100];
Export["testexport2_125.png", tempimage2, ImageResolution -> 125];
Export["testexport2_150.png", tempimage2, ImageResolution -> 150];
```

Then all three resulting files are identical and 7KB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering your question in comments, there are ways to crop graphics directly, without converting it to raster. For example, using `Inset` here I cut off 10% of the `ImageSize` from the right and from the top keeping everything in vector form:

```
gr = Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}];
Graphics[Inset[gr, ImageScaled[{0, 0}], ImageScaled[{0, 0}], 
  ImageScaled[10/9]], Options[gr, AspectRatio]]
```

And here I cut off 10 printer's points from the right and from the top:

```
gr = Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}, ImageSize -> {360, 234}];
gr2 = Graphics[
  Inset[gr, ImageScaled[{0, 0}], ImageScaled[{0, 0}], Automatic], 
  ImageSize -> {{0, 360 - 10}, {0, 234 - 10}}, AspectRatio -> Full]
```

If you just need to display a part of the plot you could set explicit `PlotRange` to include only the part of the plot you wish to display (but it is not identical to vector cropping). If you need to remove white borders you could try `Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}`.

Comment: Related: "[Cropping a plot via a command](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5568/280)."

Comment: Related: "[Cropping a Plot without rasterization](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43636/280)."

Comment: Can you kindly add some explanation that how the first method is working. I cannot get it! :)

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason, the image that results from applying `ImagePad` or `ImageCrop` or `ImageTrim` cannot have its resolution changed.  Maybe it's already been rasterized?  But I'm able to work around this by rasterizing the image before applying `ImagePad`.  I use the following function to make sure that the amount trimmed off the side is the same that you would get by applying `ImagePad` to the original.

```
RasterPad[image_, resolution_, padding_] := 
  Module[{odims, ndims, nimage, npadding},
   odims = ImageDimensions[image];
   nimage = Rasterize[image, "Image", ImageResolution -> resolution];
   ndims = ImageDimensions[nimage];
   npadding = ndims/odims padding;
   ImagePad[nimage, npadding]];
```

So I can get the results desired above by

```
Export["testexport2_100.png",RasterPad[tempimage,100,{{0,-10},{0,-10}}]];
Export["testexport2_125.png",RasterPad[tempimage,125,{{0,-10},{0,-10}}]];
Export["testexport2_150.png",RasterPad[tempimage,150,{{0,-10},{0,-10}}]];
```

Comment: Surely `ImagePad` rasterizes the fugure as well as any other `Image*` function: all these functions are designed to work with raster `Image`s and apply `Image` in order to get an object they can work with. Note also that even `Graphics[Raster[...]]` will be rasterized in the same way (generally with loosing quality).

Comment: I think you have confused yourself slightly by referring to `Graphics` expressions as images. Your `tempimage` is not an `Image`, it is a `Graphics` expression. As Alexey notes, when `ImagePad` receives an argument which is not already an `Image` it must rasterize it. This rasterization takes place behind the scenes, using default settings. As you have discovered, if the default settings are no good for you, you need to do the rasterization explicitly with your preferred settings instead of having `ImagePad` do it automatically.

Comment: So yeah, I didn't realize there was a difference between an `Image` and a `Graphics` expression.  So is there a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish here?  Is there a way to crop a graphics expression directly?

Comment: @JasonB  This depends on what you really want. You can always set `PlotRangePadding -> None` and set explicit `PlotRange` to include only the part of the plot you wish to display. If you need to remove white borders you could try `Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}`.