# Crop a `Graphics` object

Tags: graphics, image

How do I crop a `Graphics` object? I know I can use `ImageCrop[graphic, {1800, 400}];` but that results in an `Image`, and I can't export it as an SVG.

Comment: Use `Show[graphic,PlotRange->plotrange]` is this what you want?

Comment: Strongly related: [cropping graphics without converting it to raster](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33824/280).

Comment: @Wjx How do i use `plotrange` if the graphic isnt a plot? What would the coordinates be?

Comment: I ended up using [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5570/39769)