# Cropping Vector Graphics without Rasterization

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

Recently, I encountered the very famous problem of cropping vector graphics without rasterization. I looked over the site and [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/imagecrop-for-vector-graphics) of *Jens* seems to be the best one to me. However, I noticed some issues with it.

1. When I crop the vector graphics using the method of *Jens* and export the file into .eps format, the size of the file becomes much larger in comparison to the case when I export the original vector graphics in .eps format. Is there any explanation for this?
2. It seems that the quality of the cropped vector graphics is reduced. Take a look at the output when I include them into a LaTeX document.
3. I would appreciate that if anyone introduces a good third party software for editing vector images specially cropping them.

[Original Vector Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj0Gn.png)

[Cropped Vector Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zy0k2.png)

Comment: "I would appreciate that if anyone introduces a good third party software for editing vector images specially cropping them." - isn't it off topic?

Comment: @Kuba: You are right but since in most of the cases a good solution with mathematica cannot be found for editing vector graphics that suggestion can be helpful for me or any other mathematica user. :)

Comment: For editing vector images, try Inkscape.

Comment: @Jens: Do you have any idea that why this happens? :)

Comment: I never use EPS anymore. In your case, you have opacity effects that aren't supported by EPS. So PDF is the only thing that will be faithful. But don't try to include 3D graphics in $\LaTeX$ documents as vector graphics. It's really unpleasant to have to wait for the huge files to be rendered while you're trying to scroll through a paper. Always use rasterized images of high resolution for 3D figures meant to to be embedded in papers. That's all I can say.

Comment: @Jens: Thanks for the attention and the advice. :) But do you know that why the size increases after cropping?

Comment: Sorry, the increase in size is quite disproportionate, and I don't see any good explanation for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a nice and easy solution with mathematica itself. However, using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/), I could crop the exported original vector graphics and save them wihtout loss of quality. Hope this may become useful for future readers.