# Generating a broken or snipped axis in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

I have two data sets, `data1` and `data2`.  For example:

```
data1 = {{1, 1.1}, {2, 1.5}, {3, 0.9}, {4, 2.3}, {5, 1.1}};
data2 = {{1, 1001.1}, {2, 1001.5}, {3, 1000.9}, {4, 1002.3}, {5, 1001.1}};
ListPlot[data1, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full, PlotStyle -> Red]
ListPlot[data2, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full, PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

[image: ListPlot 1]

Their $y$-*values* are in vastly different regimes, but their *oscillations* in $y$ are comparable, and I'd like to compare them visually using `ListPlot`.  But if I simply overlay them, it is nearly impossible to see and compare their oscillations, because of the scaling:

```
Show[{
  ListPlot[data1, PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {-100, All}}, Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full,
     PlotStyle -> Red, AxesOrigin -> {1, -50}],
  ListPlot[data2, Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full, PlotStyle -> Blue]
}]
```

[image: ListPlot 2]

Is there a way to "break" or "snip" the $y$ axis so that I can compare `data1` and `data2` on the same plot?  There is no data in the range ~3 to ~1000, so I would like to snip this $y$-range out, if possible, and perhaps include a jagged symbol to show that this has been done.

Comment: Very very strongly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis

Comment: @Ajasja Yes, that is similar, but not identical to this question.  In that question, they ask for two different axes/scales, one on each side.  I am asking for a snipped axis.  While the two approaches accomplish similar things, they are different, since I would like to show how the blue set of data (`data2`) are above the red set of data (`data1`).

Comment: @Andrew Ajasja wasn't the one that voted to close, that was me — I didn't catch the snipped axes requirement at first. I agree that there is a subtle difference and not a duplicate.

Comment: I've got a function that does this, on my laptop at home. Will post this evening (although somebody will surely beat me to it :))

Comment: @JxB Yes, please, if you could post it sometime in the next day or two, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Also, W|A does a snipped axis (see, e.g. [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20100%2Bx%5E2&t=crmtb01)). I wonder if it'll be included as an option in MMA 9?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses a `BezierCurve` to indicate a "snipped" axes. The function `snip[x]` places the mark on the axes at relative position `x` (0 and 1 being the ends). The function `getMaxPadding` gets the maximum padding on all sides for both plots (based on [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2093/5)). The two plots are then aligned one over the other, with the max padding applied for both.

```
snip[pos_] := Arrowheads[{{Automatic, pos, 
     Graphics[{BezierCurve[{{0, -(1/2)}, {1/2, 0}, {-(1/2), 0}, {0, 1/2}}]}]}}];
getMaxPadding[p_List] := Map[Max, (BorderDimensions@
    Image[Show[#, LabelStyle -> White, Background -> White]] & /@ p)~Flatten~{{3}, {2}}, {2}] + 1
p1 = ListPlot[data1, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full, PlotStyle -> Red, 
    AxesStyle -> {None, snip[1]}, PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> 30];
p2 = ListPlot[data2, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
    Axes -> {False, True}, AxesStyle -> {None, snip[0]}, PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> 30];

Column[{p2, p1} /. Graphics[x__] :> 
    Graphics[x, ImagePadding -> getMaxPadding[{p1, p2}], ImageSize -> 400]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one, oh hypnotoad!

Comment: @YvesKlett it sort of forces you to upvote him, doesn't it? All hail the Hypnotoad!

Comment: @rcollyer well ,here goes: ALL GLORY TO THE HYPNOTOAD!

Comment: Only ever beaten by the [brain slug](http://www.futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Brain_Slug). Now that might make for another nice gravatar...

Comment: @Yves my brain slug starved.

Comment: R.M. this looks nice but (for me) it only works at one particular size since if I resize the graphic it overlaps incorrectly.  I'm not sure if that's what you're referring to at the bottom of the answer.  Either way, can you fix it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard now that is statement is food for thought...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's more an indictment of `GraphicsColumn`, which overlaps (eventually) when resizing if a particular negative spacing is set (alternately, widens for positive spacing). For example, try: `GraphicsColumn[{#, #}, Spacings -> -10] &@Plot[, {x, 0, 1}]`. I've used `Column` now, and you shouldn't have this issue if you use the `ImageSize` option to set the size

Comment: Great work… I’ve been playing around with this. Can’t seem to get this to work with Frame enabled. I’d like to be able to have this work with  Frame -> {{ True, True}, {False, True}} for the first plot and Frame -> {{ True, True}, {True, False}} for the second so that you get a nice border around the two charts. Any ideas?

Comment: I should be able to do this myself, but can't exactly figure it out. I want to "snip" the horizontal axis, but I can't get the spacing to be right. What needs to be changed so that it works properly for horizontal snipping? Could anyone post an updated or generalized version?

Comment: Is it just me or does this not work on version 10.2 for anyone else?  I get [this result](http://i.imgur.com/UyTzYLk.png)

Comment: @JasonB It looks like the default padding for plots might have changed. Try using `ImagePadding -> {{40, 20}, {10, 5}}` for the bottom one and `{{40, 20}, {5, 5}}`, for the top one. It's unfortunate that it now requires a little bit of fiddling... I'll try to think of something.

Comment: I was thinking to try and adapt the [`plotgrid`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6882/9490) function so that it could do this, and also handle a discontinuity on the horizontal axis, but haven't done so yet

Comment: What if I wanted to have multiple plots on top of one another? Not just two? The snip function seems to only let you have the squiggle on the top or the bottom. @rm-rf

Answer (score 27):

This solution shifts data around and makes new ticks for the *y* axis.

`compressYAxis[plot_,plotRange1_,plotRange2_]` will modify the *y* axis of the supplied `plot` to exclude the region between the upper limit of `plotRange1` and the lower limit of `plotRange2`. With your data, here is the plot with a *compressed*  *y* axis:

```
data1 = {{1, 1.1}, {2, 1.5}, {3, 0.9}, {4, 2.3}, {5, 1.1}};
data2 = {{1, 1001.1}, {2, 1001.5}, {3, 1000.9}, {4, 1002.3}, {5, 1001.1}};

p = ListLinePlot[{data1, data2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "Example of a compressed y axis", 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}];

compressYAxis[p, {0, 3}, {999, 1003}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You will have to fiddle with this if you want tick subdivisions or a different background colour; the compression marks could be improved too.

The definition is

```
Clear[compressYAxis];
compressYAxis[plot_, range1_, range2_] := 
  Module[{ytick1, ytick2, epilog1, target},
   ytick1 = FindDivisions[range1, 5] /. y_?NumericQ :> {y, y} /. {y_?NumericQ, _} /; y >= range1[[2]] :> Sequence[];
   ytick2 = FindDivisions[range2, 5] /. y_?NumericQ :> {y - range2[[1]] + range1[[2]], y} /. {y_?NumericQ, _} /; y <= range1[[2]] :> Sequence[];
   epilog = Options[plot, Epilog][[1, 2]];
   target = Subtract @@ Reverse@range1/(Subtract @@ Reverse@range1 + Subtract @@ Reverse@range2);
   Show[plot /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ /; y > range2[[1]]} :> {x, y - range2[[1]] + range1[[2]]}, 
     PlotRange -> {range1[[1]], range1[[2]] + Subtract @@ Reverse@range2}, 
     Ticks -> {Automatic, Join[ytick1, ytick2]}, 
     Epilog -> Join[epilog, {White, Rectangle[Scaled[{-0.1, 0.98 target}], Scaled[{1.1, 1.02 target}]], Black, Text[Rotate["\\", \[Pi]/2], Scaled[{0, 0.98 target}], {-1.5, 0}], Text[Rotate["\\", \[Pi]/2], Scaled[{0, 1.02 target}], {-1.5, 0}]}]]
 ]
```

Comment: @Andrew As promised. It's hawkish, and needs Mma v7 or greater. This approach could work quite nicely if (once?) `AbsoluteOptions` is fixed so that it returns suitable values for `Ticks`. As it stands, R.M's solution looks more robust.

Comment: In the `Module` parameter list there is a `epilog1` variable, however in the following code you used `epilog` (without the `1`). This should probably be corrected.

Answer (score 9):

#### ScalingFunctions

We can use custom piecewise linear `ScalingFunctions` which efectively makes the interval $[3,1000]$  very short and add a glyph to indicate the break using `Epilog` or `AxesStyle` to

```
ClearAll[sf, isf, inset]
sf[t1_, t2_, gap_: 1/10][x_] := Piecewise[{{x, x <= t1}, {t1 + gap/(t2 - t1) (x - t1), 
    t1 <= x <= t2}, {t1 + gap + (x - t2), x >= t2}}]
isf[t1_, t2_, gap_: 1/10][x_] := InverseFunction[sf[t1, t2, gap]][x]

head = Graphics[{Antialiasing -> True,EdgeForm[None], FaceForm[White], 
    Polygon[{{-1, -1/6}, {1, 5/6}, {1, 1/6}, {-1, -5/6}}], Black, 
    CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[1], 
    Line[{{{-1, -5/6}, {1, 1/6}}, {{-1, -1/6}, {1, 5/6}}}]}];
inset[pos_: Scaled[{0.005, .55}], size_: {1/3, 1/3}] := Inset[head, pos, Automatic, size]


{t1, t2} = {Ceiling[#[[1, 2]]], Floor[#[[2, 1]]]} &@
   (CoordinateBounds[#][[2]]&/@ {data1, data2});
{yrange1, yrange2} = {Floor[#, .5], Ceiling[#2, .5]} & @@@ 
  (CoordinateBounds[#][[2]] & /@ {data1, data2});
ticks = Join @@ (Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}][##] & @@@ {yrange1, yrange2});
```

Using `inset[]` as `Epilog`:

```
ListLinePlot[{data1, data2}, PlotStyle -> Thick,
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", {sf[t1, t2], isf[t1, t2]}}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, ticks}, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 Epilog -> inset[], ImageSize -> Medium, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Using `head` as `Arrowheads` in `AxesStyle`:

```
ListLinePlot[{data1, data2}, PlotStyle -> Thick,
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", {sf[t1, t2], isf[t1, t2]}}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, ticks}, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 ImageSize -> Medium, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 AxesStyle -> {Automatic, Arrowheads[{{.05, .55, MapAt[ 
  GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[Pi/2]] &, head, {1}]}}]}]
```

[image]

A modification of rm-rf's `snip` used with `Epilog` and `AxesStyle`:

```
ClearAll[snip2, inset2]
head2 = Graphics[{Antialiasing -> True, FaceForm[White], 
   Rectangle[{-1/3, -1/2}, {2/3, 1/2}],
   {#, Translate[#, {1/2, 0}]} & @
    BezierCurve[{{0, -(1/2)}, {1/2, 0}, {-(1/2), 0}, {0, 1/2}}]}];
snip2[pos_] := Arrowheads[{{Automatic, pos, head2}}];
inset2[pos_: Scaled[{0.005, .55}], size_: {1/3, 1/3}] := Inset[MapAt[ 
  GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[Pi/2]] &, head2, {1}], 
  pos, Automatic, size]

ListLinePlot[{data1, data2}, PlotStyle -> Thick,
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", {sf[t1, t2], isf[t1, t2]}}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, ticks}, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 Epilog -> inset2[], ImageSize -> Medium, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[{data1, data2}, PlotStyle -> Thick,
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", {sf[t1, t2], isf[t1, t2]}}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, ticks}, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 AxesStyle -> {Automatic, snip2[.55]}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

#### TranslationTransform

We can translate `data2` and modify vertical tick labels taking the translation into account:

```
data2translated = TranslationTransform[{0, -997}] @ data2;
ticks2 = Join[Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}][##] & @@ yrange1, 
   Charting`FindTicks[#, # + 997][## & @@ #] &@(yrange2 - 997)];
ListLinePlot[{data1, data2translated }, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 ImageSize -> Medium, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 AxesStyle -> {Automatic, snip2[.55]}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, ticks2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Now there is a package in Mathematica which handles all of this **without effort**.

You just need to use the package and does the job in **just one line**!

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{{plot2}, {plot1}}, "MergeAxes" -> "ZigZag", Spacings -> {0, 5}]
```

[image]

Just store your plots in one variable, and add the `Frame-> True` option to them:

```
plot1 = ListPlot[data1, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full, PlotStyle -> Red];
plot2 = ListPlot[data2, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full, PlotStyle -> Blue];
```

Here you can find more documentation on how to tweak it according to your needs: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid/

Based on this Q&A:
[Broken y axis at multiple locations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253120/broken-y-axis-at-multiple-locations?rq=1)