# Combining 3 graphics of different coordinate systems

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have 3 graphics in different coordinate systems and I want to join them in as in the following figure.
[image: Sample Figure]
This is just a sample figure, not the real one.

My functions are as follows.

```
y[t_]=Sin[Pi t]/(Pi t);
ar={1.415,2.495,3.526,4.462,5.421,6.477} (* Aproximate roots of y'[t] *);
rr=Join[{0},Table[t/.FindRoot[D[y[t],t]==0,{t,ar[[k]]}],{k,1,Length[ar]}],{7}] (* Real roots y'[t] *);
θ[t_]=Piecewise[Table[{ArcTan[y[t]/(t^2 y'[t])]+k Pi,rr[[k]]<=t<rr[[k+1]]},{k,1,Length[rr]-1}]] (* Phase function *);
ρ[t_]=Sqrt[(y[t])^2 + (t^2 y'[t])^2] (* Amplitude function*) ;
```

The first graphic is generated by

```
p1=Plot[θ[t],{t,0,5},Ticks->{None,Table[{k π,k "π"}, {k,0,4}]},AxesLabel->{"t","θ"},AxesStyle->Directive[14],AxesOrigin->{0,0},PlotRange->Full]
```

[image: p1]

the second graphic is generated by

```
p2=Plot[y[t],{t,0,5},Ticks->{Table[{k,""},{k,1,5}],{1}},AxesLabel->{"t","y"},AxesStyle->Directive[14],AxesOrigin->{0,0},PlotRange->Full]
```

[image: p2]

the third and last one is generated by

```
p3=PolarPlot[ρ[t],{t,0,5},Ticks->None,AxesLabel->{"θ","ρ"},AxesStyle->Directive[14],AxesOrigin->{0,0}]
```

[image: p3]

---

**Properties of the graphic is as follows.**
1. Origins of *p1* and *p2* must be on the same vertical line, and the origins of *p2* and *p3* must be on the same horizontal line (as shown on the sample figure).
2. The horizontal lines passing at the points $\pi$, $2\pi$, $3\pi$, $4\pi$ located on the $\theta$-axis of *p1* and the vertical lines passing at the zeros of the curve (which are explicitly $1,2,\cdots$ since $y(t)=\sin(\pi t)/(\pi t)=0$ at such points) in *p2* must intersect on the curve in *p1* (see the sample figure).
3.The list of extreme points of the curve in *p2* are listed in *rr*, i.e., if $t$ is in *rr* then $y'(t)=0$ and thus $\rho(t)=|y(t)|$. For such points the distance from $t$-axis to the function $y$ in *p2* is equal to the length from the *Origin* to the corresponding peak point of the curve in *p3*. This requires scaling of *p3* so that the lengths are equal.

It would be very good to have them just in the right position, I guess I can draw the lines myself...

Many thanks.
**bkarpuz**

---

**Edit**. After reading **Yves Klett**'s comment decided to show what I have tried. I did everything manually as I don't really understand the command *Inset* very well.

```
p1 = Plot[θ[t], {t, 0.7, 4.2}, Ticks -> {None, None}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"t\",\nFontSlant->Italic]\)", "\!\(\*TagBox[
StyleBox[\"θ\",\nFontSize->14,\nFontSlant->Italic],
(StyleForm[#, 14, Italic]& )]\)"}, AxesStyle -> Directive[14], 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4.5}, {0, 14}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];
p2 = Show[
   Plot[y[t], {t, 0.7, 4.2}, Ticks -> {Table[{k, ""}, {k, 1, 5}], {}},
     AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"t\",\nFontSlant->Italic]\)", "\!\(\*TagBox[
StyleBox[\"y\",\nFontSize->14,\nFontSlant->Italic],
(StyleForm[#, 14, Italic]& )]\)"}, AxesStyle -> Directive[14], 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4.5}, {-2, 2}}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1], 
   ListPlot[Table[{rr[[k]], y[rr[[k]]]}, {k, 2, 4}], Filling -> Axis, 
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[Small]]];
pl = Table[{rr[[k]], ρ[rr[[k]]]}, {k, 2, 4}];
p3 = Show[
   PolarPlot[ρ[t], {t, 0.7, 4.2}, Ticks -> None, 
    AxesLabel -> {"θ", "ρ"}, AxesStyle -> Directive[14], 
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[Tiny], AspectRatio -> 1], 
   Table[ListPolarPlot[{{0, 0}, pl[[k]]}, Joined -> True, 
     PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Tiny], 
       Directive[Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], Opacity[0.2]]}], {k, 1, 
     Length[pl]}], ListPolarPlot[pl]];
```

The figures are drawn above

```
Show[Graphics[{Inset[p2, {0, -0.35}, Right, 0.8], 
   Inset[p1, {0, 0.55}, Right, 0.8], 
   Inset[p3, {0.24, -0.415}, Left, 0.6]}, PlotRange -> 1], 
 Graphics[{Dotted, Line[{{-0.6215, -0.41}, {-0.6215, 0.3152}}], 
   Line[{{-0.4634, -0.41}, {-0.4634, 0.4762}}], 
   Line[{{-0.30515, -0.41}, {-0.30515, 0.6326}}]}], 
 Graphics[{Dotted, Line[{{-0.7778, 0.3152}, {-0.6215, 0.3152}}], 
   Line[{{-0.7778, 0.4762}, {-0.4634, 0.4762}}], 
   Line[{{-0.7778, 0.6326}, {-0.30515, 0.6326}}]}], 
 Graphics[{Point[{-0.6215, 0.3152}], Point[{-0.4634, 0.4762}], 
   Point[{-0.30515, 0.6326}]}], 
 Graphics[{Text[StyleForm["π", 14], {-0.8, 0.3152}, {1, 0}], 
   Text[StyleForm["2π", 14], {-0.8, 0.4762}, {1, 0}], 
   Text[StyleForm["3π", 14], {-0.8, 0.6326}, {1, 0}],}]]
```

I obtained all the points in the last part from the plain figure by *Get Coordinates* and drew the lines. On the other hand, to fit the *Origins* of *p1* and *p2*, I drew them with *Ticks->None* and then put the *Ticks* manually on the figure obtained by *Inset*. However, the figure still seems to be inconvenient with *p3* as it does not satisfy *Property 3 (scaling)* mentioned above.

Comment: To motivate any takers, showing what you already tried might be a good move. You might also want to try and break down your problem into smaller, concise tasks if possible(for me reading all your explications proved too tiresome).

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest **Yves Klett** but I can not split my problem into smaller pieces since my only problem is to join these 3 different coordinates.

Comment: rr = Join[{0}, 
   Table[t /. FindRoot[D[y[t], t] == 0, {t, ar[[k]]}], {k, 1, 
     Length[ar]}], {7}] (*Real roots y'[t]*); this line gives many errors. Could you check ?

Comment: Oh, **s.s.o** please replace `Sin(Pi t)` with `Sin[Pi t]`. Updated the code in the original post.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your intent, esp. with the sample figure (+1). `Inset` can be very tricky indeed.

Comment: This code looks almost suitable after removing the *Labels* and the *Ticks* of the *Axes*. `Show[Graphics[{Inset[p1,{-2.5,3.6164},Right,2],Inset[p2,{-2.5,1.6164},Right,2],Inset[p3,{-1.5,-0.7},Left,6]},PlotRange->5]]` Bu I don't know how to find the exact ratio to fix *p3* satisfying *Property 3 (mentioned above)*.

Comment: Probably related:
[Vertically aligning two separate plots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13373/131) and
[Aligning plot axes in a graphics object](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4059/131)

Comment: Where's the sample figure? Should it be a link or pasted in?

Comment: @ **JohnD** : Figure 3.7-1 is the sample figure. I want to form the same figure with my own plots *p1*, *p2* and *p3*.  By the way, it seems that `GraphicsGrid` also useful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here I join 3 figures with lines in a tricky way, where I plot vertical and horizontal lines separately and set them by `Inset` at appropriate positions in such a way that the lines vanish when they touch the end figures.
[image: Figure~1]

```
y[t_] := Sin[π t]/(π t);
p[t_] = t^2;
a = 0.7;
b = 5.2;
yRoots = t /. {ToRules@Reduce[{y[t] == 0, 0 <= t <= 5}, t]};
yDRoots = t /. {ToRules@N@Reduce[{y'[t] == 0, 0 <= t <= 5}, y]};
ranges = Append[Prepend[yDRoots, 0], 6];
θ[t_] := Piecewise[Table[{ArcTan[y[t]/(p[t] y'[t])] + k Pi, ranges[[k]] < t <= ranges[[k + 1]]}, {k, Length@ranges - 1}]];
ρ[t_] := Sqrt[(y[t])^2 + (p[t] y'[t])^2];
ε = 1/(10^7);
p1 = Plot[θ[t], {t, a, b}, Ticks -> {None, Join[Table[{k Pi, k π}, {k, 0, 5}], Table[{(2 k - 1) Pi/2, (2 k - 1) Pi/2}, {k, 1, 5}]]}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "θ"}, AxesStyle -> Directive[14], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5.3}, {0, 16}}, AspectRatio -> 1, ImagePadding -> 20, 
   Epilog -> {{Red, AbsolutePointSize@5, Point[{#, θ[#]}&/@yRoots]},
     {Blue, AbsolutePointSize@5, Point[{#, θ[#]}&/@(yDRoots + ε)]},
     {Black, AbsolutePointSize@5,Point[{{a, θ[a]}, {b, θ[b]}}]},
     {Gray, Dashed, Line[{{0, θ[#]}, {#, θ[#]}, {#, -100}}&/@yRoots], Line[{{0, θ[#]}, {#, θ[#]}}&/@yRoots]},
     {Gray, Dashed, Line[{{0, θ[#]}, {#, θ[#]}, {#, -100}}&/@(yDRoots+ε)]}}];
p2 = Plot[y[t], {t, a, b}, Ticks -> {Table[{k, ""}, {k, 1, 5}], {{1, ""}}}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "y"}, AxesStyle -> Directive[14], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5.3}, {-0.3, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, ImagePadding -> 20, 
   Epilog -> {{Red, AbsolutePointSize@5, Point[{#, y[#]} & /@ yRoots]},
     {Blue, AbsolutePointSize@5, Point[{#, y[#]} & /@ yDRoots]},
     {Black, AbsolutePointSize@5, Point[{{a, y[a]}, {b, y[b]}}]},
     {Gray, Dashed, Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 100}} & /@ yRoots]},
     {Gray, Dashed, Line[{{100, y[#]}, {#, y[#]}, {#, 100}} & /@ yDRoots]}}];
p3 = ParametricPlot[{ρ[t] Cos[θ[t]], ρ[t] Sin[θ[t]]}, {t, a, b}, Ticks -> None, AxesLabel -> None, AxesStyle -> Directive[14], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, ImagePadding -> 20, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-0.3, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   Epilog -> {{Red, AbsolutePointSize@5, Point[(ρ[#]*{Cos[θ[#]], Sin[θ[#]]})&/@yRoots]},
     {Blue, AbsolutePointSize@5,Point[(ρ[#]*{Cos[θ[#]], Sin[θ[#]]}) & /@ (yDRoots + ε)]},
     {Black, AbsolutePointSize@5, Point[{ρ[a]*{Cos[θ[a]], Sin[θ[a]]}, ρ[b]*{Cos[θ[b]], Sin[θ[b]]}}]},
     {Gray, Dashed,Line[{({-100, ρ[#]*Sin[θ[#]]}), (ρ[#]*{Cos[θ[#]],Sin[θ[#]]})}&/@(yDRoots + ε)]},
     {Gray, Dotted, Line[{{0, 0}, (ρ[a]*{Cos[θ[a]],Sin[θ[a]]})}]}}];
(* Vertical lines *)
pvl = Plot[2, {t, a, b}, Axes -> None, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5.3}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1,  ImagePadding -> 20, 
   Epilog -> {{Gray, Dashed, Line[{{#, 0.66}, {#, 1}} & /@ yRoots]},
     {Gray, Dashed, Line[{{#, 0.66}, {#, 1}} & /@yDRoots]}}];
(* Horizontal lines *)
phl = Plot[2, {t, a, b}, Axes -> None, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5.3}, {-0.3, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, ImagePadding -> 20, 
  Epilog -> {{Gray, Dashed, Line[{{0.03, y[#]}, {0.9, y[#]}} & /@yDRoots]}}];
(* Put the images together *)
Graphics[{Inset[p1, ImageScaled@{.05, 0.52}, {0, 0}, 1], 
  Inset[pvl, ImageScaled@{.05, .31}, {0, 0}, 1], 
  Inset[p2, ImageScaled@{.05, .12}, {0, 0}, 1], 
  Inset[phl, ImageScaled@{.48, .12}, {0, 0}, 1], 
  Inset[p3, ImageScaled@{.77, .12}, {0, 0}, 1]}, ImageSize -> 800, PlotRange -> All]
```

Using `GraphicsGrid` this can be done easier as follows by replacing the code under the last *comments* in the above with the following.

```
GraphicsGrid[{{p1,Null,Null},{pvl,Null,Null},{p2,phl,p3}},ImageSize->600,Spacings->-66]
```

Thank you for the interest, and any other solutions are welcome.
**bkarpuz**

Answer (score 7):

This is just a crude approximation of what you expect using `Inset`, but it becomes rather complicated to track subplot coordinates when `Inset`ted in a larger `Graphics` environment.

My method requires the individual plots to be tampered with:

- give identical `ImagePadding` values for each subplot;
- draw grid lines as `Epilog` primitives (otherwise `GridLines` would go from edge to edge, crowding the plots);
- restrict the `PlotRange` of `p3`, as it is way too big for the other plots if scaled correctly.

Still I have no idea how to:

- calculate the scaling factor of `p3` programmatically (though the fourth argument of `Inset` could be used for scaling if the right ratio is known);
- draw lines over the whole image (i.e. lines connecting points of `p1` and `p2`) using the subplots' own coordinates.

The code:

```
y[t_] := Sin[Pi t]/(Pi t);
yRoots = t /. {ToRules@Reduce[{y[t] == 0, 0 <= t <= 6}, t]};
yDRoots = t /. {ToRules@N@Reduce[{y'[t] == 0, 0 <= t <= 6}, y]}
ranges = Prepend[yDRoots, 0];
θ[t_] := Piecewise[
    Table[{ArcTan[y[t]/(t^2 y'[t])] + k Pi, ranges[[k]] < t <= ranges[[k + 1]]},
    {k, Length@ranges - 1}]];
ρ[t_] := Sqrt[(y[t])^2 + (t^2 y'[t])^2];

d = 10^-7; (* A small delta is defined so that lines at points of yDRoots appear in the correct interval *)

p1 = Plot[θ[t], {t, 0, 5}, 
   Ticks -> {None, Table[{k Pi, k "π"}, {k, 0, 4}]}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"t", "θ"}, AxesStyle -> Directive[14], 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> Full, ImagePadding -> 20,
   Epilog -> {
     {Red, AbsolutePointSize@5, Point[{#, θ[#]} & /@ yRoots]},
     {Gray, Dashed, Line[{{#, θ[#]}, {#, -100}} & /@ yRoots], 
                    Line[{{0, θ[#]}, {#, θ[#]}} & /@ yRoots]},
     {Green, AbsolutePointSize@5, Point[{#, θ[#]} & /@ (yDRoots + d)]},
     {Gray, Dashed, Line[{{#, θ[#]}, {#, -100}} & /@ (yDRoots + d)]}
   }];
p2 = Plot[y[t], {t, 0, 5}, Ticks -> {Table[{k, ""}, {k, 1, 5}], {1}}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"t", "y"}, AxesStyle -> Directive[14], 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> Full, ImagePadding -> 20,
   Epilog -> {
     {Red, AbsolutePointSize@5, Point[{#, y[#]} & /@ yRoots]},
     {Green, AbsolutePointSize@5, Point[{#, y[#]} & /@ yDRoots]},
     {Gray, Dashed, Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 100}} & /@ yRoots]},
     {Gray, Dashed, Line[{{#, y[#]}, {#, 0}} & /@ yDRoots]}
   }];
p3 = PolarPlot[ρ[t], {t, 0, 5}, Ticks -> None, 
   AxesLabel -> {"θ", "ρ"}, AxesStyle -> Directive[14], 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, ImagePadding -> 20, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}*.35,
   Epilog -> {
     {Green, AbsolutePointSize@5, Point[(ρ[#]*{Cos[#], Sin[#]}) & /@ yDRoots]},
     {Gray, Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, ρ[#]*{Cos[#], Sin[#]}} & /@ yDRoots]}
     }];

(* define origo points for p1 and p3 (p2 is derived from these) *)
o1 = {.1, .5};
o3 = {.75, .25};
o2 = {First@o1, Last@o3};
Graphics[{
  Inset[p1, ImageScaled@o1, {0, 0}, 1],
  Inset[p2, ImageScaled@o2, {0, 0}, 1],
  Inset[p3, ImageScaled@o3, {0, 0}, 1]
  }, ImageSize -> 500, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the effort **István Zachar**. I tried to add the same green points and corresponding grey lines for *p1* but it seems that there is a problem in the definition of the function $\theta$. How it can be fixed?

Comment: @bkarpuz Yes, you have to add a small number to each `y'` root so that the appropriate line appears in the correct interval. Please see edit.