# Size problems combining objects in a Graphics using Inset

Tags: graphics

**The Problem**

I need to put together different graphics objects in a precise way inside a `Graphics`. Some objects are drawn directly by graphics primitives, some others are the result of calls to built-in and custom functions.

I've use `Inset` to place these objects, but the result is unsatisfactory, as the objects appears in wrong sizes.

For analizing better the problem, I've wrote a simple general example, where there are five objects that are placed in the `Graphics` sharing the very same shape, size and parameters. They differ only by the way how they are generated (please see the full code below).

There are five bars: redBar, greenBar, blueBar, yellowBar, orangeBar, they should be draw as the following picture (manually adjusted):

[image]

but instead, putting the elements together with this code (fragment):

```
 Graphics[{
   redBar[barW, barH]
   , Inset[greenBar[barW, barH, options], {0, yPos}, {0, 0}] /. {yPos -> 100}
   , Inset[blueBar[barW, barH, options], {0, yPos}, {Left, Bottom}] /. {yPos -> 200}
   , Inset[yellowBar[barW, barH, options], {0, yPos}, {Left, Bottom}] /. {yPos -> 300}
   , Inset[orangeBar[barW, barH, options], {0, yPos}, {Left, Bottom}] /. {yPos -> 400}
   }
  , Axes -> True
  , PlotRange -> {{0, slideW}, {0, slideH}}
  , ImageSize -> {slideW, slideH}
  , AspectRatio -> Automatic
  ]
```

will give this kind of output:

[image]

**Sample Code**

Here it is the full code for this example:

```
(* --- Functions definitions --- *)

(* a simple bar as a base for the red, green and blue bars*)
bar[w_, h_] := {Opacity[0.6], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {w, h}]};

(* Red Bar: this return a simple graphics Primitive *)
redBar[w_, h_] := {Red, bar[w, h]};

(* Green Bar: this returns a Graphics object, based on the shared bar primitive *)   
greenBar[w_, h_, options_] := Graphics[{Green, bar[w, h]}, Sequence@options];

(* Blue Bar: this returns a composed Graphics object *)
blueBarToInset[w_, h_, options_] := Graphics[{Blue, bar[w, h]}, Sequence@options];
blueBar[w_, h_, options_] := Graphics[Inset[blueBarToInset[w, h, options], {0, 0}, {Left, Bottom}], Sequence@options];

(* Yellow Bar, this is just the usual Plot function output *)
yellowBar[w_, h_, options_] := Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, Axes -> True, Background -> Directive[Opacity[0.6], Yellow], Evaluate@Sequence@options];

(* Orange Bar, this is just the same as above, but without Axes  *)
orangeBar[w_, h_, options_] := Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, Axes -> False,  Background -> Directive[Opacity[0.6], Orange], Evaluate@Sequence@options];

(* --- Main code --- *)
slideW = 500;
slideH = 500;

barW = 300;
barH = 100;

Manipulate[

 (*shared Graphics options*)
 options = {ImageSize -> {barW, barH}, AspectRatio -> aspectRatio, PlotRangePadding -> plotRangePadding};

 (*put elements together*)
 Graphics[{
   redBar[barW, barH]
   , Inset[greenBar[barW, barH, options], {0, yPos}, {0, 0}] /. {yPos -> 100}
   , Inset[blueBar[barW, barH, options], {0, yPos}, {Left, Bottom}] /. {yPos -> 200}
   , Inset[yellowBar[barW, barH, options], {0, yPos}, {Left, Bottom}] /. {yPos -> 300}
   , Inset[orangeBar[barW, barH, options], {0, yPos}, {Left, Bottom}] /. {yPos -> 400}
   }
  , Axes -> True
  , PlotRange -> {{0, slideW}, {0, slideH}}
  , ImageSize -> {slideW, slideH}
  , AspectRatio -> Automatic
  ]

 , {plotRangePadding, {Automatic, None}}
 , {aspectRatio, {Automatic, Full, (barH/barW) -> "barH/barW"}}
 ]
```

**Another Test**

To be sure that the graphics elements are actually similar in size, I've put them in a `Column`, obtaining almost the proper size, so this may prove than the problem is within `Inset`, not with the graphics elements themselfs:

```
Framed@Column[{
orangeBar[barW, barH, options],
yellowBar[barW, barH, options],
blueBar[barW, barH, options],
greenBar[barW, barH, options],
Graphics[redBar[barW, barH], options]
}
, Alignment -> Left
, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]

**IMHO**

Maybe is my fault in understanding which option is to be given, but I think that this kind of (apparently simple) operations hasn't to be so difficult and frustrating..

Comment: I agree that it's frustrating. `Inset` is a little mysterious, and it took me a little while to figure out how it works. In addition, `GraphicsColumn` is non-ideal for various reasons. In any case, see these posts: [(1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79773/29734), [(2)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4060/29734), [(3)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88533/29734) for some ideas. I recommend using `GraphicsColumn` (which uses `Inset` internally) with equal padding, and scaling all the figures to be the same size.

Comment: Also related: [(16475)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16475/121),
[(73522)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73522/121),
[(83636)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83636/121)

Comment: Thank you for the links, I've already read some of them before posting, but I've post this question hoping to find a general explanation of why these things happen rather than find a specific solution. As you point out `Inset` is a little bit obscure, it is really difficult to understand when the problem is coming from a hypothetical bug or from the user's incompetence