# How to align the output of MatrixPlot with the output of Plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am trying to figure out how to align different types of plots into one image. For example in the following code, it plots two lines on top of a `MatrixPlot`. I want the lines to pass through the corners of the red squares in the overlaid image.

```
 Overlay[{
     MatrixPlot[Table[Mod[i^2 + j^2, 3], {i, 20}, {j, 20}], 
         ColorRules -> {0 -> Red, 1 -> White, 2 -> White}, AspectRatio -> Full],
     Plot[{y = x, y = -x/1 + 1}, {x, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> Full]}, 
     ImageSize -> Full]
```

How can I create the image so the lines and squares fit together better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you overlay two plots like that, you need to make sure that both plots have the same [`AspectRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AspectRatio.html), [`PlotRangePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotRangePadding.html) and [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImagePadding.html). It also improves the clarity if you turn off the ticks for one of the plots:

```
With[{opts = {AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 18}}, 
    Overlay[{
        MatrixPlot[Table[Mod[i^2 + j^2, 3], {i, 20}, {j, 20}], 
            ColorRules -> {0 -> Red, 1 -> White, 2 -> White}, opts, FrameTicks -> False], 
        Plot[{y = x, y = -x/1 + 1}, {x, 0, 1}, opts]}, ImageSize -> Full
    ]
]
```

[image]

I've eyeballed the `ImagePadding` here, and you will have to adjust it if you change the font size or include frame labels. You can also use different paddings for each side.

For a more robust and automated solution, you can use [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2093/5) by Heike to retrieve the image padding of both plots and set them both to the maximum padding as I did in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13374/5).

Comment: Sweet! Thank you @rm -rf !

Answer (score 1):

You also could just place them in the same coordinate system. That opens few other ways.

```
MatrixPlot[Table[Mod[i^2 + j^2, 3], {i, 20}, {j, 20}], 
 ColorRules -> {0 -> Red, 1 -> White, 2 -> White},
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> 0, Epilog -> {
   {Orange, Line[{{0, 0}, {20, 20}}]},
   {Green, Line[{{0, 20}, {20, 0}}]}}]
```

or...

```
Show[
 MatrixPlot[Table[Mod[i^2 + j^2, 3], {i, 20}, {j, 20}], 
  ColorRules -> {0 -> Red, 1 -> White, 2 -> White}],
 Plot[{y = x, y = 20 - x}, {x, 0, 20}],
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

...