# Plot not aligned after adding plot legends

Tags: plotting, legending

The new `GraphicsColumn` function claims to have the ability to align the axes [Align Frame Edges](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/core-visualization/align-frame-edges.html?product=mathematica). It works fine for very very simple plots, but if one adds a simple thing such as `plot legends` to it, it will not work anymore. For example, a simple plot as below works:

```
 plot1 = ListLinePlot[{Range[10], Range[11, 20]},
   Axes -> False,
   Frame -> True];
plot2 = ListLinePlot[{Range[41, 50], Range[61, 115]},
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Black},
   Axes -> False,
   Frame -> True];
plots = {plot1, plot2};
GraphicsColumn[plots]
```

But once we added legends, things start to break down:

```
plot1 = ListLinePlot[{Range[10], Range[11, 20]},
   PlotLegends -> {"line 1", "line 2"},
   Axes -> False,
   Frame -> True];
plot2 = ListLinePlot[{Range[41, 50], Range[61, 115]},
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Black},
   PlotLegends -> {"line 3", "line 4"},
   Axes -> False,
   Frame -> True];
plots = {plot1, plot2};
GraphicsColumn[plots]
```

**Mathematica** really need to do something to catch up with **Python** in terms of visualization capabilities.

Comment: Do you have a question or is this just a rant?

Comment: Plots can easily be aligned by giving both plots the same image padding such as `ImagePadding -> {{30, 5}, {30, 5}}`. I realize how frustrating it can be when things don't work the way you expect when you're new to a language, but this community is pretty good at helping if you give them a chance, either by asking a well-posed question or looking through answers to old questions. [Vertically aligning two separate plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13373/vertically-aligning-two-separate-plots)

Comment: Try `Spacings -> -100`.

Comment: ImagePadding works well. Thanks @MassDefect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use `Multicolumn` for alignment. Using the same `ImagePadding` for all figures is crucial.

```
imgPad = {{20, 2}, {20, 6}};
plot1 = ListLinePlot[{Range[10], Range[11, 20]}, 
   ImagePadding -> imgPad, PlotLegends -> {"line 1", "line 2"}, 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True];
plot2 = ListLinePlot[{Range[41, 50], Range[61, 115]}, 
   ImagePadding -> imgPad, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"line 3", "line 4"}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True];
Multicolumn[{plot1, plot2}, 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following within the `GraphicsColumn`:  `Spacings->-80`

[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to align the edges of the frames. It's close on the right side, but a bit off on the left side.

Comment: I think the choice by @MassDefect using the "image padding" is the best. I will try to structure the post more like a question not a rant in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`GraphicsColumn` together with `GraphicsRow` and `GraphicsGrid` are a bit problematic tools. There is problem with determination of `AspectRatio` for resulting graphics. Moreover, the plot with legend is a combined object and therefore the aspect ration is another than for pure plots.

You should define the `AspectRatio` directly in both plots to obtain normal view.

```
plot1 = ListLinePlot[{Range[10], Range[11, 20]}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"line 1", "line 2"}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   AspectRatio -> 0.6, ImageSize -> 400];
plot2 = ListLinePlot[{Range[41, 50], Range[61, 115]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}, PlotLegends -> {"line 3", "line 4"}, 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.6, ImageSize -> 400];
plots = {plot1, plot2};
GraphicsColumn[plots, ImageSize -> 500, AspectRatio -> 0.6]
```

[image]