# How to add/insert a well aligned graphics on top of another one?

Tags: plotting, graphics, output-formatting, formatting, display

I need to add a small graphics on top of a larger one, and the small graphics should stick very close to the large one, with their axis aligned.  Here's a minimal code to work with, using some elements from this question/answer :

[How to make a plot on top of other plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22521/how-to-make-a-plot-on-top-of-other-plot)

```
Intensity[p_, q_, phi_] := Plot[
    (If[p > 0, Sin[2Pi p^2 x]/(2Pi p^2 x), 1]Cos[2Pi p^2 q x + phi/2])^2,
    {x, -30, 30},
    PlotPoints -> 400,
    MaxRecursion -> 4,
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotRange -> {{-30, 30}, {0, 1}},
    Axes -> False,
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    Frame -> True,
    ImageSize -> {600, 600}
]

LumIntensity[p_, q_, phi_] := DensityPlot[
    (If[p > 0, Sin[2Pi p^2 x]/(2Pi p^2 x), 1]Cos[2Pi p^2 q x + phi/2])^2,
    {x, -30, 30}, {y, 0, 1}, 
    AspectRatio -> 0.1,
    PlotPoints -> {1000, 2},
    Frame -> None, 
    ImageSize -> 600
]

GraphicsColumn[
    {LumIntensity[0.25, 5, 0], Intensity[0.25, 5, 0]},
    Spacings -> 0
]
```

Here's what I want to achieve (which the question/answer above don't solve) :

[image: interference]

Also, how can I add a black frame around the small graphics ?  Using `Frame -> True` or `Framed[...]` gives an ugly output.

The combination would be used for a Manipulate box, since `p`, `q` and `phi` are variables.

**EDIT :**  Actually, it would be better if the small graphics was placed at the bottom of the large one.

Comment: Try `Frame -> TrueFrameTicks -> None, PlotRange -> Full`

Comment: @chris, thanks, this works for the frame around the small graphics.

Comment: Using `Epilog` in the large graphics, and `Inset` for the small graphics could partially solve my issue.  Unfortunately, if I resize the large graphics by hand, the small one isn't well aligned anymore with the marks on the large graphics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it may perhaps be easier just to combine plots and modify (e.g. suppress unnecessary frame ticks). I post this as a motivating answer rather than definitive answer. `li` is a modified version of OP function:

```
li[p_, q_, phi_, {l_, u_}] := 
 DensityPlot[(If[p > 0, Sin[2 Pi p^2 x]/(2 Pi p^2 x), 1] Cos[
      2 Pi p^2 q x + phi/2])^2, {x, -30, 30}, {y, l, u}, 
  AspectRatio -> 0.1, PlotPoints -> {1000, 2}, Frame -> None, 
  ImageSize -> 600]
Manipulate[
 Show[Intensity[0.25, 5, 0], li[0.25, 5, 0, {l, u}]], {l, -1, 0, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{u, -0.5}, -1, 0, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: This solution is simpler and more natural than my `Inset` + `Epilog` solution.  The code is a bit shorter.  I'll adopt it as the solution to the problem.

Comment: @Cham  thank you. My aim with Manipulate was to find the desired bounds. I am glad it was helpful. :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a partial solution, using `Epilog` and `Inset`.  It has an alignment problem, especially after we resize the picture by hand inside the `Manipulate` box.  Also, without resizing the whole, playing with the parameters may give an alignment problem after a while.  How to fix this ?

```
LumIntensity[x_, p_, q_] := (If[p > 0, Sin[2Pi p^2 x]/(2Pi p^2 x), 1]Cos[2Pi p^2 q x])^2

Intensity1[p_, q_] := Inset[
    DensityPlot[LumIntensity[x, p, q],
    {x, -30, 30}, {y, 0, 1},
    ColorFunction -> GrayLevel,
    AspectRatio -> 0.1,
    Frame -> None,
    PlotPoints -> {1000, 2},
    ImageSize -> 600],
    {0, -0.1}
]

Intensity2[p_, q_] := Plot[
    LumIntensity[x, p, q],
    {x, -30, 30},
    PlotPoints -> 400,
    MaxRecursion -> 4,
    PlotRange -> {{-30, 30}, {-0.2, 1}},
    Axes -> None,
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    Frame -> True,
    Epilog -> Intensity1[p, q],
    ImageSize -> {600, 600}
]

Manipulate[
    Intensity2[p, q],
    {{p, 0.25, Style["Diffraction : p", 12]}, 0, 0.5, 0.01,
        ImageSize -> Large, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{q, 1, Style["Interference : q", 12]}, 1, 10, 0.01,
        ImageSize -> Large, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    ControlPlacement -> Bottom,
    FrameMargins -> None
]
```

Preview :

[image: Box]

So how can I make the bottom graphics always well aligned with the graphics above it, even after we resive the whole by hand ?

Comment: I think I've found it.  In the `Inset`, I just need to replace the coordinates `{0, -0.1}` to `{0, -0.1}, {0, 0.5}, 60`.  The result is superb !

Answer (score 1):

Just going to throw this in to the mix.  When I saw this question, it immediately seemed perfect for Jens's [function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6882/9490), which I modified and used previously, and in fact I have it defined in my init.m because I use it with such regularity.

I have modified the original function to respect the individual aspect ratios of the constituent plots, and the definition is in the pastebin linked below.  It's a reasonably large but robust function, which I've used to combine plots for publication for years now.

Using the functions defined in the OP, this is the plotting code,

```
<< "http://pastebin.com/raw/1uhTgyuJ"
plotGrid[{{LumIntensity[0.25, 5, 0]}, {Intensity[0.25, 5, 
    0]}}, 600, 660, "KeepAR" -> True]
```

[image]

The plot can be interactively resized with the mouse and the overall appearance remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by matching a few layout options between the two charts. Namely, `ImageSize`, `ImageMargins`, `ImagePadding`, `PlotRange`, and `PlotRangePadding`.  `Scaled` and `Automatic` can be used to simplify selection.

With

```
f[p_, q_, phi_, x_] := 
   (If[p > 0, Sin[2 Pi p^2 x]/(2 Pi p^2 x), 1] Cos[2 Pi p^2 q x + phi/2])^2

alignment = 
 Sequence[ImageSize -> {600, Automatic}, 
  ImageMargins -> 0, 
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02], 
  ImagePadding -> {{Scaled[.03], Scaled[.01]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}];
```

Then

```
Column[
 {DensityPlot[f[.25, 5, 0, x], {x, -30, 30}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   PlotPoints -> {1000, 2}, Frame -> None, AspectRatio -> .1, 
   Evaluate@alignment],
  Plot[f[.25, 5, 0, x], {x, -30, 30}, 
   PlotRange -> Full, Frame -> True, 
   Evaluate@alignment]},
 Spacings -> Scaled[.0005]]
```

[image]

Since we want to align along the x-axis we only need the x-axis plot range, size, padding, and margin to match between the two plots. The plot range is matched in the plot calls so `alignment` only contains items for size, padding, and margin.  With this the plots have the same width and amount of *whitespace* along the x-axis and so they align.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using `Column` instead of `GraphicsColumn` as I'm currently using 10.3 and it appears that `GraphicsColumn` is ignoring its `Spacings` option.