# Make two plots on top of each other

Tags: plotting

I would like to make a single plot which contains two graphs on top of each other like the plot below (with frames, axes labels and the legend on the top right corner)

[image]

I read [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22521/how-to-make-a-plot-on-top-of-other-plot) and tried to implement it, but it did not work because it removes the labels of the axes when I use `ImagePadding` . Could somebody give me an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
   Frame -> True,
   PlotLegends -> Placed[Framed[LineLegend[{Automatic}, {"Something"}]], ImageScaled[{.8, .9}]]];

p2 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
   Frame -> True,
   PlotLegends -> Placed[Framed[LineLegend[{Automatic}, {"Something"}]], ImageScaled[{.8, .9}]]];

GraphicsColumn[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Almost there! How do I modify the spacing between the two plots? I ran the code but the spacing between them is too large. I want them a bit closer to each other.

Comment: @eemg Add the `Spacings -> Scaled[0]` option to `GraphicsGrid`. Use a negative value rather than `0` to further decrease, but that might cause overlaps.

Comment: There is also: GraphicsGrid[{{p1}, {p2}}]

Comment: You can also use [`ResourceFunction\[“PlotGrid”\]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid) which would do exactly what you want here!