# Discontinue, then continue x-axis of 2D Histogram

Tags: graphics, functions, histograms

I have the pictured Histogram. It was generated by the following lines:

```
H = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "HighEnergyTheoryCollaborations"}]
Histograms`Histogram[Length /@ ConnectedComponents[H], Histograms`HistogramRange -> {0, 25}, AspectRatio -> 2, BaseStyle -> 10]
```

[image]

I cut the x-axis at 25 because there is only one y(x)>0, x>25: x=5835. A better solution would be to cut x at 25, then continue x at 5834 and end it again at 5836. How can I achieve this?

Comment: closely related: [8241](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8241/5478)

Comment: How can the bin width be changed?

Comment: some user who deleted its post suggested this 

Histogram[Select[Length /@ ConnectedComponents[H], # < 1000 &], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, All}]

which gives a plot stopping at 50. User said it may be because bin width is autoset. How can I set bin width?

Comment: @Kuba I can't find by googling "dx histogram mathematica" or "dx mathematica". sure you spelled right? got another keyword for me?

Comment: Details and Options section of [`Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Histogram.html?q=Histogram&lang=en) you can find help about the function by pressing F1.

Answer (score 5):

Considering your working example on which I added `99` data of the maximum value:

```
g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "HighEnergyTheoryCollaborations"}];
data = (Length /@ ConnectedComponents[g]);
(* adding 99 value so it can be seen *)
data = Flatten@Append[data, ConstantArray[Max@data, 99]];
```

You can do the following, which is not very good looking in my opinion:

```
h1 = Histogram[Select[data, # < RankedMax[First /@ Tally@data, 2] &], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, RankedMax[First /@ Tally@data, 2]}, {0, Max[Last /@ Tally@data]}}, 
  Axes -> True, 
  AxesStyle -> {Arrowheads[{0, 0.075}], Automatic}, 
  AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> {230, 350}];

h2 = Histogram[Select[data, RankedMax[First /@ Tally@data, 2] < # <= Max@data &], {1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{Max@data - 2, Max@data + 2}, {0, Max[Last /@ Tally@data]}}, 
  Axes -> {True, False}, 
  AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio*6, Ticks -> {{Max@data}}, 
  ImageSize -> {230/6, 350}];

Grid[{{h1, h2}}, Spacings -> {-1.1, 1}]
```

[image]

**I don't like:**

- The big arrow. That's all I could come up with that looked *correct* in my eyes, but it's not good looking.
- The fact that everything is *user defined* (playing with `AspectRatio`, `ImageSize` or `Ticks`). There should be way to adjust the width of the last box automatically.

---

With the same `data` you can also do the following that I find better looking:

```
h3 = Histogram[Select[data, # < RankedMax[First /@ Tally@data, 2] &], 
  PlotRange -> {{1, RankedMax[First /@ Tally@data, 2]}, {0, Max[Last /@ Tally@data]}}, 
  AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio, Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
  FrameTicks -> All, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> {{Blue, Opacity@0}, {Blue, Opacity@0}}, 
  ImageSize -> {250, 350}];

h4 = Histogram[Select[data, RankedMax[First /@ Tally@data, 2] < # <= Max@data &], {1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{Max@data - RankedMax[First /@ Tally@data, 2] - 2, Max@data + 1}, {0, Max[Last /@ Tally@data]}}, 
  Axes -> None, 
  ChartStyle -> Directive[{Opacity@.5, Red}],
  AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio, Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
  FrameTicks -> All, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> {{Opacity@0, Red}, {Opacity@0, Red}}, 
  ImageSize -> {250, 350}];

Overlay[{h3, h4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice idea with this new one :)

Comment: Thanks! The new one is not as sensitive as the first one at least, but I still don't really like it, it wouldn't work on every set of data.