# Custom plot range cropping

Tags: plotting

I'd like to plot two functions, say,

```
Plot[{1 + Sin[x]/4, 10 + Cos[x]/4}, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Since their amplitudes are really small, I'd like to crop the picture in such a way that I can cut off the empty part of the picture.

Usually I use the following workaround

```
exp2a = Plot[1 + Sin[x]/4, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {Range[0, 10], True, False, False}, 
   AspectRatio -> .5/GoldenRatio, ImagePadding -> {{25, 2}, {15, 2}}];
exp2b = Plot[10 + Cos[x]/4, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {False, True, Range[0, 10], False}, 
   AspectRatio -> .5/GoldenRatio, ImagePadding -> {{25, 2}, {2, 15}}];
exp2 = Column[{exp2b, exp2a}, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]

And, of course, it works. *The problem arises when I need to set the labels as I'd have to use something like `Row` and `Column` (it's really nasty, I'm not going to post it:-).*

My question is as follows: is it possible to crop the irrelevant part of a picture in a more straighforward way? *It'd be great if somehow the labeling could be done in a simple manner.*

Below you can find a picture roughly describing the idea (I apologize for the poor quality). Well, here we have different a log scale and a normal scale (ote the change of ticks on the horisontal axis) but clealy it's a combination of two plot regions.

[image]

In general, it would be great, if something like this could work on the vertical lines as well.

Comment: Perhaps you could use this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/627/193

Comment: Well, ok, this is a solution i was aware of as well. The point is that this method is like the last resort (at least in my case). I believe that the picture is not as clear as stacked plots.

Comment: There was another question about cropped axes, but I can't find it now. I can't remember the keyword (it wasn't "cropped")

Comment: Perhaps this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8241/generating-a-broken-or-snipped-axis-in-listplot

Comment: This looks what I was looking for. I'm not sure about the labeling but I think I can work with it. Thank you!