# Break axes on listcontourplot

Tags: graphics, plotting

I would like to insert a break on both of the axes of a ListContourPlot near the origin, to include  a datapoint which has axis values quite far away from the others. The question is similar in nature to this one:

[Generating a broken or snipped axis in ListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8241/generating-a-broken-or-snipped-axis-in-listplot)

Although, this is for a single axis on a simple Listplot, and I don't think it would be usable in this case.

To be clear, I am looking for a break in **BOTH** of the axes on a **ListContourPlot**, which would allow me to include the origin (0,0) on this graph below:

[image]

Although it looks like a single break on the x axis would work, I actually beed a double break, as between 0.01 and 0 on the y is not plotable.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Best,

Ben

Comment: But what you want to do with the contours around the breaks? They will look rather ugly!

Comment: @belisarius Thanks for your reply. The whole graph would simply be shifted towards top right. I only want to label a point, having whitespace between there and the rest of the contour plot.

Comment: Ok, but that isn't "Breaking axes on ListContourplot[]` since `ListContourplot` doesn't do that kind of things.