# How to delete part of a constant plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a plot that looks like this:
[image]

and what bothers me is that the center straight line is that long. The plot would look a lot better if I were somehow able to delete everything from -3 to 3.  Is that understandable?

Thank you for your help. Here is my code for the center line:

```
Plot[sigma2[y], {y, -yT + h1/2, -yT + h1/2 + h2}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[.008], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {StandardForm["Višina nosilca [mm]"], 
   StandardForm["Trdnost [MPa]"]}, 
 PlotLabel -> HoldForm[Subscript[σ, 2] "(y)"]]
```

Comment: Do you need a broken axes? Like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8245/10397)?

Comment: I think @rhermans has the right suggestion for you; if you *don't* want a broken axis though, you will want to use a `RegionFunction` specification in your `Plot` (e.g. `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x < -3 || x > 3]`) to prevent `Plot` from displaying anything in that region of your plot.

Comment: @MarcoB, you can just use `Abs[x] > 3` to make that a little bit more compact.  The answers in that post linked above need some tweaking to work with a discontinuous horizontal axis.

Comment: @rhermans YES! That is way better than my idea! :) Thank you!