# Horizontal Bar Chart splitting axis, and putting labels in the the center

Tags: labeling, charts, customization

I am trying to generate a horizontal bar chart which is centered at zero. Currently what I have is this:

[image]

And the code that  I am using is:

```
BarChart[{{0.91, 0.87}, {-0.3, -0.27}, {0.1, 0.05}, {0.95, 1}}, 
 BarOrigin -> Left, BarSpacing -> {0, 1.5}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style["Stokes", Black, Bold, FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> font], 
 ChartStyle -> {LightRed, LightBlue}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, ChartLegends -> {"Measured", "Generated"}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{Style["S3", Black, Bold, FontSize -> 15, 
      FontFamily -> font], 
     Style["S2", Black, Bold, FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> font], 
     Style["S1", Black, Bold, FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> font], 
     Style["DOP", Black, Bold, FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> font]}, 
    Above], Placed[{}, Top]}, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Rotate[#, 0* Pi], 
     If[Abs[#1] > 0.5, Right, {{1, 0}, {-0.2, 0}}]] &)]
```

I would like to make a couple of modifications. First of all, I would like to create a gap between the x-axis and -x-axis and place the labels corresponding to each group (like DOP, S1 etc) in the middle. Furthermore, currently, I manually change the location of the data labels for bars which are too short, but how can I automatically position the data labels such that they don't overlap with the bars if bars are too short? Thanks!

Comment: This might be of use: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8241/121

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you can get most of your requirements using `PairedBarChart`.

First, define a function to transform the original data so that it can be used as input for `PairedBarChart`:

```
ClearAll[bcToPbc]
bcToPbc = Sequence @@ ({ # /. _?Positive :> None, # /. _?Negative :>  None} /. 
  {x_?Negative :> Labeled[-x, x, If[Abs[x] > 0.5, Left, Before]],
   y_?Positive :> Labeled[y, y, If[Abs[y] > 0.5, Right, After]]}) &;
```

Example 1:

```
data = {{0.91, 0.87}, {-0.3, -0.27}, {0.1, 0.05}, {0.95, 1}}; 
newdata = bcToPbc @ data;
```

Then use `PairedBarChart` with appropriate option settings:

```
font = "Calibri";
pbc = PairedBarChart[newdata, BarSpacing -> {.5, 1.5, 0},
  PlotLabel -> Style["Stokes", Black, Bold, 15, font], 
  ChartStyle -> {LightRed, LightBlue}, 
  ChartLegends -> {"Measured", "Generated"}, 
  ChartLabels -> {None, Placed[Style[#, Black, Bold, 15, font] & /@ {"S3", "S2", "S1", 
  "DOP"}, Axis], None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Post-process to change the tick labels on the left panel:

```
MapAt[# /. Text[x_, y___] :> Text[-x, y] &, pbc, {{1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Example 2:

```
d = Round[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 5}], .01];

BarChart[d, BarSpacing -> {0, 2}, 
 ChartLabels -> {None, Placed[Style[#, Black, Bold, 15, "Panel"] & /@ {"C", "B", "A"}, 
    Axis], None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
PairedBarChart[bcToPbc@d, BarSpacing -> {.25, 2, 0}, 
 ChartLabels -> {None, Placed[Style[#, Black, Bold, 15, "Panel"] & /@ {"C", "B", "A"}, 
    Axis], None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]