# Dividing a plot into multiple plots by y-axis intervals and finding the midpoint value of each graph

Tags: plotting

I'm new to *Mathematica*. I have a `Plot` that I would like to divide evenly at the y-axis. I can divide evenly at x-axis if I set the min and max range of `x`.

**But, how do I do that at the y-axis, and how do I show the midpoint (x,y values) of each graph?**

I would like to show part of the graph when for eg: Plot situation at y-axis from `0-0.2` / `0.2-0.4` / `0.4-0.6` and so forth...but without changing the plotrange that have been set

Here is the code

```
k = 155900;
F3 = Plot[
  Sqrt[2] √(√(1/m1^2 + 
         20 Sqrt[3118] (1/m1)^(3/2) Sqrt[1/50] + 
         3118020 Sqrt[3118] Sqrt[1/m1] (1/50)^(3/2) + 
         24304810001/50^2 + 623602/(m1 50)) - 
      10 Sqrt[3118] Sqrt[1/m1] Sqrt[1/50] - k/50)
  , {m1, 5, 500}
  , PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, {0, 1}}
  , AxesLabel -> {m1, SuperStar[E]}
  ]
```

[image: The graph]

Comment: "divide evenly at y-axis" - this is unclear; please clarify what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I would like to show part of the graph when for eg: graph situation at y-axis from 0-0.2/ 0.2-0.4/ 0.4-0.6/ and so forth. Sorry for my english. I tried to clarify as best as I can.

Comment: `k` is undefined.

Comment: lets say k value is 155900

Comment: Maybe you can change the ticks distribution of the y-axis using the package CustomTicks  https://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/CustomTicksGuide.pdf

Comment: So you want to make 6 plots, first for `y` in `0-0.2`, second for `y` in `0.2-0.4` etc.?

Comment: Yes. but without changing the plot range.

Comment: I'm can't understand what is been asked here. @AhmadRuzaini禅, do you have any examples of plots or graphs that are similar to what you need? Can you please [edit] your question to include an example of the expected output? And clarify the text in the question whenever possible.

Comment: By the way, welcome to Mma.SE! To make the most of the site start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned. (Notice the links in the comment)

Comment: Related: [(6877)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6877/121), [(8241)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8241/121)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will work for you.

```
With[{k = 155900},
  Column[
    Table[
      Plot[
        Sqrt[2] 
          Sqrt[
            Sqrt[1/m1^2 + 20 Sqrt[3118] (1/m1)^(3/2) Sqrt[1/50] + 
              3118020 Sqrt[3118] Sqrt[1/m1] (1/50)^(3/2) + 
              24304810001/50^2 + 623602/(m1 50)] - 
            10 Sqrt[3118] Sqrt[1/m1] Sqrt[1/50] - k/50], 
        {m1, 5, 500},
        PlotRange -> {All, interval},
        AxesLabel -> {m1, SuperStar[E]}],
      {interval, Partition[Range[0., .6, .2], 2, 1]}]]]
```

[image: plots]

Answer (score 0):

```
k = 155900;
GraphicsColumn@Table[
  Show[Plot[
    Sqrt[2] \[Sqrt](\[Sqrt](1/m1^2 + 
           20 Sqrt[3118] (1/m1)^(3/2) Sqrt[1/50] + 
           3118020 Sqrt[3118] Sqrt[1/m1] (1/50)^(3/2) + 
           24304810001/50^2 + 623602/(m1 50)) - 
        10 Sqrt[3118] Sqrt[1/m1] Sqrt[1/50] - k/50), {m1, 5, 500}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, r}, AxesLabel -> {"m1", SuperStar[E]}],
   PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, {0, 1}}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], {r, {{.4, .8}, {.2, .4}, {0, .2}}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
expr = Sqrt[2] √(√(1/m1^2 + 20 Sqrt[3118] (1/m1)^(3/2) Sqrt[1/50] + 
     3118020 Sqrt[3118] Sqrt[1/m1] (1/50)^(3/2) + 24304810001/50^2 + 623602/(m1 50)) - 
     10 Sqrt[3118] Sqrt[1/m1] Sqrt[1/50] - k/50);
```

Using `ConditionalExpression`:

```
Row[Plot[ConditionalExpression[expr, # <= expr <= #2], {m1, 5, 500}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, {0, 1}}, AxesLabel -> {m1, SuperStar[E]}, 
    ImageSize -> 300] & @@@ {{0.4, 0.8}, {0.2, 0.4}, {0., 0.2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using `MeshFunctions` and `MeshShading`:

```
Row[Plot[expr, {m1, 5, 500}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
    MeshShading -> {None, Blue}, Mesh -> {#},   MeshStyle -> Opacity[0],
    PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, {0, 1}}, AxesLabel -> {m1, SuperStar[E]}, 
    ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {{0.4, 0.8}, {0.2, 0.4}, {0., 0.2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do I show the midpoint for each of the graph? For eg: for graph 0.6-0.4, it will display the midpoint of x and y coordinates of it in the graph.