# How to change the distance between individual ticks on my axis?

Tags: graphics, visualization, ticks

I have a small deal of experience with *Mathematica* for the use in physics and am in no capacity an expert.

My issue is that I am creating a discrete plot that has data at very large distance from each other and therefore seems too elongated for decent resolution of what I need. I will provide an example below of how it looks:

[image: Elongated Plot/ Still bad resolution]

If I change the aspect ratio to where I can see the waves clearly it becomes far too large and long and if I shrink it I cannot see the wave behavior very well:

[image: Not as Elongated/ No resolution]

[image]

Now my solution to the problem is to somehow change the tick to tick distance in order for the discrete levels to be closer but still accurately depict the data and get better resolution.

I have looked at almost all the tick documentation and the questions on here and see nothing on the inherent distance of the ticks and how it can be done. 
I've used the *Mathematica* built-in functions `Ticks` and `FrameTicks` and even tried to construct my own ticks using `Table` and inserting it into `Ticks`.

My overall goal is to shrink the vertical axis while keeping the horizontal about the same.

Solutions to the problem for me would be to change the tick distance and thus make the discrete levels more compact. Another would be to change the size of the y-axis only without the X-axis which seems like functionality that is not available. Something I also found interesting is the `Ticks` command seems to have an option that takes in three values and one is the length, but i cant get the proper code to use that.

Please do not confuse this question with the spacing of the ticks to the axes label and call it duplicate. If I can edit the question to better justify or explain please let me know. And please don't be disrespectful, like I said I'm not an expert or a computer scientist.

Comment: Would using a y Log-scale be a solution for your problem?

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate of a different question than the one suggested by @Mathe172. It's not an exact duplicate, but my answer to it contains everything necessary to solve your problem.

Comment: @Ruud3.1415 Using the y-log scale has very similar result

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Your solution is unnecessarily complicated for my purposes. Like i said im using mathametica as a utility and not to code. I am looking for a simple way to fix my issue. Please provide this or take the duplicate off ,as this question is unique. Thank you

Comment: @LLlAMnYP to be clear, i am also not trying to switch to logarithm because it has little effect on the outcome. I have tried to plot this is log scale and the result is the same.

Comment: The point of marking a question as "duplicate" is not meant to be a personal attack on the topic-starter, but facilitates searching and prevents *duplication of effort*. Furthermore, it is absolutely normal in traditional programming languages to use external libraries to solve certain problems, even if they have a larger functionality in general. Likewise, my solution also provides a method to omit the unnecessary whitespace in your plots. Just load the definition of `AxisBreaks` then use something like `{{5,15,1},{35,45,1},{85,95,1},{155,165,1}}` for `specs`.

Comment: By the way, the other [linked question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8241/26956) also should solve your problem with minimal modification.