# Squish Axes Plot

Tags: plotting

Is there a way to squish the axes plots at the start of a 2d data plot. For example, imagine a signal from a wave has a continuous signal when $x\in [0,L]$ and out-with $L$ the plot becomes noisy.

I am looking for a way to shrink the region $[0,L]$ then return to a normal scale out-with this.

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8241/generating-a-broken-or-snipped-axis-in-listplot) should give you ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ScalingFunctions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) option of most Plot functions.
A simple Example made by myself:

```
Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}, ScalingFunctions -> {Function[If[# < 0.0, # 0.1, #]], Function[If[# < 0.0, # 10, #]]} ]
```

[image: non linear y-axis example]

The first Function is the one scaling the axis. You also need to provide it's inverse. Otherwise ticks will not work properly. Compare:

```
Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}, ScalingFunctions -> {Function[If[# < 0.0, # 0.1, #]], Function[#]} ]
```

[image: Broken Axes]