# Broken y axis at multiple locations

Tags: plotting

I have some data that I want to compare on a broken y axis. I found a similar post [Generating a broken or snipped axis in ListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8241/generating-a-broken-or-snipped-axis-in-listplot) but it is only for one break in the y-axis. For my plot, I want three breaks in the y-axis. One between zero and the first set of data, between the first and second set of data, and between the second and third set of data. I have a sketch of what I would like the data to look like. The snip function I was using from the post I listed seems to only let you set it to 0 or 1, so the squiggle can only go on top or the bottom of the plot, but in some cases I need the squiggle on both ends. Also, the code I got from that post cuts off some of my points?

And eventually, I want the data points to not be color coded but rather black and data1, data2, data3, and data4 corresponding to squares, triangles, diamonds, and x's as shown in the photo.

Here is my code so far:

```
list1 = {6.9310, 6.9362, 6.9427, 6.9484, 6.9538, 6.9579, 6.9611, 
   6.9633, 6.9661, 6.9666, 6.9682, 6.9695, 6.9702};
list2 = {6.9659, 6.9722, 6.9799, 6.9869, 6.9933, 6.9980, 7.0019, 
   7.0047, 7.0079, 7.0086, 7.0103, 7.0119, 7.0128};
list3 = {4.1774, 4.1845, 4.1926, 4.1999, 4.2069, 4.2116, 4.2157, 
   4.2187, 4.222, 4.2228, 4.2244, 4.226, 4.2269};
list4 = { 4.0106, 4.0114, 4.0129, 4.0137, 4.0154, 4.0167, 4.0175, 
   4.0176, 4.0192, 4.0189, 4.0202, 4.0208, 4.021};
listtot = {0.000, 0.099, 0.196, 0.291, 0.385, 0.476, 0.566, 0.654, 
   0.741, 0.826, 0.909, 1.111, 1.304};
data1 = Transpose[{listtot, list1}];
data2 = Transpose[{listtot, list2}];
data3 = Transpose[{listtot, list3}];
data4 = Transpose[{listtot, list4}];
snip[pos_] := 
  Arrowheads[{{Automatic, pos, 
     Graphics[{BezierCurve[{{0, -(1/2)}, {1/2, 0}, {-(1/2), 0}, {0, 
          1/2}}]}]}}];
getMaxPadding[p_List] := 
 Map[Max, (BorderDimensions@
        Image[Show[#, LabelStyle -> White, Background -> White]] & /@ 
      p)~Flatten~{{3}, {2}}, {2}] + 1
p1 = ListPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> False, 
   Mesh -> Full, PlotStyle -> Red, Axes -> {False, True}, 
   AxesStyle -> {None, snip[0]}, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
   ImagePadding -> {{40, 20}, {5, 5}}];
p3 = ListPlot[data3, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> False, Mesh -> Full, 
   PlotStyle -> Green, Axes -> {False, True}, 
   AxesStyle -> {None, snip[1]}, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
   ImagePadding -> {{40, 20}, {5, 5}}];
p4 = ListPlot[data4, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> False, Mesh -> Full, 
   PlotStyle -> Orange, AxesStyle -> {None, snip[1]}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> {{40, 20}, {15, 5}}];
Column[{p1, p3, p4} /. 
  Graphics[x__] :> 
   Graphics[x, ImagePadding -> getMaxPadding[{p1, p2, p3, p4}], 
    ImageSize -> 400]]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: definetly the best question and answer about broken axis on Mathematica

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Lukas Lang's [ResourceFunction[PlotGrid]](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid/) as follows:

```
plotGrid = ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"];
```

Add the option `Frame -> True` to all plots:

```
plt1 = ListPlot[{data1, data2}, Joined -> False, Mesh -> Full, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True];

plt3 = ListPlot[data3, Joined -> False, Mesh -> Full, 
   PlotStyle -> Green, Frame -> True];

plt4 = ListPlot[data4, Joined -> False, Mesh -> Full, 
   PlotStyle -> Orange, Frame -> True];
```

Construct an empty graphics to add as the last and/or first row:

```
emptygraphics = Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.3}, {0, 1}},  Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Automatic, Automatic}}];
```

Use `plotGrid` with the option `"MergeAxes" -> "Cut"` and appropriate values for the option `Spacings`:

```
plotGrid[{{emptygraphics}, {plt1}, {plt3}, {plt4}, {emptygraphics}}, 
  ImageSize -> 700, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
  "MergeAxes" -> "Cut", Spacings -> {0, 20}, 
  ItemSize -> {1, {1/4, 1, 1, 1, 1/4}}]
```

[image]

Add the option `FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, Opacity[0]}, {Automatic, Opacity[0]}}` to all plots to make top and right frames invisible:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! That helped tremendously. Only question I have, how can I make the axes black instead of gray? I tried `AxesStyle -> Black`, `AxesStyle-> Directive[Black]`, `FrameStyle` as well but nothing seems to be doing the trick. @kglr

Comment: @btilson, add the option `FrameStyle->Black` to `emptygraphics`, `plt1`, `plt3` and `plt4`.

Comment: If I type `FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, Opacity[0]}, {Automatic, Opacity[0]}}, FrameStyle -> Black` then it only obeys the first FrameStyle. If I switch them like this: `FrameStyle -> Black, FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, Opacity[0]}, {Automatic, Opacity[0]}}` then it becomes black but the two axes pop up on the top and right side? @kglr

Comment: I figured it out! @kglr I just need to replace `Automatic` with `Black`. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer should be highlighted on top of the rest of "broken axes" solutions on StackExchange. You saved me tons of time with this reply and mentioning this package!