# Plot with one axis, two scales

Tags: plotting

I want to plot data from two functions, one of which goes from 0 to 0.05 and the other from 0.05 to 1. I want the curves, which have different scales, to be presented in the same frame, but I don't want two axes.

I wan't the y-Axis to be divided into two ranges (0, 0.05) and (0.05, 1). The first range should have a larger (linear) scale and take up, let's say, 1/3 of the axis.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Broken y axis at multiple locations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253120/broken-y-axis-at-multiple-locations) - you can of course use the same technique to create only one axis break