# How to remove part of a plot range between the data?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, regionplot

Is there a way to manipulate a plot range to be non continuous?
I mean, I have some data that goes from x=18;;25 and then x=45;;50.
I want to plot the in the same ListPlot, but if I do so there's a blank space between the two parts of the data.
I try PlotRange, DataRannge, and ScalingFunction, but I did not manage to do what I want.
My data looks like this now: [image]

I would like to have something like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Does this answer your question? [Generating a broken or snipped axis in ListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8241/generating-a-broken-or-snipped-axis-in-listplot)

Comment: It does. Thank you.