# How do I make framed plots the same size?

Tags: plotting

Suppose that I have two plots, `plot1` and `plot2`.  The plots have different ranges and different axes.  Here is a fictitious example that makes no scientific sense, but demonstrates my issue with the size of framed plots:

```
imgSize = 475;

plot1 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x (nm)", "y (nm)"}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 20}, ImageSize -> imgSize];

plot2 = Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-10, 1000}, 
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\"x\", \"a\"], \
\"2\"]\) (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\"nm\", \"2\"]\))", 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\"y\", \"b\"], \"2\"]\) (\!\(\
\*SuperscriptBox[\"nm\", \"2\"]\))"}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 20}, ImageSize -> imgSize];

Grid[{{plot1, plot2}}]
```

I get this output:

[image: plotsize]

Notice that `plot1` and `plot2` are not really the same size -- in terms of the size of the outer frame of each.  In particular, the outer frame of `plot1` has greater height than that of `plot2`.  In addition, I think that the outer frame of `plot1` has greater width than that of `plot2`.  I think this is because of the different ranges and different axis labels of the two plots.

Observed separately, one probably could not discern a difference in size between `plot1` and `plot2`.  But when they are next to each other, as in a `Grid`, `plot1` looks noticeably "larger" than `plot2`.  This would look rather poor in a publication, like an article in a scientific journal.

Is there any way that I can make the outer frames the same size, such that the plots look like they are the same size?

Comment: Try [LevelScheme](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/).

Comment: A question with a slightly different goal but similar issues is here: [Do I have to code each case of this Grid full of plots separately?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6877/245)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As Jagra said, the usual solution is to manually specify the `ImagePadding` values.  The problem is that if the plot or frame labels are too large, a fixed `ImagePadding` may cut them off.

*But can we automate this?*

Ideally what we would do is:

- Create the two plots of fixed vertical size and retrieve their vertical `ImagePadding`
- Change the `ImagePadding` of both to use the larger value.  This will ensure that they have the same size while no labels are cut off.

So how do we measure the `ImagePadding` of an existing plot?  This is unfortunately tricky as the value *depends on the size of the plot*.  Since the plots will be stacked horizontally, we need to fix the vertical image size before trying to retrieve the padding.  But here's a pretty useful solution (that I use regularly):

- [Retrieving the ImagePadding in absolute units](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2093/12)

First note that I'm fixing the vertical size instead of the horizontal one.  This allows the graphics to have differing horizontal sizes if necessary while still aligning perfectly when stacked in a row.

```
verticalSize = 250;

plot1 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x (nm)", "y (nm)"}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 20}, 
   ImageSize -> {Automatic, verticalSize}];

plot2 = Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-10, 1000}, 
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\"x\", \"a\"], \
\"2\"]\) (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\"nm\", \"2\"]\))", 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\"y\", \"b\"], \"2\"]\) \
(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\"nm\", \"2\"]\))"}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 20}, 
   ImageSize -> {Automatic, verticalSize}];
```

This function measures the padding (based on @Heike's code):

```
getPadding[g_] := Module[{im},
  im = Image[Show[g, LabelStyle -> White, Background -> White]];
  BorderDimensions[im]
  ]
```

Now let's choose the larger one of both the top and bottom paddings of the two figures.  This will give us the minimum image padding that still does not cut off labels.

```
{p1h, p1v} = getPadding[plot1];

{p2h, p2v} = getPadding[plot2];

verticalPadding = Max /@ Transpose[{p1v, p2v}]

Row[{
  Show[plot1, ImagePadding -> {p1h, verticalPadding}],
  Show[plot2, ImagePadding -> {p2h, verticalPadding}]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem with this approach is that often one would wish to fix the horizontal size of the whole graphic (to fit the text width of the document).  I admit that when I had the same problem I did this by iteratively refining the sizes, which is not very elegant, but produces good results automatically.

Answer (score 19):

ImagePadding should get you most of want you want:

```
imgSize = 475;
imagePadding = {{100, 10}, {25, 10}};

plot1 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x (nm)", "y (nm)"}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 20}, ImageSize -> imgSize, 
   ImagePadding -> imagePadding];

plot2 = Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-10, 1000}, 
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\"x\", \"a\"], \
\"2\"]\) (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\"nm\", \"2\"]\))", 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\"y\", \"b\"], \"2\"]\) \
(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\"nm\", \"2\"]\))"}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 20}, ImageSize -> imgSize, 
   ImagePadding -> imagePadding];

Grid[{{plot1, plot2}}]
```

[image]

You can play around with the values to get what you need.  Hmmm?  I wonder if one could automate the selection of the optimum values?

Answer (score 11):

Use the undocumented (but not likely to go away) [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize) syntax `ImageSize -> Automatic -> width`:

```
imgSize = Automatic -> 300;
```

Then, your code produces:

```
Grid[{{plot1, plot2}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just use `GraphicsRow` and only need to specify `ImageSize` in `GraphicsRow`. This is a [new feature](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/core-visualization/align-frame-edges.html?product=language) in version 12.

```
plot1 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x (nm)", "y (nm)"}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 20}];

plot2 = Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-10, 1000}, 
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\"x\", \"a\"], \
\"2\"]\) (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\"nm\", \"2\"]\))", 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\"y\", \"b\"], \"2\"]\) \
(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\"nm\", \"2\"]\))"}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", 20}];

GraphicsRow[{plot1, plot2}, ImageSize -> 800]
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know If this is a correct answer. But at least it works for me in Mathematica 11 for Students.

If I put `Axes->False` in my frame plots the plotting area stays the same regardless if the ticks are wider or shorter in each graph (granted they have the same `ImageSize`).

I don't understand why it happens, but for someone from the future this could be helpful. You can add the axes back with `Gridlines` and your plotting areas will stay the same in each plot.

PD: If I change `Axes->True` then the plotting areas are different, that's how I know this tag is what changes things.