# Make legend same height as plot

Tags: plotting, legending

One common style for density plots is to have a vertical legend that is the same height as the plot itself. Some example density plots from [Google Image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=density%20plot&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=UpW2UPuEIMj5igKU24Eo&biw=1132&bih=919&sei=VJW2UPO1IYXUiwKqiYCQDg#q=density%20plot&um=1&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&sa=N&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=fflb&tbm=isch&tbs=simg:CAESEgkZAIEfYuS5iSFQ5Gmu4yT3DQ&iact=hc&vpx=470&vpy=311&dur=946&hovh=179&hovw=282&tx=22&ty=270&sig=115489543708262199624&ei=VZW2ULiWJ4XaigLIjYHgDA&page=1&tbnh=134&tbnw=232&ved=1t:722,r:9,s:0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=eb2df208a710fafa&bpcl=38897761&biw=1132&bih=919):

[image: Density plots from Google Image search]

How can we make [DensityPlots](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DensityPlot.html) with legends whose height matches the height of the plot? By default the heights are different:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Default DensityPlot with legend]

Comment: I guess you mean with the new built-in legending? If not, there's [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2064/5)

Comment: You can resize them manually. They have handles you can drag.

Comment: Maybe you can also use [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6380/245)

Comment: It is odd that it clips the top of the frame, just did it on my machine and I get the same image artifact ... ugh

Answer (score 17):

Elaborating a little on Sjoerd's answer:

Specifying `LegendMargins` makes it even clearer that the fancy new legend might be not as useful as I first thought. We now have a working legend but lost basically all control over its apearance:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ImageSize -> {300, 300},
 ImagePadding -> {{30, 30}, {30, 30}}, Background -> LightGray, 
 PlotLegends -> 
 BarLegend["LakeColors", 
           LegendMargins -> {{10, 0}, {30, 20}}, 
           LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 10] &)
           ]]
```

[image]

The upper edge of the `BarLegend` appears to allign roughly with the `Plot` canvas, but we now have the additional 30 points  `Margin` at the top. Unfortunately if we change the Bottom `Margin` everything rescales:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ImageSize -> {300, 300},
 ImagePadding -> {{30, 30}, {30, 30}}, Background -> LightGray, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend["LakeColors", 
            LegendMargins -> {{10, 0}, {10, 20}}, 
            LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 10] &)
           ]]
```

[image]

Again the `Legend` claims additional space above and below the `Plot`. Imagine the nightmare in a `GraphicsGrid` with different kinds of Plots.  To me, it appears as if the chance of ever aligning to `Plots` (and their Legends) next to each other are basically zero.

Looking at the `InputForm` of the above `Plot` gives a huge expression with `Head` `Legended`:

> Legended[ .......,
>          {Placed[BarLegend["LakeColors", 
>           LegendFunction -> (Framed[#1,    FrameMargins -> 10] & ), 
>           LegendLayout -> "Column", 
>           LegendMargins -> {{10, 0}, {10, 20}}, 
>           LegendMarkerSize -> 300, 
>           Charting`TickSide -> Right, 
>           ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
>           LegendMargins -> {{10, 0}, {10, 20}},
>           LegendFunction -> (Framed[#1, FrameMargins -> 10] & )]
>         , After, Identity]}]

We note two things: first there is the use of `LegendMarkerSize` that appears to take the vertical `ImageSize`. Fiddling with it can improve the result a little:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ImageSize -> {300, 300},
 ImagePadding -> {{30, 30}, {30, 30}}, Background -> LightGray, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend["LakeColors", 
  LegendMargins -> {{10, 0}, {-10, -10}}, 
  LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 10] &), 
  LegendMarkerSize -> 300]
 ]
```

gives:

[image]

The second thing is the usage of `Charting`TickSide -> Right`, which controls where the Ticks are written.

I tried to find where the `Charting`*` stuff is defined, but could only get the following large list of expressions:

```
Names["Charting`*"]

{"Charting'angleCalc", "Charting'angleToValue", 
 "Charting'AngularScale", "Charting'apportion", 
 "Charting'AutomaticBar", "Charting'AutomaticBar3D", 
 "Charting'AutomaticBubble", "Charting'AutomaticBubble3D", 
 "Charting'AutomaticSector", "Charting'AutomaticSector3D", 
 "Charting'AutomaticTrap", "Charting'AxesLabelRotate", 
 "Charting'AxisAnnotation", "Charting'AxisAppearance", 
 "Charting'AxisFactor", "Charting'AxisLabel", "Charting'BackTesting", 
 "Charting'barPointtoValue", "Charting'barValHeight", 
 "Charting'barValueToPoint", "Charting'BoxElements", 
 "Charting'BulletCheck", "Charting'canonicalPlotLegends", 
 "Charting'canonicalWrapperLegends", "Charting'CanvasPadding", 
 "Charting'CategoricalAxis", "Charting'CategoryBounds", 
 "Charting'CategorySpacing", "Charting'ChartArgCheck", 
 "Charting'ChartHighlighting", "Charting'ChartLegendsParser", 
 "Charting'ChartParser", "Charting'ChartStyleBlock", 
 "Charting'ChartStyleInformation", "Charting'checkChartElement", 
 "Charting'checkColor", "Charting'checkGridLines", 
 "Charting'ClickEffect", "Charting'ClockCheck", 
 "Charting'colorfunctionScale", "Charting'CompleteSizes", 
 "Charting'computeScenePlotRange", "Charting'computeSceneRange", 
 "Charting'ConstructColorFunction", "Charting'ConstructDirective", 
 "Charting'ConstructErrorBars", "Charting'constructLegends", 
 "Charting'CoordinateListQ", "Charting'CoordinateQ", 
 "Charting'createDefaultLabels", "Charting'createPlotRange", 
 "Charting'createPlotRange3D", "Charting'dataExtremes", 
 "Charting'DateAxis", "Charting'datedDataExtremes", 
 "Charting'DateFormat", "Charting'DateScale", "Charting'DateScope", 
 "Charting'DateValueParser", "Charting'dbPrint", 
 "Charting'DefaultPlotStyle", "Charting'DisplayFunctionTest", 
 "Charting'DivisionLabelingFunction", "Charting'drawLegendMarkers", 
 "Charting'drawLegends", "Charting'drawMarkers", 
 "Charting'drawMarkers3D", "Charting'DynamicAction", 
 "Charting'DynamicImage", "Charting'edgeDirective", 
 "Charting'emptyDataQ", "Charting'ErrorBar", 
 "Charting'ErrorBarFunction", "Charting'ErrorBarSize", 
 "Charting'ErrorBarStyle", "Charting'expandFilling", 
 "Charting'expandPlaced", "Charting'expandPlotRange", 
 "Charting'expandPlotRange3D", "Charting'extractLabels", 
 "Charting'FilterGraphics3DOptions", "Charting'FilterGraphicsOptions", 
 "Charting'FinancialIndicatorList", 
 "Charting'FinancialIndicatorLists", "Charting'FinancialIndicators", 
 "Charting'FinancialPattern", "Charting'findAxesOrigin", 
 "Charting'FindGrid", "Charting'findPlotRange", "Charting'FindTicks", 
 "Charting'FindTicksP", "Charting'gaugeBoxes", "Charting'GaugeCheck", 
 "Charting'generalDirective", 
 "Charting'generateLegendDynamicVariable", "Charting'generateLegends", 
 "Charting'get2DPlotRange", "Charting'get3DPlotRange", 
 "Charting'getBasicStyles", "Charting'getBasicStyles2", 
 "Charting'getDataExtremes", "Charting'getExtremes", 
 "Charting'GetGraphicsOptions", "Charting'getPlotStyles", 
 "Charting'getQuantityLabel", "Charting'getSideMarker", 
 "Charting'getTargetUnits", "Charting'getTrendStyle", 
 "Charting'gridlinesFinder", "Charting'HeldOptionQ", 
 "Charting'Highlighted", "Charting'HistArgCheck", 
 "Charting'HorizontalScale", "Charting'iBarChart", 
 "Charting'iBarChart3D", "Charting'iBarLegend", 
 "Charting'iBoxWhiskerChart", "Charting'iBubbleChart", 
 "Charting'iBubbleChart3D", "Charting'iCandlestickChart", 
 "Charting'iDensityHistogram", "Charting'iDialGauge", 
 "Charting'iDistributionChart", "Charting'iFinancialIndicatorLists", 
 "Charting'iHistogram", "Charting'iHistogram3D", 
 "Charting'iHistogramList", "Charting'iInteractiveTradingChart", 
 "Charting'iKagiChart", "Charting'iLegended", "Charting'iLinearGauge", 
 "Charting'iLineBreakChart", "Charting'iLineLegend", 
 "Charting'IndicatorFunction", "Charting'Indicators", 
 "Charting'interactiveTradingChartActionMenu", 
 "Charting'interactiveTradingChartResetButton", 
 "Charting'interactiveTradingChartSnapshotButton", 
 "Charting'iPairedBarChart", "Charting'iPairedHistogram", 
 "Charting'iPointFigureChart", "Charting'iPointLegend", 
 "Charting'iRenkoChart", "Charting'iSectorChart", 
 "Charting'iSectorChart3D", "Charting'iSwatchLegend", 
 "Charting'iTradingChart", "Charting'LabelSide", "Charting'Legend", 
 "Charting'LegendCanvas", "Charting'LegendConstructer", 
 "Charting'legendize", "Charting'LegendSize", 
 "Charting'LegendWrapper", "Charting'listDepthCount", 
 "Charting'ListScale", "Charting'lookUpIndicators", 
 "Charting'mainChart", "Charting'makeDynamicModule", 
 "Charting'makeGaugeBoxes", "Charting'MemoryLeakTest", 
 "Charting'MouseEffect", "Charting'nearestDate", "Charting'negativeQ", 
 "Charting'nonNegativeQ", "Charting'noShow", "Charting'Nothing", 
 "Charting'OHLC", "Charting'OHLCV", "Charting'optCheck", 
 "Charting'padChartElements", "Charting'PadLabels", 
 "Charting'padList", "Charting'padMarkerStyle", 
 "Charting'padMarkerStyle2", "Charting'padMarkerStyle3", 
 "Charting'PairedCategoryAxis", "Charting'PairedChartArgCheck", 
 "Charting'PairedHistArgCheck", "Charting'ParametricScale", 
 "Charting'parseBulletChart", "Charting'parseChartElements", 
 "Charting'parseChartElementsRow", "Charting'parseChartLabels", 
 "Charting'parseChartLabelsRow", "Charting'parseChartLegends", 
 "Charting'parseChartLegends2", "Charting'parseClock", 
 "Charting'parseLabelingFunction", "Charting'parseLegendPlotStyle", 
 "Charting'parsePlotMarkers", "Charting'parsePlotMarkers3D", 
 "Charting'parseThermometer", "Charting'PatternsFunction", 
 "Charting'PFLP", "Charting'PictorialBar", "Charting'PictorialBar3D", 
 "Charting'PictorialBubble", "Charting'PictorialBubble3D", 
 "Charting'PictorialTrap", "Charting'PlainAutomaticBar3D", 
 "Charting'PlotArgCheck", "Charting'PlotOrigin", 
 "Charting'PlotParser", "Charting'PlotTheme", 
 "Charting'polarMarkerLabeling", "Charting'polarMarkerLabeling3D", 
 "Charting'polygonDirective", "Charting'positiveQ", 
 "Charting'PruneOptions", "Charting'RadialScale", 
 "Charting'RangeBarChart", "Charting'realNumericQ", 
 "Charting'RenderAssembler", "Charting'RenderMarker", 
 "Charting'RenderMouseEffect", "Charting'rescale", 
 "Charting'resetAngle", "Charting'resolveHighlighting", 
 "Charting'resolveLabeled", "Charting'resolveLabeledDynamic", 
 "Charting'resolveLabeledStatic", "Charting'resolveLabelingFunction", 
 "Charting'resolveLabelingFunctionDynamic", 
 "Charting'resolveLabelingFunctionStatic", 
 "Charting'resolveMarkerLabeling", "Charting'resolvePlaced", 
 "Charting'resolvePlacedDynamic", "Charting'resolvePlacedStatic", 
 "Charting'resolvePlotRangePadding", "Charting'ResolvePlotTheme", 
 "Charting'RotateLabels", "Charting'RotateTicks", "Charting's", 
 "Charting'safeColor", "Charting'ScaleAxes", "Charting'ScaleAxis", 
 "Charting'ScaleAxis3D", "Charting'ScaledFrameTicks", 
 "Charting'ScaledTicks", "Charting'ScaledTicks2", 
 "Charting'ScaledTickValues", "Charting'scaledValues", 
 "Charting'scientificForm", "Charting'SetChartStyleInformation", 
 "Charting'SimplePadding", "Charting'StudiesFunction", 
 "Charting'styleTree", "Charting's$", "Charting'TickAnnotations", 
 "Charting'TickLabels", "Charting'TickLengths", 
 "Charting'TickMarkers", "Charting'TickSide", "Charting'TickWrappers", 
 "Charting'TimeAxis", "Charting'TimelineParser", "Charting'TimeScale", 
 "Charting'tradingChartGridlinesFinder", 
 "Charting'TradingChartIndicator", "Charting'TradingChartSlider", 
 "Charting'Tukey5", "Charting'Tweaked", "Charting'unitConverting", 
 "Charting'UnsetChartStyleInformation", "Charting'value2pts", 
 "Charting'valueToAngle", "Charting'varCheck", 
 "Charting'VerticalScale", "Charting'$Graphics3DExtraOptions", 
 "Charting'$GraphicsExtraOptions", "Charting'$MajorTickLength", 
 "Charting'$MinorTickLength", "Charting'$PlotTheme", 
 "Charting'$PlotThemes"}
```

So maybe there is some chance left to regain control over our plots. However, this is beyond me. Please, could somebody explain to me the reasoning behind the new `Legended` functionality and the Layout? What were they thinking??

Answer (score 13):

If you provide `BarLegend` as an explicit option value of `PlotLegends` it seems to do what you want:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ImageSize -> {300, 300}, PlotLegends -> BarLegend["LakeColors"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: almost... it's now offset vertically.

Comment: @rm-rf That will surely be fixed by version 18...

Comment: @Jens I almost chocked on my noodles laughing ...

Comment: @Jens At least, in version 11. This is fixed. And explict `Barlegend` is not the key. `ImageSize` is the key that must be explicitly set ! It seems that `BarLegends` needs `ImageSize` to pick up `LegendMarkerSize`. Check `DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ImageSize -> Medium, PlotLegends -> Automatic]`

Comment: @Jens Well, I found I am wrong. With different plot ticks and legend ticks(the number of ticks are varying with different plot range). There is sometimes perfect match, most time slight offset...

Comment: @matheorem It works for the example you gave - looks like `ImageSize` is very often the answer when plots look bad, especially after exporting... but I guess we'll still have to wait for version 18 after all.

Answer (score 11):

This makes me happy.  Still a usage case for ye-olde-colorbarplot package :)
I've not checked if it works in v9 though!

http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=2960

[image]

Comment: I have tested tested colorplot package with v9
from http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=2960 everything works just fine, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Hope this workaround helps.

Use `Placed` to position legends more precisely:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 280], {1.05, 0.52}]]
```

[image]

`{1.05, 0.52}` is a scaled position referred to the `DensityPlot`.

The offset here, 0.52 instead of 0.5, is because frame tick labels move the plot off center. The same reasoning applies to the `BarLegend` itself sometimes because the tick labels can move the gradient off center (this example is lucky to have symmetric labels on both ends).

`LegendMarkerSize->280` is because the `DensityPlot` has some plot range padding that needs compensation.

Comment: Can you add more Details on how you obtained the values (`0.02` offset, the `1.05`and the `280`)?

Comment: I guess those offsets are just hand chosen... but this is good to know anyway. This is a good option for one-off cases I think.

Comment: I wonder if an Aligned[...] wrapper could be created, by analogy with Placed[...]. Aligned[expr, Top, tag] tries to align the Top of expr with other Aligned elements with the same tag.

Comment: @Andrew Right, it is difficult to get the number right programmatically because..

1. PlotRangePadding is by default Scaled.
2. LabelStyle can also affect the ticks label size both in plots and BarLegend.

Comment: Ok, i just played around with my example for the `PlotLegends` and guessed them, too; though they are quite different for my `ArrayPlot` (that does not have Padding for example).

Comment: @Ronny, 1.05 means Scaled[1.05] refer to the plot. Scaled[{0,0}] is left bottom corner of the plot and Scaled[{1,1}] is right top corner. A double list give you full control. {pos_list, objpos_list}

Comment: @AndrewMoylan and MinHsuan: [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2093/5) might help you get the padding programmatically. I've used it a few times to align two plots precisely like in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8245/5)

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to combine the already suggested old style `Row` arrangement (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2058/sizing-cells-in-a-graphicsgrid-graphicsrow/2064#2064)) automatically with the new and convenient `BarLegend` using these conversion function:

```
(* Function to generate the color bar legend *)

customBarLegend[zmin_, zmax_, label_, colorFunction_: Automatic, 
  colorFunctionScaling_: True] := Module[{},
  Show[ArrayPlot[
    Table[{zmax + zmin - y}, {y, zmin, zmax, (zmax - zmin)/100}],
    ColorFunction -> colorFunction,
    ColorFunctionScaling -> colorFunctionScaling,
    DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {zmin, zmax}},
    Frame -> True,
    FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, label}},
    FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}},
    PlotRangePadding -> 0,
    AspectRatio -> 20,
    Axes -> False],
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {zmin, zmax}}]]

(* Function to convert a regular (ugly) BarLegend into a custom bar 
legend that has the same height as the plot. *)

convertBarLegend[plot_, imPad_, barPad_, size_] := 
 Module[{zmin, zmax, zlabel, colorFunction, colorFunctionScaling, bar},
  {zmin, zmax} = (List @@ (List @@ plot)[[2]][[1]])[[1]][[2]];
  zlabel = LegendLabel /. (List @@ (List @@ plot)[[2]][[1]])[[3]];
  colorFunction = (List @@ (List @@ plot)[[2]][[1]])[[1]][[1]];
  colorFunctionScaling = 
   ColorFunctionScaling /. (List @@ (List @@ plot)[[2]][[1]])[[6]];
  bar = customBarLegend[zmin, zmax, zlabel, colorFunction, 
    colorFunctionScaling];
  Row[{Show[(List @@ plot)[[1]], ImageSize -> {Automatic, size}, 
     ImagePadding -> imPad], 
    Show[bar, ImageSize -> {Automatic, size}, ImagePadding -> barPad]}]
  ]
```

Example:

```
uglyplot = 
 DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "z"]]
```

[image: default image style]

```
imPad = {{50, 7}, {60, 10}}; (*{{left,right},{bottom,top}}*)
barPad = {{1, 100}, imPad[[2]]};(* bottom and top should be the same as imPad. *)
plot = convertBarLegend[uglyplot, imPad, barPad, 300]
```

[image: consistent bar height]

The numbers in `imPad` and `barPad` need to be adjusted to fit the size of the tick labels and the axes/frame labels. Therefore, they depend on the actual labels. The last parameter `size` determines how large the image is rendered.

In the functions, I make use of the fact that `List@@plot` gives access to a large variety of parameters that characterize the plot, such as ranges and labels.

**Edit:**

Changed the rendering of the custom bar legend from `DensityPlot` to `ArrayPlot`. This reduces the computation time and the file size of the graphics if exported to disk. Similarly, it is recommended to use `ArrayPlot` for the main graphics. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133021/export-grid-of-figures-not-graphicsgrid-to-pdf) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my attempt to solve it as a post-processing way.

I will use two tools as bridges

1. convert legend to graphics from [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172823/4742)
2. get absolute padding from [Heike](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2093/4742)

The basic idea is stated quite clearly in Szabolcs's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8660/4742) for frame plots.

So first is define `convertLegendToGraphics`, it converts legend to Graphics object.

```
ClearAll[convertLegendToGraphics];
convertLegendToGraphics[legend_] := 
 First@Cases[ToBoxes@legend, 
   gr_GraphicsBox :> ToExpression[gr], \[Infinity]]
```

Then define `getPadding`

```
ClearAll[getPadding];
getPadding[g_] := Module[{im},
   labelStyleOpt = Options[g, LabelStyle][[1, 2]];
   im = Image[
     Show[g /. _?ColorQ -> White, 
      LabelStyle -> Directive[labelStyleOpt, White], 
      Background -> White]];
   BorderDimensions[im] + {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}];
```

Note that I do a little tweak here which I found is necessary if your plot has specified custom `LabelStyle` or Styled `PlotLabel`. The `_?ColorQ -> White` has the ability to turn any explicit colored things into white including explicitly colored `PlotLabel`. However, it will have an disadvantage, it make `getPadding` only works for black frame or axis, **so do not set fancy colored frame or axis**.

then, finally the main part

```
ClearAll[sameHeightLegends];
sameHeightLegends[plot_] := Module[{},
  plotPart = plot[[1]];
  plotLabelOpt = Options[plotPart, PlotLabel][[1, 2]];
  imageSize = ImageDimensions[plotPart];
  verticalImageSize = imageSize[[2]];
  legendPart = 
   Show[convertLegendToGraphics@plot[[2, 1]], 
    ImageSize -> {Automatic, verticalImageSize}];

  {ph, pv} = getPadding[plotPart];
  {phNoLabel, pvNoLabel} = 
   getPadding[Show[plotPart, PlotLabel -> None]];
  {lh, lv} = getPadding[legendPart /. _?ColorQ -> White];
  verticalPadding = pv;
  If[plotLabelOpt === None,
   Row[{Show[plotPart, ImageSize -> imageSize, 
      ImagePadding -> {ph, verticalPadding}], 
     Show[legendPart, ImagePadding -> {lh, verticalPadding}]}],
   Row[{Show[plotPart, ImageSize -> imageSize, 
      ImagePadding -> {phNoLabel, pvNoLabel}], 
     Show[legendPart, ImagePadding -> {lh, verticalPadding}]}]]]
```

note that I treat labeled case separately.

Ok, here is an example which I found probably no other solutions can done it right.

```
plot = DensityPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
  PlotLabel -> Style[Column[{"line1", "line2"}], 30, Red],
  BaseStyle -> Directive[Bold, 24],
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, LabelStyle -> Green,
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

it will give

[image]

and

```
sameHeightLegends[plot]
```

gives

[image]

**ps**

This method doesn't need to set `ImageSize` explictly and no special treatment to 
`PlotLegends`, so is full automatic.

But of course, it only supports vertical Legends.

Currently, this post-processing method has one drawback. To retrieve absolute dimension of Plot or absolute ImagePadding, we need rasterization, and every rasterization takes about 0.3 seconds on my computer, so it has some efficiency problem. Nevertheless, for most case, it is bearable. Hope there is some faster way to get absolute imagesize and imagepadding.

Comment: This [works bad](https://imgur.com/a/hHC6vT8) in v10.4, although it works _almost_ [good](https://imgur.com/a/SaatRX6) in v11.3 - except for some wiggly line directly below the legend.

Comment: @corey979 Thank you for comment. then I don't know what is going on? Mathematica is really a fast changing system!

Comment: the "wiggly line" below barlegend only appears on linux from v11.3. see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181210/what-are-these-markers-at-the-bottom-of-barlegend/181231) for solutions.

Answer (score 2):

In the featured example on [changing legend orientations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/example/ChangeLegendOrientation.html), they use the following:

```
PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLayout -> "Column"], After]
```

This appears to produce legends that align as wanted *if* accompanied by an explicit `ImageSize`. It still produces a slight vertical offset as in Sjoerd's answer.

As a side note, the four-plot combination on the same page is far from perfect because of the other misalignments.

Comment: The options you mentioned seem - as far as i worked today with PlotLegends - to be the default values, hence they lead to exactely the image the OP postet. But Setting `ImageSize -> 300` for the Plot will (why ever) do the Job on my PC (in contrary to @Sjoerd C.s answer), if I use only one Value and set the `PlotRangePadding -> 0`