# Running PlotLegends in Mathematica 8

Tags: legending, version-8

I will like to get a density plot (in *Mathematica 8*) as in: [Make legend same height as plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/make-legend-same-height-as-plot).
However, anytime I run

```
DensityPlot[ Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

I get a red coloured `"PlotLegends"` within the input text followed by an error message. I need your help!

Comment: you need Mathematica 9.

Comment: As Rolf said, you need _Mathematica_ 9 to use those functions. For v8, you can use Jens' solution in the linked question. See also [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/5) by Jens for creating good looking legends in v8 and below.

Comment: @Rolf and R.M., I now have Mathematica 9 and enjoying the autocruise. Thanks.